# Mathematica won't give eigenvectors but Wolfram Alpha will? What am I doing wrong?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, eigenvalues

If I ask Mathematica to find the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of the matrix:

```
mat := {{a, b, c}, {b, d, e}, {c, e, f}}
Assuming[{a > 0, b > 0, c > 0, d > 0, e > 0, f > 0}, Eigenvalues[mat]]
Assuming[{a > 0, b > 0, c > 0, d > 0, e > 0, f > 0}, Eigenvectors[mat]]
```

If returns stuff like

```
{Root[c^2 d - 2 b c e + a e^2 + b^2 f - 
a d f + (-b^2 - c^2 + a d - e^2 + a f + d f) #1 + (-a - d - 
   f) #1^2 + #1^3 &, 1], 
Root[c^2 d - 2 b c e + a e^2 + b^2 f - 
a d f + (-b^2 - c^2 + a d - e^2 + a f + d f) #1 + (-a - d - 
   f) #1^2 + #1^3 &, 2], 
Root[c^2 d - 2 b c e + a e^2 + b^2 f - 
a d f + (-b^2 - c^2 + a d - e^2 + a f + d f) #1 + (-a - d - 
   f) #1^2 + #1^3 &, 3]}
```

But if I ask Wolfram Alpha:

[image]

It does it. What am I doing wrong in Mathematica?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use

```
Eigenvalues[mat, Cubics -> True]
Eigenvectors[mat, Cubics -> True]
```

sometimes `Quartics -> True`can be needed.

or

```
ToRadicals @ Eigenvalues[ mat]
ToRadicals @ Eigenvectors[ mat]
```

In general one cannot find roots (of higher order) polynomials in terms of radicals. The reason that `Mathematica` allows this option is that in general it is  convenient to decide whether output (sometimes very large) is needed. For a matrix `2 x 2` it yields automatically the result in terms of radicals :

```
Eigenvalues[{{a, b}, {c, d}}]
```

> ```
> {1/2 (a + d - Sqrt[a^2 + 4 b c - 2 a d + d^2]), 1/2 (a + d + Sqrt[a^2 + 4 b c - 2 a d + d^2])}
> ```

because it is quite simple, but the first eigenvalue of your matrix is slightly more involved :

```
Eigenvalues[ mat, Cubics -> True][[1]]
```

[image]

So these options are certainly convenient to choose whether one prefers the results in terms of `Root` objects or it terms of radicals.

Comment: Thank you very much. First of all, +1 for the help. Just wondering though - is the Cubics -> True making assumptions about something, or just forcing Mathematica to give me an analytical expression? Thanks again.

Comment: @DJ, `Cubics -> True` just means that the routine should give explicit solutions to cubic equations as opposed to producing `Root[]` objects. Similarly for `Quartics -> True`.

Comment: Artes, you might want to talk about `Eigensystem[]` as well. :)

Comment: This option exists because Quartics can be huge and you might not want to see the explicit representation of the result fill your pages. The root object represent the same solutions, but much more compactly.

Comment: @DJBunk You are welcome. I edited my answer to elaborate a bit why these options are convenient. Try for example to solve a fourth order polynomial with `Quartics -> True` with Reduce. @J.M True indeed, but there is also  an argument to mention about `Reduce`, `Resolve` etc.