# How do I work with Root objects?

Tags: equation-solving, symbolic, polynomials, trigonometry, faq

I want to solve the trigonometric equation :
$$(3-\cos 4x )\cdot (\sin x - \cos x ) = 2.$$
I tried

```
Solve[(3 - Cos[4*x])*(Sin[x] - Cos[x]) == 2, x]
```

It returns the solutions in terms of `Root` objects yielding also this message :

> ```
> Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found;
> use Reduce for complete solution information. >>
> ```

How do I tell *Mathematica* to do that?

How can I solve this equation : $\tan(2x)⋅ \tan(7x) = 1$ ?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

A shorter introduction to working with [`Root`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) objects is in [the below answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/126156/12).

---

Solutions to algebraic or transcendental equations are expressed in terms of `Root` objects whenever it is impossible to find explicit solutions. In general there is no way express roots of 5-th (or higher) order polynomials in terms of radicals. However even higher order algebraic equations can be solved explicitly if an associated Galois group is solvable.  On the other hand `Solve` and `Reduce` behave differently by default, e.g. evaluate `Reduce[x^4 + 3 x + 1 == 0, x]` and `Solve[x^4 + 3 x + 1 == 0, x]`, this justifies apparently different outputs :

```
Options[#, {Cubics, Quartics}] & /@ {Reduce, Solve}
```

> ```
> {{Cubics -> False, Quartics -> False}, {Cubics -> True, Quartics -> True}}
> ```

or read [another related post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11498/mathematica-wont-give-eigenvectors-but-wolfram-alpha-will-what-am-i-doing-wron). 
Using `Solve` you could include this option `InverseFunctions -> True` to avoid any messages generated :

```
s = Solve[(3 - Cos[4x])(Sin[x] - Cos[x]) == 2, x, InverseFunctions -> True]
```

[image]

nevertheless you won't get all solutions, only three of them are real numbers :

```
Select[ s[[All, 1, 2]], Element[#, Reals] &]
```

> ```
> {-π, π/2, π}
> ```

In general, it is recommended to use `Reduce` rather than `Solve` when one is looking for a general solution, mainly because the latter yields only generic solutions. Another reason is that lists must be of finite length while boolean form of `Reduce` output is more appropriate to include infinite number of solutions. However in our case one can add the option `MaxExtraCondition` to express full set of solutions, e.g.

```
 Solve[(3 - Cos[4x])(Sin[x] - Cos[x]) == 2, x, MaxExtraConditions -> All]
```

> ```
> {...,
>  {x -> ConditionalExpression[
>            2 ArcTan[ Root[1 + 12 #1^2 - 8 #1^3 - 26 #1^4 + 28 #1^6 + 8 #1^7 + #1^8 &,  8]] 
>            + 2 π C[1],        C[1] ∈  Integers] },   ...}
> ```

With `Reduce` we needn't use any options and we'll get  all i.e. infinitely many solutions, evaluate e.g. :

```
Reduce[(3 - Cos[4x])(Sin[x] - Cos[x]) == 2, x]
```

There is no problem with infinitely many solutions since the function is periodical and in a given period all roots are expressed in terms of a finite number of polynomial roots.
Real solutions are integer multiples of `π/2` and for the  rest  `Mathematica` cannot decide whether they are transcendental or algebraic numbers, to check it try e.g. :

```
Element[#, Algebraics] & /@ s[[All, 1, 2]]
```

Note that `Root` objects represents the exact solutions, e.g. :

```
FullSimplify[(3 - Cos[4 x]) (Sin[x] - Cos[x]) - 2 /. s]
```

> ```
> {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
> ```

`Root` includes a pure function and an integer number pointing out explicitly a given root (here e.g. `Root[1 - 4 #1 + 8 #1^2 - 4 #1^3 + 24 #1^5 - 24 #1^6 - 16 #1^7 + 
   16 #1^8 &, 1]`) or (since `ver.7`) a list including a pure function and numerical approximation where we can find a root in case of a [transcendental equation](http://www.wolfram.com/products/mathematica/newin7/content/TranscendentalRoots/). This [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4694/can-reduce-really-not-solve-for-x-here/4697#4697) may be helpful as well. Regardless of the form of representation `Root` can be exactly determined with an [arbitrary accuracy](http://www.wolfram.com/products/mathematica/newin7/content/TranscendentalRoots/FindRootsExactlyAndToArbitraryNumericalPrecision.html), whatever one needs, let's take the fourth solution in `s` e.g. :

```
N[ s[[4]], 30]
```

> ```
> {x -> -2.8504590137122308498000229727725413207035323228576 
>       -0.2528465030753225904344011159589677330661689973232 I }
> ```

In case of `Root` is expressed by a transcendental function which has unbounded set of roots we have to restrict our searching to a [bounded set](http://www.wolfram.com/products/mathematica/newin7/content/TranscendentalRoots/SolveAnAnalyticEquationOverABoundedInterval.html) including another condition, e.g. here we can restrict to `-5 < Re[x] < 5`, let's define :

```
g[x_, y_] := (3 - Cos[4 (x + I y)])(Sin[(x + I y)] - Cos[(x + I y)]) - 2
rsol = Reduce[(3 - Cos[4x])(Sin[x] - Cos[x]) == 2 && -5 < Re[x] < 5, x];
roots = {Re @ #, Im @ #} & /@ List @@ rsol[[All, 2]];
```

now we can visualize the geometrical structure of of the solution set :

```
GraphicsColumn[
  Table[
    Show[ ContourPlot @@@ {
            { f[ g[x, y]], ##, Contours -> 15, ColorFunction -> "AvocadoColors", 
              Epilog -> {PointSize[0.007],  Red , Point[roots]}},
            { Re[ g[x, y]] == 0, ##, ContourStyle -> {Blue, Thick}},
            { Im[ g[x, y]] == 0, ##, ContourStyle -> {Cyan, Thick}}}, 
          AspectRatio -> 3/10],        {f, {Re, Im}}] & @  Sequence[{x, -5, 5}, {y, -1, 1}]]
```

[image]

The blue curves are sets of complex numbers `x + I y` where `Re[ g[x, y]] == 0`, while the cyan ones where `Im[ g[x, y]] == 0`, and the roots are denoted by red points. 
We can see that we have `12` complex roots and `4` purely real ones, whereas `Solve` yielded respectively only `8` complex roots and `3` purely real.

For more information I recommend reading carefully e.g. an interesting post by Roger Germundsson on Wolfram Blog :  [Mathematica 7, Johannes Kepler, and Transcendental Roots](http://blog.wolfram.com/2008/12/18/mathematica-7-johannes-kepler-and-transcendental-roots/).

**Edit**

Solving another equation of the OP I'd take :

```
Solve[ Tan[ 2x] Tan[ 7x] == 1, x, MaxExtraConditions -> All]
```

or simply

```
Reduce[ Tan[ 2x] Tan[ 7x] == 1, x]
```

All roots are real numbers :

```
Reduce[#, x] == Reduce[#, x, Reals] & [Tan[2 x] Tan[7 x] == 1]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Restricting our search to an interesting range of periodical function, let's  denote :

```
hrs = List @@ Reduce[ Tan[ 2x] Tan[ 7x] == 1 && -5 < Re[x] < 5, x][[All, 2]];
```

now we can plot the roots :

```
Plot[ Tan[ 2x] Tan[ 7x] - 1, {x, -2.7, 4.8}, AspectRatio -> 1/3, PlotStyle -> Thick,
      Exclusions -> {Cot[2x] == 0, Cot[7x] == 0}, 
      Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.007], Point[Thread[{#, 0}& @ hrs]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Base on your code, I solve the equation $\tan 2x \cdot \tan 7x = 1$. I input
s = Solve[Tan[2*x]*Tan[7*x] == 1, x, InverseFunctions -> True]
and Select[s[[All, 1, 2]], Element[#, Reals] &]
But the equation has many other real roots. Please help me.

Comment: Using MMA 8 and your state of the art answer, I had no problem at all. But with MMA 10.0 some output format changed and I had to do some modifications to get again your answer.For example `s = Solve[(3 - Cos[4 x]) (Sin[x] - Cos[x]) == 2, x,   MaxExtraConditions -> 0] /. C[1] -> 0`. But I now have 2 real solutions instead of 3 (-Pi is missing). Do you know which MMA version returns the correct answer?

Answer (score 27):

This answer is to summarize the most important points about working with `Root` objects.

Essential reading:

- [Algebraic Numbers](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/AlgebraicNumbers.html) in the documentation.

#### What are `Root` objects?

[`Root`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) is primarily used to symbolically represent roots of polynomials.  In general, roots of polynomials of order $\ge 5$ do not have an explicit expression in terms of radicals, as stated by the [Abel–Ruffini theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem).  However, *Mathematica* can work with polynomials in a general way without referring to an explicit representation.  It uses `Root` as a general symbolic representation instead.

`Root` objects are often returned by equation solving functions such as `Solve` and `Reduce`.

#### How do I work with `Root` objects? How do I "get the solution"?

- Use [`ToRadicals`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToRadicals.html) to convert a `Root` object to an explicit representation in terms of radicals, whenever this is possible:

  ```
   root = Root[#^3 - #^2 + 2 # - 3 &, 1];

   ToRadicals[root]

   (* 1/3 (1 - 5^(2/3) (2/(13 + 3 Sqrt[21]))^(1/3) + (5/2 (13 + 3 Sqrt[21]))^(1/3)) *)
  ```

  Before doing this, think about whether an explicit representation is the most useful one for your purposes.

  Note that it is possible for a `Root` object to have an explicit radical representation that cannot be found by `ToRadicals`:

  ```
   root = Root[1 - 36 # + 12 #^2 - 6 #^3 - 6 #^4 + #^6 &, 2];

   ToRadicals[root]

   (* Root[1 - 36 #1 + 12 #1^2 - 6 #1^3 - 6 #1^4 + #1^6 &, 2] *)

   RootReduce[Sqrt[2] + 3^(1/3)]

   (* Root[1 - 36 #1 + 12 #1^2 - 6 #1^3 - 6 #1^4 + #1^6 &, 2] *)
  ```
- [`N`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/N.html) works on `Root` objects:

  ```
   N[root]
   (* 1.27568 *)
  ```
- [`RootReduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RootReduce.html) is the reverse operation.  It converts an expression in terms of radicals to a `Root` object, essentially finding the minimal polynomial of that root (the polynomial of lowest degree which has the expression as one of its roots).

  ```
   Sqrt[5]/2 + Sqrt[3] // RootReduce
   (* Root[49 - 136 #1^2 + 16 #1^4 &, 4] *)

   MinimalPolynomial[Sqrt[5]/2 + Sqrt[3], x]
   (* 49 - 136 x^2 + 16 x^4 *)
  ```

#### Transcendental equations

Since *Mathematica* 7, `Root` objects can be used to represent not only polynomial roots, but also roots of certain transcendental equations.  These are representations of the exact solutions. This functionality is introduced in this blog post:

- [Mathematica 7, Johannes Kepler, and Transcendental Roots](http://blog.wolfram.com/2008/12/18/mathematica-7-johannes-kepler-and-transcendental-roots/)

`Reduce` can usually find such solutions:

```
Reduce[Exp[-x] == Log[x] + x, x, Reals]
(* x == Root[{Log[#1] + E^-#1 (-1 + E^#1 #1) &, 0.75358664811840711860}] *)
```

While the representation contains numerical parts, it is important to understand that this is an exact result.  In practice, this means that it is guaranteed that this returned solution is unique, and that it can be numericised (using `N`) to arbitrary precision.

`Root` objects of this type cannot be used with `ToRadicals`.

#### Output formatting

Starting in version 12, `Root` objects now have a special output format where the object now displays its approximate numerical value:

[image: example of Root output in version 12]

Using `InputForm[]`/`FullForm[]` on these objects will reveal the actual representation. If you wish to go back to the pre-version 12 behavior, you can evaluate the following (or even put it in your `init.m`):

```
SetSystemOptions["TypesetOptions" -> "NumericalApproximationForms" -> False]
```

as noted by ilian in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/202792).

Comment: **Why this answer?**  There are several posts marked the duplicate of this one.  It was necessary to have an answer which is more general and more concise that than of @Artes, and it was very important to mention `ToRadicals` at the beginning.

Comment: [Transform Root objects into Trigonometric expressions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/52124/transform-root-objects-into-trigonometric-expressions) may be relevant in special cases.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Feel free to edit the answer, that's why I made it community wiki.  Maybe an link collection at the end would be good.

Answer (score 6):

First, I put $t = \sin x - \cos x$,

```
eq1 = (3 - Cos[4x]) ( Sin[x] - Cos[x]) - 2 == 0;
eq2 = t == Sin[x] - Cos[x];
Eliminate[ TrigExpand[ {eq1, eq2}], x]
```

I receive

`2 t - 2 t^3 + t^5 == 1`

And then, I solve

```
Solve[ 2 t - 2 t^3 + t^5 == 1, Reals]
```

finally

```
Reduce[ -Cos[x] + Sin[x] == 1, x, Reals]
(C[1] ∈ Integers && x == π/2 + 2 π C[1]) || (C[1] ∈ Integers && x == π + 2 π C[1])
```

This is my solution by hand, I put at  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/218381/how-to-solve-this-trigonometric-equation/218496#218496

Answer (score 1):

To recover the third solution in Mathematica as is to explain why it is missing in the solution without extra conditions.

```
zeros=Reduce[(3 - Cos[4 x]) (Sin[x] - Cos[x]) == 2 && x >= -2 π && 
   x <= 0, x] /. C[1] -> 0
```

---

(*x == -((3 [Pi])/2) || x == -[Pi]*)

So the solution implicitly is the substitution for C[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPf6x.png)==0. This has to done by interpreting the periodicity of the trigonometric composition.

```
FunctionPeriod[(3 - Cos[4 x]) (Sin[x] - Cos[x]), x]
```

---

2 [Pi]

That is too what the constant C[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPf6x.png) is for in the solution of `Solve` and `Reduce`.

So getting the -Pi in the solution was a different interpretation in the question and is not an error.

zlist = List @@ zeros[[All, 2]];

This shows each period of the functions has two zero on the real axis.

```
Solve[(3 - Cos[4*x])*(Sin[x] - Cos[x]) == 2, x]
```

[image: output of Solve for the first question]

This shows the constant C[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPf6x.png) and this domain of C[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPf6x.png). So there are as many solutions as the `Integers` are mighty.

The `ConditionalExpression` is much to advanced for beginners. In the `Plot` built-in it does not matter because `Plot` uses `Through`. That evaluates the `ConditionalExpression` on the choosen interval of the `Plot`. In the output of Mathematica, the substitution evaluates them too and this makes a choice of an interval in which the solution reside. Sinces most beginners courses in maths do not teach Complexes there are obsolete solutions.

```
zlist = List @@ zeros[[All, 2]]
zlist = Append[zlist, zlist + 2 π] // Flatten

Plot[(3 - Cos[4 x]) (Sin[x] - Cos[x]) - 2, {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, 
 Ticks -> {{-2 Pi, -Pi, 0, Pi, 2 Pi}, {-1, 1}}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.01], Point[Thread[{#, 0} &@zlist]]}]
```

[image: Plot of the function and the zeros]

With 12.0.0 I have no problems solving this input. Most probable source for beginners are token variables. Just use Clean or CleanAll on the variables or CleanAll["Global`*"] or Quit and try again.

```
 ComplexPlot[(3 - Cos[4*x])*(Sin[x] - Cos[x]) - 
  2, {x, -2 π - 2 π I, 2 π + 2 π I}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.01], Point[Thread[{#, 0} &@zlist]]}]
```

[image: ComplexPlot and the zeros]

For the second part of the question

```
Reduce[Tan[2 x] Tan[7 x] == 1, x, Reals]
```

[image: solutions]

```
FunctionPeriod[Tan[2 x] Tan[7 x], x]
```

(*Pi*)

`Reduce` is slightly easier to understand in the output compared to `Solve`.

`Reduce` contains `Solve` complete and the methods of `Solve` can restricted in `Reduce` with the option `Method->Reduce` `Solve` behave almost like `Reduce`. Instead of `Solve` `Reduce` is invoked.

In the documentation page of [`Reduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce.html) Wolfram Inc states that "For transcendental equations, Solve may not give all solutions:". On the other side "Reduce does not solve equations that depend on branch cuts of Wolfram Language functions:". So plot the function first and identify the problem.

`Solve` has much more options than `Reduce` in the documentation page. It is up to oneself to test their functionality in `Reduce`.

```
solt = Solve[Tan[2 x] Tan[7 x] == 1, x, Reals]
zert = solt[[All, 1, 2]] /. C[1] -> 0 // List // Flatten
plo = Plot[Tan[2 x] Tan[7 x] - 1, {x, -1.0125 π, 1.0125 π}, 
  Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[Thread[{#, 0} &@zert]]}]
```

[image: Plot of the given functions and the zeros]

```
lip = ListPlot[
  Callout[{# // N, 0}, #, 
     LeaderSize -> {{32, 135 \[Degree], 6}, {5, 180 \[Degree]}}] & /@ 
   zert, PlotMarkers -> Automatic, PlotTheme -> "Web"];

Show[plo, lip, ImageSize -> 600, AspectRatio -> 1/4]
```

[image: Annotated zeros for Tan[ 2x] Tan[ 7x] - 1]

The substitution of the trigonometrics is a nice alternative. Both factors work brilliant and give a polynomial of fifth order.

```
equ1 = (3 - Cos[4 x]) (Sin[x] - Cos[x]) - 2 == 0;
equ2 = t == 3 - Cos[4 x];
Eliminate[TrigExpand[{equ1, equ2}], x]
```

(* 16 t^2 - 4 t^4 + t^5 == 32 *)

```
Solve[16 t^2 - 4 t^4 + t^5 == 32, Reals]
```

(* {t -> 2} *)

The polynomial for the substitution of t == 3 - Cos[4 x] has only one solution.

```
Plot[{16 t^2 - 4 t^4 + t^5, 32}, {t, -3, 3}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[{2, 32}]}]
```

[image: Plot]

```
Reduce[-Cos[x] + Sin[x] == 1, x, Reals]
Solve[-Cos[x] + Sin[x] == 1, x, Reals]

(Element[C[1], Integers] && x == Pi/2 + 2*Pi*C[1]) || 
  (Element[C[1], Integers] && x == Pi + 2*Pi*C[1])


{{x -> ConditionalExpression[Pi/2 - 4*Pi*C[1], Element[C[1], Integers]]}, 
  {x -> ConditionalExpression[2*(-(Pi/2) + 2*Pi*C[1]), Element[C[1], Integers]]}, 
  {x -> ConditionalExpression[2*(Pi/2 + 2*Pi*C[1]), Element[C[1], Integers]]}, 
  {x -> ConditionalExpression[Pi/2 - 2*(Pi + 2*Pi*C[1]), Element[C[1], Integers]]}}

Reduce[3 - Cos[4 x] == 2, x, Reals]

Element[C[1], Integers] && x == (Pi*C[1])/2
```

### Some examples:
Table[(Pi*C)/2, {C, -6, 6}]

```
(* {-3*Pi, -((5*Pi)/2), -2*Pi, -((3*Pi)/2), -Pi, -(Pi/2), 0, Pi/2, Pi, (3*Pi)/2, 2*Pi, 
  (5*Pi)/2, 3*Pi} *)
```

The cause is 4 is even and this means the zeros of both factors match.

Mathematica stays a little back on Root object and representation of numbers in terms of trigonometrics for example. This question might help further in this and other problems, [transform root objects into trigonometric expressions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/52124/transform-root-objects-into-trigonometric-expressions/70003#70003). Especially the robust approach in the AskConstants package [AskConstants download](http://math.hawaii.edu/%7Edale/AskConstants/AskConstants.html) and [AskConstants WTC presentation on Youtube.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6gm_ocyvRlA) This package is free and the user are professional Mathematica users at the University of Hawaii.