# How to find the sum all even numbers of this sequence?

Tags: programming, equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, symbolic

I have a sequence $(u_{n})$
$$u_1= 1, \quad u_2 = 2, \quad u_3 = 3, \quad  u_{n}= -u_{n-3} + 3u _{n-2} +2 u_{n-1}, \quad \forall n \geqslant 4.$$
I want to list the first $20$ terms of this sequence and find the sum of  all terms and sum of all even numbers of $20$ terms.
I tried

```
Clear[u];
u[1] := 1; u[2] := 2;
u[3] := 3;
u[y_] := -u[y - 3] + 3u[y - 2] + 2u[y - 1]
A := Table[ u[k], {k, 1, 20}]

Sum[ A[[i]], {i, 1, Length[A]}]
```

I can't find sum of even numbers. How do I tell *Mathematica* to do that ?

Comment: Do you want to sum all `u[n]` terms, i.e. up to infinity ?

Comment: You might consider cacheing values of `u` to speed things up. Just change the first part of your code to: `u[1] = 1; u[2] = 2; u[3] = 3; u[y_] := u[y] = -u[y - 3] + 3*u[y - 2] + 2*u[y - 1];`

Comment: Also, I note you can get the sum of all elements with `Total@A`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `Select` to pull the elements meeting some specified criterion from a list. The selected elements are returned in a list that you can feed to `Total` to sum them. `Total` is better than `Sum` for your problem because you don't have to supply the length of the list and you have no need for indexing.

```
Clear[u];
u[1] := 1; u[2] := 2;
u[3] := 3;
u[y_] := -u[y - 3] + 3*u[y - 2] + 2*u[y - 1]
A = Table[u[k], {k, 1, 20}]
Total[Select[A, EvenQ]]

(* 278878570 *)
```

Answer (score 13):

Working with `RSolve` we can find  much more than only a few first terms, here is a general term of your function `u[n]` e.g.  :

```
u[n_] = u[n] /. Flatten[ RSolve[{ u[1] == 1, u[2] == 2, u[3] == 3, 
                                  u[n] == -u[n-3] + 3 u[n-2] + 2 u[n-1]}, u[n], n]]
```

> ```
> Root[1 - 3 #1 - 2 #1^2 + #1^3 &, 3]^n Root[-45 + 457 #1 - 1028 #1^2 + 257 #1^3 &, 1] + 
> Root[1 - 3 #1 - 2 #1^2 + #1^3 &, 1]^n Root[-45 + 457 #1 - 1028 #1^2 + 257 #1^3 &, 2] + 
> Root[1 - 3 #1 - 2 #1^2 + #1^3 &, 2]^n Root[-45 + 457 #1 - 1028 #1^2 + 257 #1^3 &, 3]
> ```

Related  : [How do I work with Root objects](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13767/how-do-i-work-with-root-objects/13768#13768).

Let's write the first `20` terms :

```
t = FullSimplify @ Table[ u[k], {k, 20}]
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 3, 11, 29, 88, 252, 739, 2146, 6257, 18213, 53051, 154484, 449908, 1310217,  
>  3815674, 11112091, 32360987, 94242573, 274456016}
> ```

```
Total @ t
```

> ```
> 417982742
> ```

Let's sum only even terms :

```
Total @ Cases[ t, _?EvenQ]
```

> ```
> 278878570
> ```

One might understand as well the task this way :

```
Total @ FullSimplify @ Table[ u[2 k], {k, 10}]
```

> ```
> 311142733
> ```

Moreover we can find a general symbolic formula for partial sums `s[n]` of the first `n` terms of `u[i]` for `1<= i <= n` :

```
s[n_] := FullSimplify[ Sum[ u[i], {i, n}], n ∈ Integers && n > 0]

s[n]
```

> ```
> 1/3 ( 3 +
>   Root[1 - 3 #1 - 2 #1^2 + #1^3 &, 2]^n Root[405 - 1233 #1 + 771 #1^2 + 257 #1^3 &, 1] +
>   Root[1 - 3 #1 - 2 #1^2 + #1^3 &, 1]^n Root[405 - 1233 #1 + 771 #1^2 + 257 #1^3 &, 2] +
>   Root[1 - 3 #1 - 2 #1^2 + #1^3 &, 3]^n Root[405 - 1233 #1 + 771 #1^2 + 257 #1^3 &, 3])
> ```

To write `s[n]` in terms of more familiar expressions we have to make a trick applying `ToRadicals` and `ComplexExpand` to every `Root` object separately and then retrieve the original expression :

```
1/3 (3 + #1^n #2 + #3^n #4 + #5^n #6)& @@ ComplexExpand @ ToRadicals @ {
Root[1 - 3 #1 - 2 #1^2 + #1^3 &, 2], Root[405 - 1233 #1 + 771 #1^2 + 257 #1^3 &, 1], 
Root[1 - 3 #1 - 2 #1^2 + #1^3 &, 1], Root[405 - 1233 #1 + 771 #1^2 + 257 #1^3 &, 2], 
Root[1 - 3 #1 - 2 #1^2 + #1^3 &, 3], Root[405 - 1233 #1 + 771 #1^2 + 257 #1^3 &, 3]} // 
Simplify // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

It is not especially surprising that neither the series `u[n]` nor `s[n]` is convergent, e.g.

```
Limit[ s[n], n -> Infinity]
```

> $\infty$

you could still find out certain interesting properties  e.g. using the `Regularization` option of `Sum`.
Regularization techniques are ubiquitous in modern theoretical physics, e.g. in quantum field theory one encounters this formula $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n = -\frac{1}{12}\;$:

```
Sum[ n, {n, Infinity}, Regularization -> "Dirichlet"]
```

> ```
> -(1/12)
> ```

See e.g. this post [The Euler-Maclaurin formula, Bernoulli numbers, the zeta function, and real-variable analytic continuation](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/04/10/the-euler-maclaurin-formula-bernoulli-numbers-the-zeta-function-and-real-variable-analytic-continuation/) by Terrence Tao. 
  Now we can figure out ( only `"Borel"` works here) the regularized sum of `u[n]`:

```
FullSimplify @ Sum[ u[n], {n, Infinity}, Regularization -> "Borel"]
```

> ```
> 1
> ```

For comparison one can regularize a geometric series of a general term `a^n` :

```
Sum[ a^n, {n, Infinity}, Regularization -> "Borel"]
```

> ```
> -(a/(-1 + a))
> ```

We get `1` for `a == 1/2`.

Comment: I receive your help very much. Thank you.

Comment: @minthao_2011  You are welcome. I added more advanced and interesting topics.

Answer (score 8):

I think `RecurrenceTable` deserves justice as a very efficient way to tabulate solutions of the recurrence equations.

Compare procedural approach with no dynamic programming used:

```
In[214]:= Block[{u, A},
  u[1] := 1; u[2] := 2;
  u[3] := 3;
  u[y_] := -u[y - 3] + 3*u[y - 2] + 2*u[y - 1];
  A = Table[u[k], {k, 1, 25}];
  Total[Select[A, EvenQ]]] // AbsoluteTiming

Out[214]= {4.617608, 7856903616}
```

to the use of `RecurrenceTable`, where all that is needed is to define the equation:

```
In[215]:= 
Select[RecurrenceTable[{u[1] == 1, u[2] == 2, u[3] == 3, 
     u[n] == -u[n - 3] + 3 u[n - 2] + 2 u[n - 1]}, u[n], {n, 1, 25}], 
   EvenQ] // Total // AbsoluteTiming

Out[215]= {0., 7856903616}
```

Also, it is worth pointing out that any linear recurrence equation of rank $r$ evaluated $\bmod p$ must be periodic, due to the recurrence relation and the finiteness of the state space. Indeed, our system turns out to have period of 7:

```
In[217]:= Partition[
 Mod[RecurrenceTable[{u[1] == 1, u[2] == 2, u[3] == 3, 
    u[n] == -u[n - 3] + 3 u[n - 2] + 2 u[n - 1]}, u[n], {n, 1, 32}], 
  2], 7]

Out[217]= {{1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0}, 
           {1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0}, 
           {1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0}, 
           {1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0}}
```

Thus $u_{7m+2}$, $u_{7m+5}$ and $u_{7m+6}$ are even.

We can now use the symbolic power of `Mathematica` to work out the recurrence relation for sums $v^{(2)}_m = \sum_{k=0}^{m} u_{7k+2}$, $v^{(5)}_m = \sum_{k=0}^{m} u_{7k+5}$ and $v^{(6)}_m = \sum_{k=0}^{m} u_{7k+6}$:

For example:

```
In[223]:= Sum[
 DifferenceRoot[
   Function[{u, n}, {u[n + 3] == -u[n] + 3 u[n + 1] + 2 u[n + 2], 
     u[1] == 1, u[2] == 2, u[3] == 3}]][7 k + 2], {k, 0, m}]

Out[223]= 
DifferenceRoot[
  Function[{y, n}, {-y[n] + 6318 y[1 + n] - 
      4544 y[2 + n] - 1774 y[3 + n] + y[4 + n] == 0, 
      y[0] == 0, y[1] == 2, y[2] == 2148, y[3] == 3817822}]][1 + m]
```

Now, evaluation for any $m$ is just a matter of substitution:

```
In[224]:= % /. m -> 20

Out[224]= \
118640843309870276692961346051090397680399199522287919469464837082
```

Working out the solution for $v^{(5)}_m$ and $v^{(6)}_m$ is an easy exercise.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't explicitly need the array `A` you can use `Sum` *in place of* `Table`.

Also, you should be using [memoization](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/FunctionsThatRememberValuesTheyHaveFound.html) in your definition of `u`.

```
u[x : 1|2|3] := x;

u[y_] := u[y] = -u[y - 3] + 3 u[y - 2] + 2 u[y - 1]
```

The function `evens` returns *n* for any even integer *n* and zero for any odd integer.

```
evens = Mod[# - 1, 2] # &;

Sum[evens @ u @ k, {k, 20}]
```

> ```
> 278878570
> ```

Thanks to memoization much larger sums are practical:

```
Sum[evens @ u @ k, {k, 100000}] // IntegerLength
```

> ```
> 46421
> ```

That's an integer with over 46,000 digits.