# integral, explicit form

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions

I want to estimate the ratio of integrals:

$$
\frac{\int \frac{4 a T^3}{\frac{4 a T^4}{3}+\Lambda_1  \left(\frac{4}{T^3}+1\right)}}{\int \frac{4 a T^3}{\frac{4 a T^4}{3}+\Lambda_0  \left(\frac{4}{T^3}+1\right)}}
$$

where $\Lambda_1$=$\Lambda$ (constant) and $\Lambda_1$=0 for some temperature $T_0$ (arbitrary constants are set to zero).

When I try to integrate the function:

```
f[T_] := (4 a T^3)/(4/3 a T^4 + Λ (1 + 4/T^3))
Integrate[ f[T], T]
```

I get the result like this (with `#` and `&`) :

```
12a RootSum[ 12 Λ + 3 Λ #1^3 + 4 a #1^7 &, (Log[T - #1] #1^4)/(9 Λ + 28 a #1^4) &]
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I get an explicit expression for the integral? 
How do I solve this problem ?

Comment: (1) The [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RootSum.html) provides some helpful hints. (2) Typically there are seven discrete poles of the integrand in the Complex plane, so the best you can hope for--except for some special values of $a$ and $\Lambda$--is precisely a sum over those poles, which is what `RootSum` accomplishes.  What, then, would a more "explicit expression" look like?

Comment: How can I, at least, approximate this function for $T\rightarrow\infty$?

Comment: You can do `Series[f[bigT], {bigT, Infinity, 10}]`.

Comment: The integral diverges logarithmically at $\infty$, because eventually the $4aT^4/3$ term in the denominator overwhelms the other term, giving an integral proportional to $\int dT/T$.

Comment: A comment on the mathematical problem itself: an indefinite integral is defined only up to an arbitrary constant, so for the ratio to be well defined you need additional conditions.

Comment: @Szabolcs A sufficient condition is that one take the same constant for both.

Comment: @Szabolcs To correct myself, I mean it is a sufficient condition whenever the indefinite integral itself goes to infinity in the variable. In this case that happens so we're fine using indefinite integrals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be more appropriate to use this definition :

```
f[T_, a_, Λ_] := (4 a T^3)/(4/3 a T^4 + Λ (1 + 4/T^3))
```

In general you cannot get an explicit expresion (i.e. in terms of radicals) when roots of higher order polynomials are taken into account. There is a fundamental mathematical barrier see e.g. [Abel's Impossibility Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AbelsImpossibilityTheorem.html), [Galois's Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GaloissTheorem.html). Only for special values of `a` and `Λ` you could get it. `Root` and `RootSum` objects are symbolic representations of certain well defined mathematical concepts. So for example you can evaluate them with arbitrary numerical accuracy. For a relation between `RootSum` and `Root` you can use `Normal`, e.g. `Normal @ Integrate[ f[T, a, Λ], T]`. More on `Root` objects you can find here [How do I work with Root objects ?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13767/how-do-i-work-with-root-objects)

You can find the limit of your ratio when `T` goes to  `Infinity` :

```
Limit[  Integrate[ f[T, a, Λ1], T, Assumptions :> {a > 0, Λ1 > 0}]/
          Integrate[ f[T, a, Λ2], T, Assumptions :> {a > 0, Λ2 > 0}] ,
       T -> Infinity]
```

> ```
>  1
> ```

If you have values `a`, `Λ1` and `Λ2` you can compute the ratio for any temerature `T` :

```
ratio[ T_?NumericQ, a_?NumericQ, Λ1_?NumericQ, Λ2_?NumericQ] :=  
  NIntegrate[f[x, a, Λ1], {x, 0, T}]/  NIntegrate[f[x, a, Λ2], {x, 0, T}]
ratio[300, 10, 20, 15]
```

> ```
> 0.990688
> ```

```
Plot[ ratio[T, 10, 20, 15], {T, 0, 300}]
```

[image]

One can see that the ratio is monotonic and tends to `1` quite rapidly.

Comment: Thnx for your help, guys!

Answer (score 4):

Can set it up as below. You need not look at the intermediate results, hence can pretend you never ran into those RootSum things.

```
f[t_, lam_] := (4 a*t^3)/(4/3 a*t^4 + lam*(1 + 4/t^3)); 
f2[t_, lam_] := Integrate[f[t, lam], t];

quot = f2[t, lam0]/f2[t, lam1];
```

Here is the asymptotic behavior of the quotient as t --> infinity.

```
Limit[quot, t -> Infinity, Assumptions -> Element[a, Reals]]

(* Out[144]= 1 *)
```