# What does # mean in Mathematica?

Tags: syntax, core-language

I asked *Mathematica* to compute the following

```
Solve[c (1-x)^2-x^(1/4) == 0, x]
```

and it returned this:

> x = Root[#1^8 c^4 - 8 #1^7 c^4 + 28 #1^6 c^4 - 56 #1^5 c^4 + 70 #1^4 c^4 - 56 #1^3 c^4 + 28 #1^2 c^4 + #1 (-8 c^4-1) + c^4&, 1]

What does this mean? In particular, what's with all the `#`s?

Comment: the coefficient c is a fixed, but arbitrary.

Comment: You may find the Mathematica Documentation Center helpful for questions like this (you can just type # in the search field at the top and it will direct you to an explanation). In any case, here's a web version of the documentation: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Slot.html

Comment: [MathGroup version of the same](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/lHM6yKqQ3Ms/discussion)

Comment: For future reference, click or select a symbol in Mathematica and hit F1 to search for that symbol in the help system.

Answer (score 80):

`#` is a placeholder for an expression.

If you want to define a function, $y(x)=x^2$, you just could do:

```
f = #^2 &
```

The `&` "pumps in" the expression into the `#` sign. That is important for pairing `&` and `#` when you have nested functions.

```
f[2]  
(* 4 *)
```

If you have a function operating on two variables, you could do:

```
f = #1 + #2 &
```

So

```
f[3,4]  
(* 7 *)
```

Or you may have a function operating on a list, like:

```
f = #[[1]] + #[[2]] &
```

So:

```
f[{3,4}]
(* 7 *)
```

#### About `Root[]`

According to *Mathematica* help:

> `Root[f,k]` represents the exact kth root of the polynomial equation f[x]==0  .

So, if your polynomial is $x^2 - 1$, using what we saw above:

```
f = #^2 - 1 &
Root[f, 1]  

(* 
 - 1  (* as we expected ! *)
*)
```

And

```
Root[f, 2]  
(*
  1  (* Thanks God ! *)
*)
```

But if we try with a higher order polynomial:

```
f = -1 - 2 #1 - #1^2 + 2 #1^3 + #1^4 &  
Root[f, 1]

(*
  Root[-1 - 2 #1 - #1^2 + 2 #1^3 + #1^4 &, 1]
*)
```

That means *Mathematica* doesn't know how to calculate a symbolic result for the root. It's just the first root of the polynomial. But it does know its numerical value:

```
 N@Root[-1 - 2 #1 - #1^2 + 2 #1^3 + #1^4 &, 1]
(* -2.13224 *)
```

So, `Root[f,k]` is a kind of stenographic writing for roots of polynomials with order > 3. I'll save you from an explanation about radicals and finding polynomial roots... for the better, I think

Comment: [Original](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4272181). Also, more on [working with `Root` objects](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13768/5)

Comment: @rm-rf It's called migration by self-defense :)

Comment: It's good that it's here now. I remember this came up a long time ago here and I think the migration was either denied or no one cared...

Comment: Note that Mathematica *can* calculate symbolic results for the roots of any polynomial of order 3 or 4, as well as certain higher-order polynomials;  it just doesn't do so by default.  Use `ToRadicals` to get Mathematica to (attempt to) expand these `Root` objects.

Comment: I have been using Mathematica on and off for ten years, but I have never before understood exactly what was happening inside a Root expression. I am quite familiar with pure-function notation, but I did not realize a function was being defined in that context. I thought that was some notation unique to Root. Thank you!

Comment: In [this example](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=y%28x%29+%3D+1%2F2+%285+-+sqrt%284+x%5E3+-+4+e%5Ex+%2B+13%29%29) why doesn't it just use a letter rather than using `#1`?

Answer (score 26):

While the [tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/PureFunctions.html) will undoubtedly explain better that I could the entire topic of pure functions, which is what `Slot`, or `#` has to do with, I'll answer the specific question at hand.

The `Slot` is treated as the argument in an *anonymous* function. Specifically, the code

```
#^2 & // FullForm
```

Reveals that what is actually going on is `Function[Power[Slot[1],2]]`. In other words, the `Slot[1]` indicates the parameter of my unnamed - "pure" - squaring function. The ampersand denotes the end of the pure function (so that in more complicated expressions one could use several pure functions and limit what they do).

Thus, something like `#^2 & [3]` evaluates to `9` (more examples in the linked tutorial).

Now, to address the role of `Root`. For some expressions, such as yours, which can be rewritten as a degree-8 polynomial, there exist no exact algebraic solutions. Thus, MMA does the best it can, showing that the root of a polynomial which takes in an argument `#1` (equivalent to `#`) and transforms it into `#1^8 c^4...` would be the exact solution to your equation.

In this case, your best bet is to quantify all but one parameter and use numerical solving.

Comment: +1 for one of the most concise and clearest descriptions of # and & and pure functions I've read.

Comment: @Jagra I agree with you. Only after I read this explanation I could understand the true meaning of this symbol