# How to only work on sublists with non-zero (or positive) values

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction

i have a large compositional dataset which contains non-zero and zero values. here is a sample:

```
  data = {{22054., 70.62, 0.37, 14.21, 2.89, 0.6, 2.05, 4.18, 4.04}, 
         {22055., 67.84, 0.52, 14.32, 3.77, 0.91, 3., 2.72, 4.62}, 
         {22581., 62.79, 0.62, 13.79, 7.27, 0.46, 2.92, 1.21, 7.97}, 
         {27601., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, 
         {27602., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, 
         {27603., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, 
         {28681., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, 
         {22757., 61.06, 0.77, 16.62, 5.72, 1.66, 4.66, 2.76, 3.46}, 
         {22803., 64.55, 3.01, 16.3, 0.48, 0.09, 0.05, 0.25, 14.29}};
```

i'm trying to convert the values from weight percent to mol percent. i wish to use the following function to generate a new array of the same length (at level 1) as the original:

```
     mw = {60.084, 79.866, 101.961, 71.844, 40.304, 56.077, 61.98, 94.2};

     molPct[oxw_, mw_] :=
        Module[{oxcomp, divmw},
        oxcomp = Drop[oxw, None, 1];
        divmw = Transpose[Transpose[oxcomp]/mw];
        (divmw/ Total[divmw, {2}])*100
        ];

     dataMolPct = molPct[data, mw]
```

unfortunately, this function fails due to the zero elements within the array (where it tries to divide by zero..). this code seems to work fine when i delete the rows containing zero-values.

I tried the following in an attempt to ignore the 'zero' rows:

```
     molPct[oxw_ /; oxw > 0, mw_] :=
        Module[{oxcomp, divmw, oxmol},
        oxcomp = Drop[oxw, None, 1];
        divmw = Transpose[Transpose[oxcomp]/mw];
        (divmw/ Total[divmw, {2}])*100
        ];
```

...no luck

as i said, it is important that i end up with an array of the same size (as i will join the new data onto the original array).

it would be nice to know how to do something similar for excluding negative numbers.

any suggestions?

Comment: Would something like: `With[{tot = Total@#}, 
   If[tot == 0, ConstantArray[0, Length@#], 100 #/tot]] & /@ (#/mw & /@
    Rest /@ data)` produce the output you desire?

Comment: @PinguinDirk, i'm not sure... what would it replace in the code?

Comment: like: `molPct[data_,mw_]:=With[{tot = Total@#}, 
   If[tot == 0, ConstantArray[0, Length@#], 100 #/tot]] & /@ (#/mw & /@
    Rest /@ data)` - I am just checking if I understood the problem correctly. If it works & you like it, I will post a longer answer

Comment: Yes, it seems to work... (not that i have a deep understanding of why?...). i'm both impressed and baffled that you don't need to specify the level.. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As discussed in the comments:

Based on your function, you could for example write something like:

```
molPct[oxw_, mw_] := 
  Module[{oxcomp, divmw}, oxcomp = Drop[oxw, None, 1];
    divmw = Transpose[Transpose[oxcomp]/mw];
    With[{tot = Total@#}, 
    If[tot == 0, ConstantArray[0, Length@#], 100 #/tot]] & /@ 
    divmw];
```

Note that I only changed the last bit, where I use `Map` (or shorter: `/@`) to map the `With`-bit over your `divmw`. I suggest you read the documentation on `Map`, it's a very powerful tool and useful. Intuitively, it goes row-by-row over `divmw` and then first calc's the total `tot` - and then executes the `If` (either constant array of 0's or the division).

As also noted in the comments, one might use the following function to get to the same result:

```
molPct2[data_, mw_] := 
  With[{tot = Total@#}, 
  If[tot == 0, ConstantArray[0, Length@#], 
  100 #/tot]] & /@ (#/mw & /@ Rest /@ data)
```

I personally find that easier to write (and read) and (I didn't test it) supposedly is faster. There are many other ways (smarter ones) to put it, I guess.

Maybe a bit of explanation is appropriate here:

The first bit is the same as in the code I used above in `molPct`. So what about the rest? This is used to create what you named `divmw` - how?

```
(#/mw & /@ Rest /@ data)
```

It starts with `data`. We `Map` the function `Rest` on that (what you used `Drop` for, see documentation). Then we `Map` the function `(#/mw)&` on it, to divide by `mw`. I guess the documentation is a perfect source of explanation on how that mapping actually works (I am terrible at explaining these things).

Comment: on the contrary, i think you explanation is pretty clear. most of the time I find the document center is only useful once I know what i'm doing :-)   thanks again!

Comment: actually, i'm a little confused about the behavior of `#` in this function. `Total@#` and `Length@#` seem to be sampling the entire row (less the first column), whereas `#/tot` and `#/mw` seem to be looking at atoms. is this a correct assessment? if so, where does the switch in directive occur? you might have guessed by now that i'm fairly new to this...

Comment: `#` is `Slot`, and "is used to represent arguments or formal parameters in pure functions of the form body& or Function[body]." (see documentation) - so `Total@#` is missing something. Also note the use of "@" (Prefix) and "/@" (`Map`). Try `f@{a, b}` versus `f/@{a, b}`, you see a difference. So the function `#/mw&` I used was mapped on the "matrix" (list of list) and thus "applied" to each row - do I make sense? :)

Comment: see also: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19035/

Answer (score 3):

*Edit: copied code was invalid; fixed!*

For speed you might try something like this:

```
fn[data_, mw_] :=
 With[{x = (Rest[data\[Transpose]]/mw)\[Transpose]},
   With[{t = Total[x, {2}]}, 100 x t^(1 - 2 Sign@t)]
 ]
```

The double-Transpose you started with is usually one of the fastest methods.  It also looks better in a Notebook than it does here.  The rest is handled numerically (`Sign` etc.) which should be faster on packed arrays of Reals.

Comment: it's a very elegant answer. thanks! i really like the use of `Sign`as a power to vet the data. is there an easy way to modify the implementation so that it also ignores negative numbers?

Comment: @geordie Negative numbers in the totals you mean?

Comment: @geordie hm... I had invalid code in my answer; sorry!

Comment: yes, in the totals but also more generally within a row (it would be nice to flag such instances but i wouldn't alter the values). perhaps this is another question....

Comment: @geordie okay, let me think about that

Comment: @geordie as a simple patch for this method you could use `100 x Clip[t^(1 - 2 Sign@t), {0, \[Infinity]}]` but that's not too elegant.  I'm still thinking about the best way to handle/filter negative values in general.

Comment: this approach causes negative to become zero which is not really ideal. i'm aiming to preserve them unmodified in the new array.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7962/discussion-between-geordie-and-mr-wizard)