# What do the hashtags represent in the result of Solve, and how should I use them?

Tags: equation-solving, functions, evaluation, syntax, algebraic-manipulation

There is a function that I'm trying to get the inverse of. My function is a simple polynomial:

```
Tn[T_] := 4/9 T^3/Tc^2 + 5/9 T
```

Now I tried to find `T` as a function of `Tn`, for which I used Solve:

```
sols=Solve[Tn[x] == a, x, Reals]
{{x -> Root[-9 a Tc^2 + 5 Tc^2 #1 + 4 #1^3 &, 1]}}
```

Plotting it is no problem, which I did by using this:

```
Tc = 1;
Plot[Evaluate[x /. sols], {a, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

But the problem is that I have no idea what the hashtags in the result of Solve denote, and how I should write the function `T(Tn)`. What do the `#`s mean, and how exactly does `T` depend on `Tn`?

Comment: This is a `Root` object; you can look it up in the documentation. The "hashtags" are `Slot`s; they are just a part of the `Root`. In this case it is only a cubic root so you can use `ToRadicals` on it if you prefer that.

Comment: I like this kind of question, as it gives people an additional means of searching "what does # mean?" Maybe we should include synonyms in [the canonical answer on notation](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25616/4330). Maybe we should just have a big table of symbol names that have as an answer a link to the canonical answer on notation. By the way if you search for "problems new users" you wont find the canonical Q&A, maybe that should be renamed "what are the most common problems awaiting new users. Language.. Btw,  [Kind of duplicate](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19035/4330)

Answer (score 4):

**What is Root?**

In Mathematica an *irreducible higher-order polynomial* will be solved, using Root-abjects.

*Root* basically represents the rootNumberth root of the equation:

> Root[ PolynomialAsPureFunction, rootNumber ]

Root objects are used to represent complex numbers and can be calculated to the required precision:

```
N[sols, 40]

{{x->Root[-9.000000000000000000000000000000000000000 a Tc^2 
 +5.000000000000000000000000000000000000000 Tc^2 #1 
 +4.000000000000000000000000000000000000000 #1^3&,1]}}
```

If you apply *Re*, *Im* and *Abs* to a Root-object a new Root-object is generated automatically:

```
Re[x/.sols]

==> {Re[Root[-9 a+5 #1+4 #1^3&,1]]}
```

Let's take the first root:

```
Im[Take[x /. sols, 1]]

==> {Im[Root[-9 a + 5 #1 + 4 #1^3 &, 1]]}
```

Let's take the last root:

```
Abs[Last[x /. sols]] (*no surprises here*)
```

---

Knowing that Root-objects can contain parameters they work perfectly together with other Mathematica functions:

```
root = Root[a - 9 #1^7&, 1];
D[root, a]

Series[root, {a, 2, 2}] // N

Plot3D[Evaluate[Re[root] /. a -> ar + I ai], 
   {ar, -12, 12}, {ai, -12, 12}, PlotPoints -> 30]
```

[image]