# Is it possible to convert expressions containing Root objects to Excel formulas?

Tags: functions, excel

I am still a beginner and do not fully understand pure functions and root objects. When I tried to calculate the inverse of a function, *Mathematica* gave me:

```
f[B_] :=
  -744.790486 + 
  559.361126 Root[-247818634 - 2500 B + 796044875 #1 - 1032864500 #1^2 + 
    675444825 #1^3 - 222213025 #1^4 + 29396850 #1^5 &, 1] -
  0.468197 Root[-247818634 - 2500 B + 796044875 #1 - 1032864500 #1^2 + 
    675444825 #1^3 - 222213025 #1^4 + 29396850 #1^5 &, 1]^2
```

*Mathematica* has no problems evaluating f[B] once B is defined. Simple equations can be easily converted into an Excel-friendly format, but this isn't exactly a simple equation.

My question: Is it possible to format this in a way that Excel can generate the same result as *Mathematica*, or is this simply beyond the scope of what is achievable with Excel?

Comment: Why do you use Excel if you have Mathematica at hand?

Comment: http://www.hec.ca/en/cam/help/topics/Solving_equations_with_Excel.pdf

Comment: [related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19035/what-does-mean-in-mathematica?)

Comment: @belisarius Thank you! The function solver in Excel was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Your `Root` objects look like this:

```
r = Root[-247818634 - 2500 B + 796044875 #1 - 1032864500 #1^2 + 
          675444825 #1^3 - 222213025 #1^4 + 29396850 #1^5 &, 1]
```

and have both the parameter `B` and slot `#1`. One way to make this more Excel-friendly would be to change the slots into a variable like `x`:

```
First[r][x]
-247818634 - 2500 B + 796044875 x - 1032864500 x^2 + 675444825 x^3
                    - 222213025 x^4 + 29396850 x^5
```

Comment: Can Excel actually find the roots to high precision without numerical problems? I had the impression that Excel was a disaster waiting to happen for this sort of thing, just due to horrible numerics implementation.

Comment: It wasn't able to find the roots to high precision, but thankfully it was accurate enough for my purposes.