# what do those signs #1, #1^2, #1^3, & mean here?

Tags: equation-solving, matrix, syntax, symbols, operators

I have read [common pitfalls](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25616/30689) page and the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Slot.html) page but I still don't understand what do those signs mean here?

```
A = {{0.472, 0.008 + 0.01 I, 0.056 - 0.029 I}, {0.008 - 0.01 I, 0.235,
     0.003 - 0.002 I}, {0.056 + 0.029 I, 0.003 + 0.002 I, 0.293}};
Cvol = {{1, 0, 1/3}, {0, 2/3, 0}, {1/3, 0, 1}};
Eigenvalues[A - a*Cvol]
(*{1. Root[(-0.0531814 - 
       2.9302*10^-20 I) + (0.439425 - 
        6.61797*10^-19 I) a - (1.17112 + 0. I) a^2 + 
     1. a^3 + ((0.529735 - 3.65918*10^-19 I) - (2.88169 + 0. I) a + 
        3.75 a^2) #1 + (-1.6875 + 4.5 a) #1^2 + 1.6875 #1^3 &, 1], 
 1. Root[(-0.0531814 - 
       2.9302*10^-20 I) + (0.439425 - 
        6.61797*10^-19 I) a - (1.17112 + 0. I) a^2 + 
     1. a^3 + ((0.529735 - 3.65918*10^-19 I) - (2.88169 + 0. I) a + 
        3.75 a^2) #1 + (-1.6875 + 4.5 a) #1^2 + 1.6875 #1^3 &, 2], 
 1. Root[(-0.0531814 - 
       2.9302*10^-20 I) + (0.439425 - 
        6.61797*10^-19 I) a - (1.17112 + 0. I) a^2 + 
     1. a^3 + ((0.529735 - 3.65918*10^-19 I) - (2.88169 + 0. I) a + 
        3.75 a^2) #1 + (-1.6875 + 4.5 a) #1^2 + 1.6875 #1^3 &, 3]}*)
```

Comment: Likely duplicates: [(13767)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13767/121), [(19035)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19035/121)

Answer (score 2):

The solution to your `Eigenvalues` function are `Root` objects, see the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html).

> `Root[f,k]`
>   represents the exact `k^(th)` root of the polynomial equation `f[x]==0`.

Inside `Root` is the pure function in the argument `#1`. If we named this pure function `f` with argument `x`, this would correspond to the situation in the above quote with `f[x]`.

Your Matrix $A$ is from $\mathbb{C}^{3\times 3}$, so the eigenvalues are solutions of the characteristic polynomial of order $3$. The `#1`, according to the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Slot.html)

> represents the first argument supplied to a pure function.

Because of the parameter `a` mathematica returns an abstract `Root` object instead of a closed solution.