# Meaning of # and & in a RootSum expression

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, notation

I'm working on calculating the first passage time in a continuous time Markov process. To do this, I have to solve a system of 10 coupled differential equations using `DSolve`, and I plan to integrate one of the solutions to get my final answer.

Here is the problem I'm having. `DSolve` accurately calculates the answer but it displays it using `RootSum` with symbols `#1` and `&`. Here is the beginning and end of the solution:

```
RootSum[
  3628800 B^9 + A^8 #1 + 12 A^7 B #1 + 116 A^6 B^2 #1 + 
  (...) 
  2352 A B #1^6 + 8862 B^2 #1^6 + 64 A #1^7 + 432 B #1^7 + 9 #1^8) &]
```

Where `A` and `B` are symbols for arbitrary rational numbers.

I've read in the documentation that the `#` is used as a placeholder for an element of a list following the `&`, which would come at the end of the solution. However, in this case there is no list after the &, so I'm not sure what to make of it.

Comment: See [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html.en) and [`Slot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Slot.html.en)

Comment: See also [1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19035/what-does-mean-in-mathematica) or [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4272067/what-does-mean-in-mathematica)

Comment: Also see [`RootSum`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RootSum.html)