# Solve this equation symbolically

Tags: programming, syntax

I am trying to solve the equation for the quantity r = y/x symbolically:

```
3/y^4 == 3/x^4 + a/(x + 2 y)^4
```

with the requirement that we need to perform the substitution y -> r x and use **Thread** to factor both sides of the equation at the same time.

Here is my attempt:

```
In: {3/y^4 == 3/x^4 + a/(x + 2 y)^4} /. y-> r x
```

> Out: {3/(r^4 x^4) == 3/x^4 + a/(x + 2 r x)^4}

But the above method of course is not completely correct. If I used thread, the output does not change:

```
In: Thread[{3/y^4 == 3/x^4 + a/(x + 2 y)^4} /. y-> r x]
```

> Out: {3/(r^4 x^4) == 3/x^4 + a/(x + 2 r x)^4}

Then I think I have to factor them first by using Thread to both sides:

```
In: Solve[Thread[Factor[{3/y^4 == 3/x^4 + a/(x + 2 y)^4} /. y -> r x], Equal], r]
```

> Out: {{r -> Root[-3 - 24 #1 - 72 #1^2 - 96 #1^3 + (-45 + a) #1^4 + 
>         24 #1^5 + 72 #1^6 + 96 #1^7 + 48 #1^8 &, 1]},
>         {r -> Root[-3 - 24 #1 - 72 #1^2 - 96 #1^3 + (-45 + a) #1^4 + 24 #1^5 + 
>         72 #1^6 + 96 #1^7 + 48 #1^8 &, 2]},
>         {r -> Root[-3 - 24 #1 - 72 #1^2 - 96 #1^3 + (-45 + a) #1^4 + 24 #1^5 + 
>         72 #1^6 + 96 #1^7 + 48 #1^8 &, 3]},
>         {r -> Root[-3 - 24 #1 - 72 #1^2 - 96 #1^3 + (-45 + a) #1^4 + 24 #1^5 + 
>         72 #1^6 + 96 #1^7 + 48 #1^8 &, 4]},
>         {r -> Root[-3 - 24 #1 - 72 #1^2 - 96 #1^3 + (-45 + a) #1^4 + 24 #1^5 + 
>         72 #1^6 + 96 #1^7 + 48 #1^8 &, 5]},
>         {r -> Root[-3 - 24 #1 - 72 #1^2 - 96 #1^3 + (-45 + a) #1^4 + 24 #1^5 + 
>         72 #1^6 + 96 #1^7 + 48 #1^8 &, 6]},
>         {r -> Root[-3 - 24 #1 - 72 #1^2 - 96 #1^3 + (-45 + a) #1^4 + 24 #1^5 + 
>         72 #1^6 + 96 #1^7 + 48 #1^8 &, 7]},
>         {r -> Root[-3 - 24 #1 - 72 #1^2 - 96 #1^3 + (-45 + a) #1^4 + 24 #1^5 + 
>         72 #1^6 + 96 #1^7 + 48 #1^8 &, 8]}}

I am not sure whether my approach is correct.

Then if I want to plot the solution for a$\in${-1,1} which is to examine the number of solutions which are real-valued. Here is what I did:

```
Plot[Table[Solve[Thread[Factor[{3/y^4 == 3/x^4 + a/(x + 2 y)^4} /. y -> r x], Equal], r], {a, -1, 1, 0.02}], {r, -100, 100}]
```

The output showed error and said ivar is not a valid variable. I am not sure what went wrong and how to fix it.

Any helps and comments are greatly welcomed.

Many thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "But the above method of course is not correct?"  You performed the same transformation to both sides of the equation; why is that not correct?  What output do you *wish* to get?

Comment: If you just want to solve equations symbolically, why not use `Solve` ?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I mean it is not an entirely correct method to solve the problem, which is to use Thread to factor both sides of the equation at the same time then solve the equation.

Comment: Please edit your question to include exactly what you expect for output, and the logic by which that is arrived at.  I cannot provide an answer to the question in its present state.

Comment: @xzczd I tried using Solve but it wasn't successful as well. This is what I did Solve[{3/y^4 == 3/x^4 + a/(x + 2 y)^4} /. y-> r x, r]. But the question wants to use Thread, so I assume we cannot use solve.

Comment: Er… So what result do you want? The order of the equation is so high that `Solve` can only give an symbolic solution in that form, and I don't think it can be changed by other approaches.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard It was a question from an exercise. We are not told what output to expect. I have a gut feeling that we need to perform tiny manipulations in order to use Thread. Also, we are not told where did the equation come from and how was it derived. I have reworded to emphasise to solve the equation for r (which is = y/x).

Comment: @xzczd That is all of the question. The expected results are not told beforehand. You are right, I don't think we need to use Solve for the first step, I think we need to factor the equation first to reduce the order then use Solve at the final step if necessary.

Comment: Well, I don't think the order of the equation can be reduced by `Factor`, unless we have a special `a`.

Comment: @xzczd I hope I have correctly reworded the question. This is as far as I can get. Many thanks if anyone can help.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Same here, I hope I have correctly reworded the question. This is as far as I can get. Many thanks if anyone can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not sure what you're aiming for but if you have been instructed to use `Thread` perhaps this will help:

```
eqn = (3/y^4 == 3/x^4 + a/(x + 2 y)^4) /. y -> r x;

Thread[eqn * (r^4 x^4), Equal]
```

> ```
> 3 == r^4 x^4 (3/x^4 + a/(x + 2 r x)^4)
> ```

This merely demonstrates using `Thread` to apply an operation to both sides of the equation at once.

Or, seeing your latest edit, perhaps this is worth a look:

```
sols = Solve[3/y^4 == 3/x^4 + a/(x + 2 y)^4 /. y -> r x, r];

vals = r /. sols;

Plot3D[vals, {a, -1, 1}, {r, -100, 100}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Your method is correct. Now what if I want to solve for r? Can I just do Solve[3 == r^4 x^4 (3/x^4 + a/(x + 2 r x)^4), r]? If you try it, the output doesn't look good, not sure whether that is correct. Thanks

Comment: I am aiming at solving for r. Then analyse the solutions r by varying the values of a. I hope it is clear.

Comment: @user71346 I see I missed a major aspect of your updated question: the `Root` objects!  Please see [this fine answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13768/121).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your answer helps so much. I have accepted and voted for your answer. Just an extra question, can you see whether the solutions are real-valued and how many of them are? I don't know how to tell from the diagram. Don't worry if cannot answer this. Thanks for all your helps.

Comment: @user71346 you could substitute an arbitrary real value for `a` and convert to numeric values with `N`.  This will not prove that certain solutions are always real (I think), but it can help you eliminate the ones that return complex values.  Try: `sols /. a -> 1 // N`

Comment: Wow, great! Yes, I agree I think by checking it's not enough to prove that certain solutions are always real. But thanks heaps! Really appreciate it. :)

Comment: I am trying to substitute a that run between -1 and 1 with steps of 0.02 and get numerical values. I used For loop and here is the code: For[i = -1, i <=  1, i = i + 0.02, vals /. a -> i // N]. But there is no output, I suspect that the i has not yet been substituted into a. Do you know how can I fix this? Thanks again, sorry for asking too many questions :)

Comment: @user71346 `For` does not accumulate output, and is also inefficient here. ([Read this.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7924/121)) Use `Table` instead: `Table[vals, {a, -1, 1, 0.02}]`