# How to get 'exact' expression for result

Tags: syntax

I have a result from *Mathematica* for which want to have the exact expression, i.e. all of the arguments of type `#` replaced.
It is given by:

```
{ a > 0, 
  Inequality[ 0, Less, r, LessEqual, Root[a^3 #1^2 + a^2 #1^4 - 22 a #1^6 + #1^8 & , 5]]}
```

where `a` and `r` are the only two variables. What exactly does the `#1` mean here? To which variables does it refer? How do I make *Mathematica* replace all these place holders with its corresponding variable?

Comment: Use e.g. `Root[a^3 #1^2 + a^2 #1^4 - 22 a #1^6 + #1^8 &, 5] // ToRadicals`. However in general one cannot express `Root` objects in terms of radicals since it is mathematically impossible. See e.g. [How do I work with Root objects?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13767/how-do-i-work-with-root-objects/13768#13768)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Root` objects are just exact expressions, if possible one can express them in terms of radicals (e.g. with `ToRadicals`). To deal with inequalities the best approach might be `Reduce`:

```
ToRadicals @ Reduce[{ a > 0, 
                      Inequality[0, Less, r, LessEqual, 
                      Root[a^3 #1^2 + a^2 #1^4 - 22 a #1^6 + #1^8 &, 5]]},
                      a] // ComplexExpand
```

> ```
>  r > 0 && a >= -(r^2/3) + 2/3 Sqrt[67] r^2 Sin[1/3 ArcTan[227/(3 Sqrt[127947])]]
> ```

```
% // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

and we can get an arbitrarily precise numerical approximation in a standard way, e.g. `40`-digit precission:

```
%% // N[#, 40] &
```

> ```
> r > 0 && a >= 0.04555316444285376876486224542203853971094 r^2
> ```

Comment: Thank you! One more question, for which variable does #1 in this case stand?

Comment: It is an abstract variable see e.g. `Slot`. `Root[a^3 #1^2 + a^2 #1^4 - 22 a #1^6 + #1^8 &, 5]` denotes `5`-th root of the polynomial `a^3 x^2 + a^2 x^4 - 22 a x^6 + x^8`, you can get it with e.g. `a^3 #1^2 + a^2 #1^4 - 22 a #1^6 + #1^8 &[x]`