# How should Root appear in an article containing Mathematica output?

Tags: output-formatting

I have the following output

```
Root[-c + λ^6 + 16 λ^4 μ + 
   104 λ^2 μ^2 + 
   384 μ^3 + (14 λ^4 + 168 λ^2 μ + 
      784 μ^2) #1 + (70 λ^2 + 560 μ) #1^2 + 
   140 #1^3 &, 1]
```

I want to transform the output of the usual form.

Comment: Your question doesn't seem clear - please supply an example of the desired output.

Comment: `ToRadicals[Root[...]]` (see [ToRadicals](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ToRadicals.html))

Comment: Did you look up what `Root` means?  If yes, that provides the answer.

Comment: Try `Root[-c + \[Lambda]^6 + 16 \[Lambda]^4 \[Mu] + 
     104 \[Lambda]^2 \[Mu]^2 + 
     384 \[Mu]^3 + (14 \[Lambda]^4 + 168 \[Lambda]^2 \[Mu] + 
        784 \[Mu]^2) #1 + (70 \[Lambda]^2 + 560 \[Mu]) #1^2 + 
     140 #1^3 &, 1] // ToRadicals // FullSimplify`.

Comment: Thank you. "ToRadicals" is the best answer.

Comment: Related: [(13767)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13767/121),
[(28459)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/28459/121)