# How do I solve $1 - (1 - (A x)^2)^\frac{3}{2} - B(1 - \cos(x))= 0$?

Tags: symbolic, equation-solving

Consider the equation

$$
1 - (1 - (A x)^2)^\frac{3}{2} - B(1 - \cos(x)) = 0
$$

where $A,B \in \mathbb{R}$ are constants.

What is the analytic solution?

Comment: There isn't any in most of such cases. It is transcendental equation. You need `NSolve`.

Comment: `Manipulate` `A` and `B` shows how sensitive the equation is. I'm afraid that an analytic solution is compromised..

Comment: Since you are asking for the analytical solution to the equation is and not how to use *Mathematica* to solve it, I think the question doesn't belong here.

Answer (score 14):

In general, one cannot get explicit analytic solutions of trancendental equations in terms of radicals. This is also the case of univariate higher order polynomial equations. On the other hand since `Mathematica 7` we can find exact solutions (in terms of `Root` objects) of a wide range of (univariate) trancendental equations, for more detailed discussion of these issues see e.g. [How do I work with Root objects?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13767/how-do-i-work-with-root-objects/13768#13768).

To get an insight in the problem try to compare different series expansions of the underlying function around `0, Pi/4` and `Pi/2` respectively, e.g.

```
Column[ Series[1 - (1 - (A x)^2)^(3/2) - B (1 - Cos[x]), {x, Sequence @@ #}]& /@ {
               {0, 6}, 
               {Pi/4, 4}, 
               {Pi/2, 4}},   Frame -> All] // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

Even though the function is analytic, basically one cannot find close-form formulae of its roots. On the other hand there are mathematical theorems which precisely say when we could expect existence of an inverse function, see e.g. the [implicit function theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ImplicitFunctionTheorem.html).

Since we expect certain kind of periodicity in `x` (because of `Cos[x]` term) we'll need to restrict the variable `x` to some bounded region in the complex plane.  There is only one obvious solution for any `a` and `b` in terms of algebraic numbers `x == 0`. Working on the symbolic level with `a` and `b` neither `Solve` nor `Reduce` could find all solutions since the system wasn't able to decide how many solutions there were (in the whole plane we can expect infinitely many).  In general we have to choose values of `a` and `b` as well as  two complex numbers denoting a rectangle  in the complex plane where we want to find all solutions.

```
sol[a_, b_, {c_, d_}] := Solve[ 1 - (1 - a^2 x^2)^(3/2) - b (1 - Cos[x]) == 0  && 
                                Re[c] < Re[x] < Re[d] && 
                                Im[c] < Im[x] < Im[d],     x]// Quiet
```

Let's find solutions for `a == 1` and `b == 2` and `-10 < Re[x] < 10` and `-10 < Im[x] < 10`:

```
sol[1, 2, {-10 - 10 I, 10 + 10 I}]
```

> ```
> {{x -> 0}, {x -> 0}, 
>  {x -> Root[{-1 + 2 Cos[#1] - Sqrt[1 - #1^2] + #1^2 Sqrt[1 - #1^2] &, 
>                -8.919028748106532016537600495313203216599120982717  
>                -7.337134108993067206908899611176545810648199786148 I}]}, 
>  {x -> Root[{-1 + 2 Cos[#1] - Sqrt[1 - #1^2] + #1^2 Sqrt[1 - #1^2] &, 
>                -8.919028748106532016537600495313203216599120982717 
>                + 7.337134108993067206908899611176545810648199786148 I}]}, 
>  {x -> Root[{-1 + 2 Cos[#1] - Sqrt[1 - #1^2] + #1^2 Sqrt[1 - #1^2] &, 
>                0.*10^-49 - 4.745288110568659108440764233893256927171177295653 I}]}, 
>  {x -> Root[{-1 + 2 Cos[#1] - Sqrt[1 - #1^2] + #1^2 Sqrt[1 - #1^2] &, 
>                0.*10^-49 + 4.745288110568659108440764233893256927171177295653 I}]}, 
>  {x -> Root[{-1 + 2 Cos[#1] - Sqrt[1 - #1^2] + #1^2 Sqrt[1 - #1^2] &, 
>                8.919028748106532016537600495313203216599120982717  
>                - 7.337134108993067206908899611176545810648199786148 I}]}, 
>  {x -> Root[{-1 + 2 Cos[#1] - Sqrt[1 - #1^2] + #1^2 Sqrt[1 - #1^2] &, 
>                8.919028748106532016537600495313203216599120982717 
>                + 7.337134108993067206908899611176545810648199786148 I}]}}
> ```

For deeper understanding of the solution space it is usually a good idea to visualize the geometry of the complex function with its roots therein. First we find all solutions in the `Rectangle[{-30, -30}, {30, 30}]` and mark them with the red color.

```
pts = {Re @ #, Im @ #}& /@ (x /. sol[1, 2, {-30 - 30 I, 30 + 30 I}]);
```

there are

```
Length @ DeleteDuplicates @ pts
```

> ```
> 19
> ```

of them, while in the rectangle denoted with the lighter color `Rectangle[{-20, -10}, {20, 10}]` we have

```
Length @ DeleteDuplicates @ sol[1, 2, {-20 - 10 I, 20 + 10 I}] // Quiet
```

> ```
> 11
> ```

Here we provide a graphics with appropriate solutions:

```
GraphicsColumn[ 
  Table[ ContourPlot[ f[1 - (1 - 1^2 (x + I y)^2)^(3/2) - 2 (1 - Cos[(x + I y)])], 
                      {x, -30, 30}, {y, -15, 15}, 
                      AspectRatio -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> "DeepSeaColors", Epilog -> 
                     {{Directive[Opacity[0.25], Cyan], Rectangle[{-20, -10}, {20, 10}]},
                      {Red, PointSize[0.01], Point[pts]}},  Contours -> 11], 
          {f, {Re, Im}}]]
```

[image]