# Solve symbolically a transcendental trigonometric equation and plot its solutions

Tags: trigonometry, equation-solving

I currently have the equation below for a beam with a hinge at various locations, the variable a can vary between 0 and 0.5.
$$
Tan\left( {a\sqrt \alpha  } \right) + Tan\left\{ {\left( {1 - a} \right)\sqrt \alpha  } \right\} - \sqrt \alpha   = 0
$$

I wanted to use this equation to replicate the figure below:

[image: Taken from Exact Solutions for Buckling of Structural Members]

My first thought was to solve the equation so that a= whatever the equation became and then I could plot this to replicate this graph.

I've tried a few different ways to solve this equation but I'm being repeatedly told:

> ```
> Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve.
> ```

A few of the methods I've tried are below...

```
Solve[Tan[a*Sqrt[α]] + Tan[(1 - a)*Sqrt[α]] == Sqrt[α], a]

Reduce[Tan[a*Sqrt[α]] + Tan[(1 - a)*Sqrt[α]] == Sqrt[α], a]

Solve[TrigExpand[
Tan[a*Sqrt[α]] + Tan[(1 - a)*Sqrt[α]]] == Sqrt[α], a]

Reduce[
Tan[a*Sqrt[α]] + Tan[(1 - a)*Sqrt[α]] == Sqrt[α] && Element[
{a, α}, Reals], a]
```

Frustratingly a colleague has managed to get the equation to be rearranged with a as the subject but not with alpha as the subject using *MathCAD* and then I can see that for certain circumstances the solutions are complex.

For completeness the solutions using *MathCAD* are below:

$$
a=a\tan \left( {\frac{{\frac{{\sqrt \alpha  }}{2} - \frac{{\sqrt {\frac{{\alpha \tan \left( {\sqrt \alpha  } \right) - 4\tan \left( {\sqrt \alpha  } \right) + 4\sqrt \alpha  }}{{\tan \left( {\sqrt \alpha  } \right)}}} }}{2}}}{{\sqrt \alpha  }}} \right)
$$

and
$$
a=a\tan \left( {\frac{{\frac{{\sqrt \alpha  }}{2} + \frac{{\sqrt {\frac{{\alpha \tan \left( {\sqrt \alpha  } \right) - 4\tan \left( {\sqrt \alpha  } \right) + 4\sqrt \alpha  }}{{\tan \left( {\sqrt \alpha  } \right)}}} }}{2}}}{{\sqrt \alpha  }}} \right)
$$

My questions for this I guess are:

1. How can I can rearrange and solve equations of this type? *Helping me understand why a simple `Solve` struggles with this would also be genuinely appreciated to help improve my understanding in Mathematica*
2. How to recreate the plot once solved?  *(I'm not concerned with the smaller diagrams that have been added, I will do that myself in illustrator)*
3. Eventually I'm going to want to find the precise maxima of this and similar equations and I'm hoping that will be fairly straightforward once I've got the equation to rearrange into a more convenient format.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

### General remarks

These are are crucial aspects of solving equations symbolically:

- So far (in general) *Mathematica* **cannot** solve transcendental equations when **two unknowns are involved**, nevervetheless in some exceptional cases it may seem like it could (see e.g. [How do I solve this equation?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16897/how-do-i-solve-this-equation/16906#16906)). This is also the case when some symbolic constants are involved  (see [How do I solve 1−(1−(Ax)2)32−B(1−cos(x))=0?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28760/how-do-i-solve-1-1-a-x2-frac32-b1-cosx-0/28763#28763))
- Another problem arises when one doesn't **restrict variables in an appropriate way**, it is the case when we deal with periodic functions, but they are involved in a way that excludes periodic solutions. This case is encountered frequently when there are trigonometric functions in equations. Take a closer look at these two posts: [Can Reduce *really* not solve for x here?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4694/can-reduce-really-not-solve-for-x-here/4697#4697) and  the [second post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28760/how-do-i-solve-1-1-a-x2-frac32-b1-cosx-0/28763#28763) of the first point .
- Another remark regards the fact that in general *Mathematica* assumes that **variables are complex**, however when variables appear in algebriac inequalities then the system assumes that they are real (see e.g. [Solve an equation in R+](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14185/solve-an-equation-in-mathbbr/14188#14188)). When we are to solve an equation in reals one should be be careful since there are subtle issues related, they are quite extensively discussed here [Why doesn't Roots work on a certain quartic equation?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/51598/why-doesnt-roots-work-on-a-certain-quartic-equation/51603#51603)

### The problem at hand

The equation can be solved as follows. Since we have two variables we should define one of them as a variable in a function solving the equation. Another important restriction is that we should restrict the variable `α`. An obvious restriction is that it should be non-negative, however the experssion defining the equation appears to be **singular** at `α == 0` so we should choose an arbitrary constant bounding `α` from below. By singular we mean that there is an infinite range for searching solutions if we assume only that `α > 0`. Instead we assume `α > c` where `c` is positive. We should also assume an upper bound for `α` enabling the system  to complete searching for solutions. So we define the lower and upper bounds as e.g. `1/1000` and `1000` respectively. So we have:

```
sol[a_] /; 0 < a < 1/2 := 
  α /. Solve[ Sqrt[α] Cos[a Sqrt[α]] Cos[Sqrt[α] - a Sqrt[α]] ==
                    Sin[Sqrt[α]] && 1000 > α > 1/1000, {α}]
```

Now we can find all solutions (under the above restrictions). Unlike the other answers suggest there are more solutions than only `2`, e.g.

```
s = sol[1/3]
```

> ```
> { Root[{-Sin[Sqrt[#1]] + Cos[Sqrt[#1]/3] Cos[(2 Sqrt[#1])/3] Sqrt[#1] &, 
>          16.4822373000779225665}], 
>   Root[{-Sin[Sqrt[#1]] + Cos[Sqrt[#1]/3] Cos[(2 Sqrt[#1])/3] Sqrt[#1] &, 
>          47.367354711372064166}], 
>   Root[{-Sin[Sqrt[#1]] + Cos[Sqrt[#1]/3] Cos[(2 Sqrt[#1])/3] Sqrt[#1] &, 
>          135.526521745056346713}], 
>   Root[{-Sin[Sqrt[#1]] + Cos[Sqrt[#1]/3] Cos[(2 Sqrt[#1])/3] Sqrt[#1] &, 
>          193.885084068927115355}], 
>   Root[{-Sin[Sqrt[#1]] + Cos[Sqrt[#1]/3] Cos[(2 Sqrt[#1])/3] Sqrt[#1] &, 
>          269.20855783335694984}], 
>   Root[{-Sin[Sqrt[#1]] + Cos[Sqrt[#1]/3] Cos[(2 Sqrt[#1])/3] Sqrt[#1] &, 
>          446.53942307593795448}], 
>   Root[{-Sin[Sqrt[#1]] + Cos[Sqrt[#1]/3] Cos[(2 Sqrt[#1])/3] Sqrt[#1] &, 
>          549.17432817270068980}], 
>   Root[{-Sin[Sqrt[#1]] + Cos[Sqrt[#1]/3] Cos[(2 Sqrt[#1])/3] Sqrt[#1] &, 
>          668.86391645603933815}], 
>   Root[{-Sin[Sqrt[#1]] + Cos[Sqrt[#1]/3] Cos[(2 Sqrt[#1])/3] Sqrt[#1] &, 
>          935.12993805306825434}]}
> ```

One should remember that `Root` objects are symbolic representations of exact solutions (see [How do I work with Root objects?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13767/how-do-i-work-with-root-objects/13768#13768)).

We add the related plot:

```
ContourPlot[ Sqrt[α] Cos[a Sqrt[α]] Cos[Sqrt[α] - a Sqrt[α]] == 
             Sin[Sqrt[α]], {a, 0, 1/2}, {α, 0, 1000}, 
             PlotPoints -> 50, MaxRecursion -> 4, 
             ContourStyle -> {Darker @ Green, Thick}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
             ImageSize -> 550, Epilog -> { Thickness[0.01], Darker @ Cyan , 
                Line[{{1/3, 0}, {1/3, 1000}}], Red, PointSize[0.02], 
                Point[Thread[{1/3, #}& @ s]]}]
```

where the red points denotes all solutions found on the line `a == 1/3` (in cyan), while green curves denote all solutions restricted by the condition `1000 > α > 1/1000`.

[image]

Without an upper bound for the search the system doesn't tell us if there are any solutions even though one could find them easily

Comment: ...thank you for this excellent post...best and beautiful answer to specific question

Comment: Beautiful explanation, thank you very much I've learned a lot from this post.  I just need to try and follow the simplification of the equation from my original to the one used here now for completeness.

Answer (score 12):

Symbolically solve this equation:

```
Solve[Tan[a Sqrt[α]]+Tan[(1-a) Sqrt[α]]==Sqrt[α]//TrigToExp,a]
Solve[Tan[a Sqrt[α]]+Tan[(1-a) Sqrt[α]]==Sqrt[α]/.a->ArcTan[x]/Sqrt[α] //FullSimplify,x]
```

Updated:

```
expr=Tan[a*Sqrt[α]]+Tan[(1-a)*Sqrt[α]]-Sqrt[α];
expr=FullSimplify@ReleaseHold@Numerator@Together[expr/.Tan[x_]:>Sin[x]/Hold@Cos[x]]
Solve[expr==0,a]//Normal
ContourPlot[expr==0,{a,0,0.5},{α,5,35}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to show how it can be solved symbolically, really appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

Just a way to visualize by rearranging (noting Chenminqi 's observation). Uses: $\tan(x)+\tan(y)=\sin(x+y)/(\cos(x)\cos(y))$. Limiting range important to avoid periodicity and singularities:

```
cp = ContourPlot[
   Sin[Sqrt[y]]/Sqrt[y] == Cos[(1 - x) Sqrt[y]] Cos[ x Sqrt[y]], {x, 
    0, 0.5}, {y, 0, 35}, FrameLabel -> {"a", "\[Alpha]"}, 
   BaseStyle -> 20];
p3 = Plot3D[
   Sin[Sqrt[y]]/Sqrt[y] - Cos[(1 - x) Sqrt[y]] Cos[ x Sqrt[y]], {x, 0,
     0.5}, {y, 0, 35}, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
   MeshStyle -> {Red, Thick}, 
   AxesLabel -> {Style["a", 16], Style["\[Alpha]", 16], None}, 
   PlotLabel -> 
    Style[Sin[x Sqrt[y]]/Sqrt[y] - 
      Cos[(1 - x) Sqrt[y]] Cos[ x Sqrt[y]], Bold]];
Framed[GraphicsRow[{p3, cp}, ImageSize -> 700]]
```

[image]

Comment: It is very ingenious that change tan to sin/cos，so that can avoid  singular points.

Comment: @Chenminqi it was just a hunch (after plotting the surface with tans...an old boss used to say 'better to be lucky than good'[sometimes]

Comment: This really is a thing of beauty, it's going to take me a while to unpick the maths behind it though.... thanks for posting.

Answer (score 8):

Numerical solution：

```
sol[a_] := {a, α} /. 
    First@NSolve[
      Tan[a*Sqrt[α]] + Tan[(1 - a)*Sqrt[α]] == Sqrt[α] && 5 <= α <= 35, α]} // Quiet
ListLinePlot[sol /@ Range[0, 0.5, 0.01]]
```

[image]

I don't know why ContourPlot doesn't work well,even though I change some options of ContourPlot.Maybe it is because there are some singular points.

```
ContourPlot[
  Tan[a*Sqrt[α]] + Tan[(1 - a)*Sqrt[α]] == Sqrt[α], {a, 0, 0.5}, {α, 5, 35}]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 you actually solve the equation (numerically in the right range). I periodicity and singularities in tan form made the contour plot difficult.

Comment: Thanks for showing me how to determine this numerically, good answer...

Answer (score 1):

```
ContourPlot[ Tan[ a Sqrt[al]]/Sqrt[al] + (Tan[ (1 - a ) Sqrt[al]]/Sqrt[al] + 10^-10) == 
  1, {a, -10, 10}, {al, 0, 10}, ContourStyle -> {Thick, Red},
GridLines -> Automatic, AspectRatio -> Automatic]

Plot3D[ Tan[ a Sqrt[al]]/Sqrt[al],{a, -5, 5}, {al, 0, 10}]
```

The extended domain plot is sufficiently regular for tan function with vertical asymptotes, if the jaggedness is overlooked. A 3D plot for part of it shows the general trend.

Near vertical asymptote branches a sufficiently accurate algebraic relation can be derived for larger values using:

$\tan (\pi /2 - eps)\approx 1/ eps $