# Can't solve equation having complex coefficients

Tags: equation-solving, complex

Why can't *Mathematica* solve

$\quad\quad\frac{1-i}{\sqrt{2}}=e^{i \alpha } \tan \left(\frac{\beta
   }{2}\right)$

with the restrictions $\alpha \in [0, 2 \, \pi)$ and $\beta \in [0,\pi]$:

```
Solve[(1 - I)/Sqrt[2] == E^(I alpha) *Tan[beta/2] &&  0 <= beta <= π && 0 <= alpha < 2 π]
```

> Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve.

The solution is $\beta=\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\alpha=\frac{7 \cdot \pi}{4}$.

If I give *Mathematica* the value for $\beta$,

```
Solve[((1 - I)/Sqrt[2] == E^(I alpha) *Tan[beta/2] /. 
  beta -> π/2) && 0 <= beta <= π && 0 <= alpha < 2 π]
```

I get the solution

```
(*{{alpha ->  ConditionalExpression[(7 \[Pi])/4, 0 < beta < \[Pi]]}}*)
```

What is the problem here?

I also tried the other functions like `FindRoot`, `Reduce`, etc.

Comment: Closely related [Symbolically solve and Plot equation involving Tan](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/54896/symbolically-solve-and-plot-equation-involving-tan/54935#54935)

Comment: Wow, Thanks! Do you know why Mathematica can solve it with $\cos[\alpha]+I*\sin[\alpha]$ but not with $\exp[I \alpha]$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use the following:

```
Reduce[(1 - I)/Sqrt[2] == ExpToTrig[Exp[I alpha]]*Tan[beta] &&  0 < beta < Pi && 0 < alpha < 2 Pi];

{ToRules[%]} // FullSimplify
```

> ```
> {{alpha -> (7 π)/4, beta -> π/4}, {alpha -> (3 π)/4, beta -> (3 π)/4}}
> ```

Although I'm not sure why it doesn't work without the `ExpToTrig[]` thing

Comment: I hope you don't mind my edit.  I think it makes the validity of your solution more clear.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Of course. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
Solve[{(1-I)/Sqrt[2]==Exp[I alpha] Tan[beta],0<beta<Pi,0<alpha<2Pi}//ComplexExpand,
{alpha,beta},Method->Reduce]
```