# Solve[ ] doesn't work with transcendental equations

Tags: equation-solving

How to solve x^5-sinx=0 in mathematica?
I try in this way: Solve[x^5 - Sin[x] == 0, x],but t doesn't work.

Comment: It's a transcendental equation, so Mathematica won't be able to solve it.  Try `FindRoot` instead (note that its syntax is somewhat different.)

Comment: "`Solve[ ]` doesn't work with transcendental equations" - your title actually answers your question, y'know.

Comment: @J.M. I was the one who spoiled it

Comment: To close-voters: This can be solved, in a limited way, by Solve.  (Nor IMO is it really clearly exemplified or explained in the documentation.)  Now, I wouldn't be surprised if there's a duplicate lurking somewhere on site....perhaps this: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54896?  Excellent answer by Artes, too.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
Reduce[x^5 - Sin[x] == 0, x, Reals]
```

or if you want the two roots that are close to `-1` and `1` you could do something like

```
Table[FindRoot[x^5 - Sin[x] == 0, {x, i}], {i, {-1, 1}}]
```

Comment: Hi ! Please, click on the gray question mark to the right when posting/asking question and read more about code formatting.

Comment: One can wrap your idea up with `Solve` this way: `Solve[x^5 - Sin[x] == 0, x, Reals, Method -> Reduce]`.  (+1)

Answer (score 2):

Some more ways:  Restricting the domain helps `Solve` out.

Over a real interval:

```
Solve[{x^5 - Sin[x] == 0, -1 <= x <= 1}, x]
(*
  {{x -> 0},
   {x -> Root[{-Sin[#1] + #1^5 &, -0.96103694149677306152}]},
   {x -> Root[{-Sin[#1] + #1^5 &, 0.96103694149677306152}]}}
*)
```

Over a complex rectangle:

```
Solve[{x^5 - Sin[x] == 0, -1 <= Re@x <= 1 && -2 <= Im@x <= 2}, x]
(*
  {{x -> 0},
   {x -> Root[{-Sin[#1] + #1^5 &, -0.961036941496773061523728659911}]},
   {x -> Root[{-Sin[#1] + #1^5 &, 
     0.*10^-60 - 1.04492470949183607101955795081806975589201595243508883000864 I}]},
   {x -> Root[{-Sin[#1] + #1^5 &, 
     0.*10^-60 + 1.04492470949183607101955795081806975589201595243508883000864 I}]},
   {x -> Root[{-Sin[#1] + #1^5 &, 0.961036941496773061523728659911}]}}
*)
```

(See [How do I work with Root objects?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13767/how-do-i-work-with-root-objects), if unfamiliar with `Root`.)