# Solving equation containing ArcTan terms

Tags: equation-solving, trigonometry

I have this expression (see below for context):

```
6.79018*10^-9/f0 - (2.16138*10^-9 ArcTan[Sqrt[Tan[4.62667*10^8 d f0]^2]])/f0
```

and want to solve it for f0.

$d$, $l$, and $f0$ are real positive numbers.

Why can't *Mathematica* solve it by:

```
Solve[
  l == 6.79018*10^-9/f0 - (2.16138*10^-9 ArcTan[Sqrt[Tan[4.62667*10^8 d f0]^2]])/f0,
  f0
]
```

#### Context

The following two equations need to be solved for f0 (dependent on d and l) because I need a contour plot of x axis d, y axis l, and contour f0.

```
 d = 2.16138*10^-9/f0 * ArcTan[Sqrt[ZL/50]]

 l = 6.79018*10^-9/f0 - (2.16138*10^-9 ArcTan[ZL/(Sqrt[50ZL])])/f0
```

My idea is:

1. solve d for ZL (worked)
2. replace ZL in l with the solution of 1. (worked)
3. solve new l for f0. (Error)

d and l are actual lengths (real, positive)
and f0 is a frequency of about 6-6.3Ghz when d=0.0053-0.0055 and l = 0.0049-0.0051

[image]

I made the assumption that ZL - Z0 = ZL. As ZL >> Z0. If Mathematica can manage that without the assumption it would be ever better.

The expressions above show original formula. With

Z0 = 50 (standart characteristic impedance of measurement devices).

$$
\beta = 2\pi \sqrt{4.88}f_0 / c
$$ 
$$
\beta = 2\pi / \lambda
$$

A reference would be [this dissertation](http://e-collection.library.ethz.ch/eserv/eth:6775/eth-6775-02.pdf): (p.48) but beta is defined by some own measurements.

Comment: In general, a transcendental equation like yours does not admit a closed form solution. You might want to try `FindRoot[]` with a good initial guess instead.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! Unfortunately I cant figure it out. I edited my post and describe the original problem. It seems to be a simple task to solve two equations but it wont work. Thanks!

Comment: I have no time to answer your question right now however I recommend to take a look at this post: [Solve symbolically a transcendental trigonometric equation and plot its solutions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/54896/solve-symbolically-a-transcendental-trigonometric-equation-and-plot-its-solution/54935#54935).  If you read it carefully you'll understand your actual problem and find an appropriate solution.

Comment: @mggiable Cab you tell me what this is specifically calculating and any references to the source of the equations? That will help me refine my answer.

Comment: I took the approach of eliminating `f0` and trying to solve for `ZL` -- you can readily show that there are no solutions.

Comment: Thanks I posted the original formulas below!

I cannot manage solving for f0. 

ZL worked for me:  ZL=50 Tan[(d \[Pi])/(d + l)]^2

Comment: The second term in your equation for l is just d, so you have `l = 6.79018*10^-9 / f0 - d` which you can probably solve without a computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updated based on the following formulas provided as additional clarification:

[image]

```
Beta = 2 Pi / Lambda = 2 Pi Sqrt[4.88] f / c
Z0 = 50 and ZL>>Z0
```

Solved:

```
 Solve[{dvar == 1/((2 Pi)/wL) ArcTan[Sqrt[ZL/50]], 
  lvar == wL/2 - 1/((2 Pi)/wL) ArcTan[(ZL)/Sqrt[ZL 50]]}, {wL, ZL}]

{{wL -> 2*(dvar + lvar), ZL -> 50 Tan[(dvar Pi)/(dvar + lvar)]^2}}

v = 299792458/Sqrt[4.88];
ContourPlot[
 f0[dvar_, lvar_] = v/(2 (dvar + lvar)), {dvar, 0, 
  0.06}, {lvar, 0, 0.06}, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
ContourPlot[
 Z[dvar_, lvar_] = 50 Tan[(dvar Pi)/(dvar + lvar)]^2, {dvar, 0, 
  0.06}, {lvar, 0, 0.06}, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you sooooo soooo much!!! Thanks excatly what i needed!

Answer (score 0):

For such complicated functions you can use `FindRoot` over a range of your parameters to get an idea.

```
data = Flatten[Table[{10^8 l, 10^8 d,
 f0 /. FindRoot[l == 6.79018*10^-9/f0 
        - (2.16138*10^-9 ArcTan[Sqrt[Tan[4.62667*10^8 d f0]^2]])/f0, {f0, 0.5}]}
, {l, 2. 10^-8, 50. 10^-8, 10^-8}, {d, 2. 10^-8, 50. 10^-8, 10^-8}], 1];

ListPlot3D[data, AxesLabel -> {"l 10^-8", "d 10^-8", "f0"}]
```

[image]