# Reduce cannot solve my system of trigonometric equations

Tags: equation-solving, trigonometry

I have been running code to solve the following equations for hours and hours, but there are still no solutions! I am new to Mathematica, so I am not really sure whether or not it is a good idea to use `Reduce` to solve trigonometric equations.

Also, I want a symbolic solution, NOT a numeric one.

The code is:

```
eq1 := (Sin[
   Subscript[θ, 1] - Subscript[θ, 
    3]] (-Sin[
       Subscript[θ, 2] - Subscript[θ, 7]] Subscript[
     a, 1] + Cos[
      Subscript[θ, 2] - Subscript[θ, 7]] Subscript[
     a, 2]) + 
 Sin[Subscript[θ, 1] - Subscript[θ, 
    2]] (Sin[
      Subscript[θ, 3] - Subscript[θ, 7]] Subscript[
     b, 1] + Cos[Subscript[θ, 
      7]] (-Cos[Subscript[θ, 3]] + 
       Sin[Subscript[θ, 3]]) Subscript[b, 2])) Subscript[l,
1] Subscript[l, 2] Subscript[l, 3];

eq2 := Sin[
Subscript[θ, 1] - Subscript[θ, 
 4]] (-Cos[
    Subscript[θ, 2] - Subscript[θ, 7]] Subscript[a, 
  2] + Sin[
   Subscript[θ, 2] - Subscript[θ, 7]] (Subscript[a, 
    1] - Subscript[b, 1]) + 
 Cos[Subscript[θ, 
   7]] (Cos[Subscript[θ, 2]] - 
    Sin[Subscript[θ, 2]]) Subscript[b, 2]) Subscript[l, 1]
Subscript[l, 2] Subscript[l, 4];

eq3 := 1/2 Cos[Subscript[θ, 1]] Sin[
Subscript[θ, 2] - Subscript[θ, 
 5]] (-2 Sin[
   Subscript[θ, 3] - Subscript[θ, 7]] Subscript[b, 
  1] + 2 Cos[Subscript[θ, 
   7]] (Cos[Subscript[θ, 3]] - 
    Sin[Subscript[θ, 3]]) Subscript[b, 2]) Subscript[l, 1]
Subscript[l, 2] Subscript[l, 3] Subscript[l, 5];

eq4 := -Sin[
 Subscript[θ, 1] - Subscript[θ, 
  4]] (-Cos[Subscript[θ, 6]] Sin[
   Subscript[θ, 2] - Subscript[θ, 7]] Subscript[a, 
  1] + Cos[Subscript[θ, 6]] Cos[
   Subscript[θ, 2] - Subscript[θ, 7]] Subscript[a, 
  2] + Cos[Subscript[θ, 
   2]] (Sin[
      Subscript[θ, 6] - Subscript[θ, 7]] Subscript[
     b, 1] + Cos[Subscript[θ, 
      7]] (-Cos[Subscript[θ, 6]] + 
       Sin[Subscript[θ, 6]]) Subscript[b, 2])) Subscript[l,
1] Subscript[l, 2] Subscript[l, 4] Subscript[l, 6];

eq5 := -Sin[Subscript[θ, 2] - Subscript[θ, 3]] Sin[
Subscript[θ, 1] - Subscript[θ, 4]] Subscript[l, 1]
Subscript[l, 2] Subscript[l, 3] Subscript[l, 4];

eq6 := Sin[Subscript[θ, 1] - Subscript[θ, 3]] Sin[
Subscript[θ, 2] - Subscript[θ, 5]] Subscript[l, 1]
Subscript[l, 2] Subscript[l, 3] Subscript[l, 5];

eq7 := -Sin[Subscript[θ, 1] - Subscript[θ, 2]] Sin[
Subscript[θ, 3] - Subscript[θ, 6]] Subscript[l, 1]
Subscript[l, 2] Subscript[l, 3] Subscript[l, 6];

sols := Reduce[{eq1 == 0, eq2 == 0, eq3 == 0, eq4 == 0, eq5 == 0, 
eq6 == 0, eq7 == 0}, {Subscript[θ, 1], Subscript[θ, 
2], Subscript[θ, 3], Subscript[θ, 4], 
Subscript[θ, 5], Subscript[θ, 6], 
Subscript[θ, 7]}];
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have reason to believe that a symbolic solution actually exists?  By the way, I suggest avoiding use of subscripted variables.

Comment: You can find θ6 quickly: Reduce[TrigExpand[{eq4==0, eq7==0}], Subscript[\[Theta], 6]] and that might give you some idea how big the full solution might be.

Comment: Read carefuly this answer [Solve symbolically a transcendental trigonometric equation and plot its solutions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/54896/solve-symbolically-a-transcendental-trigonometric-equation-and-plot-its-solution/54935#54935).  Then try to solve it recalling those hints, and at least you'll be able to reformulate your problem in a way to be easily solvable.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no well-posed question in this post; the OP is simply begging for somebody to act as a free debugging service.

Comment: @bbgodfrey I've got 84 eqs like these 7. I manually worked on some them so they had symbolic solutions (at least what I had expected!). Also, `NSlove` cannot solve these 7 eqs either!
Anyway, I do enhance my next codes :-)

Comment: @m_goldberg I am just asking for help as I am really new. By the way, thank you for your comments and revisions. The question looks much nicer now :-)

Comment: @Bill You are right. However, I tried `NSolve[{eq4 == 0, eq7 == 0}, Subscript[\[Theta], 6]]` and it gave an expected solution though with the following error _Inverse functions are being used by NSolve, so some solutions may not \
be found; use Reduce for complete solution information._

Comment: These equations appear to have many solutions.  For instance, `{eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4, eq5, eq6, eq7} /. {Subscript[θ, 5] -> Subscript[θ, 1], Subscript[θ, 4] -> Subscript[θ, 1], Subscript[θ, 3] -> Subscript[θ, 1], Subscript[θ, 2] -> Subscript[θ, 1]}` satisfies all seven equations while leaving the remaining three variables undetermined.

Answer (score 2):

Probably well beyond what can be handled due to the complexity. I'd try changing to a polynomial formulation (replace the trigs with new variables after first using `TrigExpand`), add defining relations between "sine" and "cosine" variables, and see if a Groebner basis can be extracted. The code below shows how one might go about this. Amongst other things, it also removes factors that do not involve the variables of interest, as they (generically) do not vanish.

```
trigs = TrigExpand[{eq1 == 0, eq2 == 0, eq3 == 0, eq4 == 0, eq5 == 0, 
      eq6 == 0, eq7 == 0}[[All, 1]] /. Subscript[th_, n_] -> th[n]];
vars = Cases[Variables[trigs], Sin[_] | Cos[_]];
reprule = {Sin[a_] :> s[a], Cos[a_] :> c[a]};
newtrigs = trigs /. reprule;
newvars = vars /. reprule;
cosvars = Cases[newvars, c[_]];
extratrigs = Map[#^2 + s[#[[1]]]^2 - 1 &, cosvars];

flists = Map[FactorList, newtrigs];
keepflists = 
  Map[Select[#, ! FreeQ[#, Alternatives @@ newvars] &] &, 
    flists, {2}] /. {} -> Nothing;
trigpolys = Apply[Times, keepflists, {1}];
    allpolys = Join[trigpolys, extratrigs]

(* {{a[2] c[θ[2]] c[θ[3]] c[θ[7]] s[θ[1]] - 
   b[2] c[θ[2]] c[θ[3]] c[θ[7]] s[θ[1]] + 
   b[2] c[θ[1]] c[θ[3]] c[θ[7]] s[θ[2]] - 
   a[1] c[θ[3]] c[θ[7]] s[θ[1]] s[θ[2]] - 
   a[2] c[θ[1]] c[θ[2]] c[θ[7]] s[θ[3]] + 
   b[1] c[θ[2]] c[θ[7]] s[θ[1]] s[θ[3]] + 
   b[2] c[θ[2]] c[θ[7]] s[θ[1]] s[θ[3]] + 
   a[1] c[θ[1]] c[θ[7]] s[θ[2]] s[θ[3]] - 
   b[1] c[θ[1]] c[θ[7]] s[θ[2]] s[θ[3]] - 
   b[2] c[θ[1]] c[θ[7]] s[θ[2]] s[θ[3]] + 
   a[1] c[θ[2]] c[θ[3]] s[θ[1]] s[θ[7]] - 
   b[1] c[θ[2]] c[θ[3]] s[θ[1]] s[θ[7]] + 
   b[1] c[θ[1]] c[θ[3]] s[θ[2]] s[θ[7]] + 
   a[2] c[θ[3]] s[θ[1]] s[θ[2]] s[θ[7]] - 
   a[1] c[θ[1]] c[θ[2]] s[θ[3]] s[θ[7]] - 
   a[2] c[θ[1]] s[θ[2]] s[θ[3]] s[θ[
      7]]}, {(c[θ[4]] s[θ[1]] - 
     c[θ[1]] s[θ[4]]) (a[
       2] c[θ[2]] c[θ[7]] - 
     b[2] c[θ[2]] c[θ[7]] - 
     a[1] c[θ[7]] s[θ[2]] + 
     b[1] c[θ[7]] s[θ[2]] + 
     b[2] c[θ[7]] s[θ[2]] + 
     a[1] c[θ[2]] s[θ[7]] - 
     b[1] c[θ[2]] s[θ[7]] + 
     a[2] s[θ[2]] s[θ[7]])}, {c[θ[
     1]] (c[θ[5]] s[θ[2]] - 
     c[θ[2]] s[θ[5]]) (b[
       2] c[θ[3]] c[θ[7]] - 
     b[1] c[θ[7]] s[θ[3]] - 
     b[2] c[θ[7]] s[θ[3]] + 
     b[1] c[θ[3]] s[θ[7]])}, {(c[θ[
        4]] s[θ[1]] - 
     c[θ[1]] s[θ[4]]) (a[
       2] c[θ[2]] c[θ[6]] c[θ[7]] - 
     b[2] c[θ[2]] c[θ[6]] c[θ[7]] - 
     a[1] c[θ[6]] c[θ[7]] s[θ[2]] + 
     b[1] c[θ[2]] c[θ[7]] s[θ[6]] + 
     b[2] c[θ[2]] c[θ[7]] s[θ[6]] + 
     a[1] c[θ[2]] c[θ[6]] s[θ[7]] - 
     b[1] c[θ[2]] c[θ[6]] s[θ[7]] + 
     a[2] c[θ[6]] s[θ[2]] s[θ[
        7]])}, {(c[θ[3]] s[θ[2]] - 
     c[θ[2]] s[θ[3]]) (c[θ[4]] s[θ[1]] - 
     c[θ[1]] s[θ[4]])}, {(c[θ[3]] s[θ[
        1]] - c[θ[1]] s[θ[3]]) (c[θ[
        5]] s[θ[2]] - 
     c[θ[2]] s[θ[5]])}, {(c[θ[2]] s[θ[
        1]] - c[θ[1]] s[θ[2]]) (c[θ[
        6]] s[θ[3]] - c[θ[3]] s[θ[6]])}, -1 + 
  c[θ[1]]^2 + s[θ[1]]^2, -1 + c[θ[2]]^2 + 
  s[θ[2]]^2, -1 + c[θ[3]]^2 + s[θ[3]]^2, -1 + 
  c[θ[4]]^2 + s[θ[4]]^2, -1 + c[θ[5]]^2 + 
  s[θ[5]]^2, -1 + c[θ[6]]^2 + s[θ[6]]^2, -1 + 
  c[θ[7]]^2 + s[θ[7]]^2} *)
```

I have no idea whether this will run to completion, let alone how useful it will be if it does (the size could be way to big to use in further manipulations).

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 gb = GroebnerBasis[allpolys, newvars, 
    MonomialOrder -> DegreeReverseLexicographic, 
    CoefficientDomain -> RationalFunctions];]
```