# Solving an equation approximately

Tags: equation-solving, numerical-value

I have a complicated equation in terms of $\omega$ and $\kappa$:

```
Tan[Sqrt[-κ^2 + ω^2*(1 + (1 - ω^2)^(-1))]/2] ==
  (ω^2*Sqrt[25 + κ^2 - ω^2]*(-2 + ω^2))/((25 - 26*ω^2 + ω^4)*Sqrt[(κ^2 - 2*ω^2 - κ^2*ω^2 + ω^4)/(-1 + ω^2)])
```

Solving this for $\omega$ and plotting the result in terms of $\kappa$ was not successful since *Mathematica* couldn't even solve for  $\omega$ analytically. Is there an efficient numerical approximation that I could use to solve for $\omega$ and if not, is there at least a nice way to plot $\omega$ as a function of $\kappa$?

I have tried to use `NSolve[]` instead but *Mathematica* tells me that it's still not able to solve the equation. Furthermore, I tried expanding both sides in a Taylor series and then solve for $\omega$, but the resulting plot is different for different orders of the expansion...

Comment: Can you give an approximate value for kappa?

Comment: `ListPlot[Table[{κ, (ω /. 
     Chop@FindRoot[eqn, {ω, 1.4}])}, {κ, -10, 10, 0.1}]]`

Comment: @mikado I would like to plot $\omega$ as a function of $\kappa$ so it should hold for all $\kappa$. I am in particular interested in the range $0<\kappa<10$.

Comment: Differentiate implicitly with respect to kappa to get an ODE which you can then integrate with NDSolve[]

Comment: Your question should contain justification for searching for solutions to such an equation. This is a quite sophisticated problem, which is not exposed sufficiently neither by the question nor by the answers. Take a look e.g. at an analogous problem [Solve symbolically a transcendental trigonometric equation and plot its solutions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/54896/solve-symbolically-a-transcendental-trigonometric-equation-and-plot-its-solution/54935#54935).

Comment: @MichaelE2:  That's your answer for everything.  :-)

Comment: Agree with @Artes .  It appears you've created a detailed exact expression for some physical system.  It is often much faster & more productive to observe the general shape of the output curve and fit a set of data points to a relatively simple function such as a polynomial plus trig funcs.  Take a look at Eureqa , perhaps.

Comment: @MichaelE2 That is in this case unfortunately not so easy. Mathematica still has issues solving this differential equation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you are root-finding on the function

```
f[k_, w_] = -((w^2 Sqrt[25 + k^2 - w^2] (-2 + w^2))/((25 - 26 w^2 + w^4) Sqrt[(k^2 - 2 w^2 - k^2 w^2 + w^4)/(-1 + w^2)])) + Tan[1/2 Sqrt[-k^2 + w^2 (1 + 1/(1 - w^2))]];
```

Any time you are root-finding on a function that diverges to a zero in some denominator somewhere, numerically finding roots is going to be a problem.  If there's some unlucky cancellation that occurs, there might be roots at points where the denominator is zero, but we can proceed as if this is *not* the case, and check our work at the end. Then, multiplying by the denominator (which is assumed to be non-zero) cannot change the roots of our equation.

To that end, let's define a new function that gets rid of the denominator:

```
f2[k_, w_] = f[k, w] Denominator@Together@f[k, w] // Expand // Simplify;
```

There are then two ways to go about finding the roots of this function.  One way is to use `FindRoot`, but my favorite is to use `ContourPlot`:

```
ContourPlot[f2[k, w], {k, -2 π, 2 π}, {w, 0, 6}, Contours -> {0}, ContourShading -> False]
```

[image]

You can then extract the points from the graph using

```
pts = Cases[Normal@pC, Line[a_] :> a, Infinity];
```

and refine them using `FindRoot`:

```
refinedPoints = Map[
   Prepend[FindRoot[f2[#[[1]], w] == 0, {w, #[[2]]}, MaxIterations -> 10000], k -> #[[1]]] &,
   pts, {2}] // Chop;
```

Then,

```
{k, w} /. refinedPoints // ListLinePlot
```

[image]

Finally, there's a little bit of trouble when we get to larger values of $\kappa$.  To figure out what's going on there, we do the following:

```
PowerExpand@ComplexExpand@Normal@Series[f[k, w], {k, ∞, 1}]
Limit[%, k -> ∞]
Solve[% == 0, w]
N@%
```

which yields

```
(* I (-((2 w^2)/(25 - 26 w^2 + w^4)) + w^4/(25 - 26 w^2 + w^4) + Sinh[k]/(1 + Cosh[k]))
   (I (25 - 28 w^2 + 2 w^4))/(25 - 26 w^2 + w^4)
   {{w -> -Sqrt[1/2 (14 - Sqrt[146])]}, {w -> Sqrt[1/2 (14 - Sqrt[146])]},
    {w -> -Sqrt[1/2 (14 + Sqrt[146])]}, {w -> Sqrt[1/2 (14 + Sqrt[146])]}}
   {{w -> -0.979018}, {w -> 0.979018}, {w -> -3.6113}, {w -> 3.6113}} *)
```

so we can see the limiting values of $\omega$ at the wings.

Comment: Great answer! Could you maybe also tell me whether there is a way to minimize the gaps in the upper and lower graph? I would like to put this figure in a report and it would look nice if the graphs were continuous.

Comment: @xabdax The orange line is not a solution, but rather a complex infinity point.

Comment: @yarchik.  I thought that might be the case, but I didn't have time to investigate it. I'm guessing that that's the curve along which the tangent is infinite.

Comment: Probably. Also, there are infinitely many solutions approaching $\omega=1$. See my analysis below. Unfortunately, I do not know how to find at least a couple of them with `ContourPlot`.

Comment: @yarchik. By plotting the function at $k=0$ from $\omega=0$ to $\omega = 6$, there's a clear zero at the base of the upper branch, so actually I think that upper branch is real.  Otherwise, I see how there are a bunch of solutions that pile up near $\omega=1$, and in between those solutions there are a bunch of vertical asymptotes.  Obviously, these roots are going to be hard to find.

Comment: Yes, absolutely agree, the upper branch starting 4.2... is real. The branch starting at 1.4... is a pathological case (not a solution). As for the roots bunching below 1.0, it is really a hard case. I think some reformulation of the problem is needed in order to catch them.

Comment: @yarchik.  Got it. That root was actually introduced by multiplying through by the denominator as I did; I didn't expect that that could cause problems.

Comment: @xabdax.  Make sure to read the comments under my post. Some of these branches I found are not actually real, and there's the added complication of infinitely many roots near $\omega=1$ that we haven't figured out how to deal with.

Comment: @march yes, thanks for the note. This is actually based on a physics problem and your plot resembles what I would have expected :)

Comment: @xabdax. All the more reason to be careful! You'll have to argue why you can get rid of some of those spurious solutions.

Answer (score 6):

### Overview

The situation is quite complicated. This is not the full solution, but just an overview.

- `gz` is a region (shaded area) where the equation is real.
- `gy` is the red contour showing where the imaginary part is equal to zero or diverging.
- Finally `gx` is a black line showing one of the desired solutions. There are infinitely many other solutions not depicted here. See discussion below.

---

```
eq=Tan[Sqrt[-κ^2+ω^2*(1+(1-ω^2)^(-1))]/2]-(ω^2 Sqrt[25+κ^2-ω^2] (-2+ω^2))/((25-26 ω^2+ω^4) Sqrt[(κ^2-2 ω^2-κ^2 ω^2+ω^4)/(-1+ω^2)])
gx=ContourPlot[eq==0,{κ,0,6},{ω,0,6},RegionFunction->Function[{κ,ω,z},-κ^2+ω^2 (1+1/(1-ω^2))>0&&25+κ^2-ω^2>0&&(κ^2-2 ω^2-κ^2 ω^2+ω^4)/(-1+ω^2)>0],ContourStyle->{Black,Thick},PlotPoints->30,MaxRecursion->4]
gy=ContourPlot[Im[eq]==0,{κ,0,6},{ω,0,6},PlotPoints->50,MaxRecursion->5,ContourStyle->{Red,Thick}]
gz=RegionPlot[-κ^2+ω^2 (1+1/(1-ω^2))>0&&25+κ^2-ω^2>0&&(κ^2-2 ω^2-κ^2 ω^2+ω^4)/(-1+ω^2)>0,{κ,0,6},{ω,0,6},PlotPoints->50,MaxRecursion->5]
Show[{gz,gx,gy}]
```

[image]

### Finer details

There are **infinitely many** solution branches approaching $\omega=1$! This can be seen by setting, e.g., $\kappa=1$ and plotting the function in the vicinity of $\omega=1$. Contour plot, of course, cannot catch them.