# Solving inequality

Tags: equation-solving, inequalities

I am trying to solve this inequality for $\eta$,

[image]

where B, J, $\eta$, and $\beta$ are reals and $\beta$>0. I used

```
f[\[Eta]_]:=(B^2+2 J^2+B^2 Cosh[2 \[Beta] \[Eta]])/(2 \[Eta]^2 Cosh[J \[Beta]] Cosh[\[Beta] \[Eta]]+2 J \[Eta] Sinh[J \[Beta]] Sinh[\[Beta] \[Eta]])
Reduce[f[\[Eta]]>=1,\[Eta]]
```

But I got nothing. Is this possible using Mathematica?

Comment: You are expecting an analytical solution for B?
It looks like your equation does not have analytical solution.

Comment: @Cruz What about now?. Please see the edit.

Comment: I still think that your equation cannot be solved analytically, however I can't prove it.

How do you conclude that this equation has an analytical solution?

Comment: Given `\[Beta] , J, B ` one can solve this inequality e.g. `With[{\[Beta] = 1, J = 1, B = 1/2}, 
 Reduce[(B^2 + 2 J^2 + B^2 Cosh[2 \[Beta] \[Eta]])/(2 \[Eta]^2 Cosh[  J \[Beta]] Cosh[\[Beta] \[Eta]] + 
      2 J \[Eta] Sinh[J \[Beta]] Sinh[\[Beta] \[Eta]]) >= 1, \[Eta], 
  Reals]]`.  Otherwise one cannot solve it symbolically, see e.g. [Solve symbolically a transcendental trigonometric equation and plot its solutions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/54896/solve-symbolically-a-transcendental-trigonometric-equation-and-plot-its-solution/54935#54935) and references therein.