# Solving a trigonometric equation with discrete solutions

Tags: equation-solving, trigonometry

So I know that trigonometric equations show up here very often, but this one is particularly difficult and important to me, so that I was hoping to get some valuable hints from people who know more about equation solving than I do.

I would like to solve the following equations:
$$f(x)=\sqrt{a \left(c^2-b \left(c^2+x^2\right)\right)+\left(c^2+x^2\right) \left((b-1) c^2+b x^2-e\right)}/\sqrt{-a+c^2+x^2}$$
$$x \cot (x\,d)=-f(x) \cot (f(x)\,d)$$
or in code form:

```
f[x_] = Sqrt[(c^2 + x^2) ((-1 + b) c^2 - e + b x^2) + a (c^2 - b (c^2 + x^2))]/Sqrt[-a + c^2 + x^2]
x Cot[x d] == -f[x] Cot[f[x] d]
```

where a, b, c, d and e are arbitrary constants which can become very small (~1e-30) or very large (~1e30).

I tried FindRoot[], which works very well for constants of the order of ~1e0 to ~1e1 but breaks down for extremely big or small numbers. In particular, I find multiple duplicates, and solutions that do not actually solve the equation above. To make the code more stable, I squared both sides of the second equation (the roots don't change), as FindRoot[] converges quicker for positive functions. Furthermore, looking at the graphs for the RHS and LHS of the second equation, one can see that the cotangent has a $\pi$-periodicity which helps determining the range in which FindRoot is supposed to look for solutions:

```
FR[n_] := FindRoot[(x Cot[x d])^2 == (-f[x] Cot[f[x] d])^2, {x,Pi*n/4 - 0.001, Pi*(n + 1)/4 - 0.001}]
sol = Map[FR, Range[0, 50, 1]];
p1 = Plot[{x Cot[x d],-f[x] Cot[f[x] d]}, {x, 1, 40}];
p2 = ListPlot[Transpose[{x /. sol, x Cot[x d] /. sol}]];
Show[p1, p2, PlotRange -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Unfortunately, this does not work so smoothly for extreme values such as

```
a = 10^14; b = 10^(-18); c = 10^6; d = 10; e = 10^(-18);
```

Could someone tell me how I can make this code more stable or suggest an alternative way of solving this equation?

Comment: I would suggest to use rational values 1/1000 instead of  0.001 and explicitly  set WorkingPrecision for  FindRoot to value larger that MachinePrecision, i.e WorkingPrecision->17. If that will not help, please provide explicit values for which you obtain parasite solutions.

Comment: Working with a nonlinear trigonometric equation it is resonable to take into acount a few hints e.g. listed in this answer: [Solve symbolically a transcendental trigonometric equation and plot its solutions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/54896/solve-symbolically-a-transcendental-trigonometric-equation-and-plot-its-solution/54935#54935)

Comment: It might help to know a little more about your ultimate goal. You mention periodicity, but the periodicity of the two expressions is not equal so only special cases where the periods are commensurable will yield a finite number of unique solutions. You're obviously not looking for an analytical expression. How many numerical solutions do you need?

Comment: @user18792 I updated the question with some explicit values for which I would like to find a solution. Setting the WorkingPrecision did not give me any useful results after Mathematica ran for 45 min so I aborted the computation.

Comment: @Artes I believe that this problem cannot be compared to the one in the link that you provided. This is because my equation has discrete values as solutions while the other question used a function with a continuous set of solutions.

Comment: @N.J.Evans That is true, but determining the periodicity of one equation should be sufficient to let FindRoot know in which interval it is supposed look for solutions. I would like to see the first 100 numerical solutions. Btw, if there is a way to solve this problem analytically, that would be even better.

Comment: For the example you give with extreme values the numerator is imaginary for x^2 less than about ~10^14. Because f has a complicated dependence on the parameters you need to be careful. If you are restricting yourself to real numbers, not all parameters will lead to a valid equation for all values of x.

Comment: For the given parameter values vals = {a -> 10^14, b -> 10^(-18), c -> 10^6, d -> 10, e -> 10^(-18)} I obtain imaginary value for f[x]. Indeed it violates the condition given by  sols2 = Reduce[-a + c^2 + x^2 > 0, {x}, Reals] then sols2 /. vals // N yields x < -9.94987*10^6 || x > 9.94987*10^6 which is incompatible with starting value Pi*1/4 + 1/1000 // N  which gives 0.786398,  for n=1.

Comment: @N.J.Evans Even though it is true that for the given parameters f(x) will become imaginary, it seems like the second equation above can still be solved with real x below the threshold that you give. I find that for roughly `x = (Pi - 0.314*10^(-6))` the equation is solved despite x being smaller that 10^14

Comment: @user18792 The starting value Pi*1/4 + 1/1000 was actually not meant to be carved in stone, but rather a dirty way to avoid singularities. I still need to find a better way to make FindRoot search in the relevant intervals without running into trouble.

Comment: I want to say, that once your set parameters values, then before calling FindRoot your have to check that f[x] yields real values for starting search interval. One way to get conditions for them is to use Reduce in the above way (both for numerator and denominator)

Comment: Just an observation: the second equation is, roughly, $x\cot(x) + y\cot(y)=0$. The set of solutions is a set of closed curves that can be easily solved numerically, and plotted with  `ContourPlot[x*Cot[x] + y*Cot[y] == 0, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}]`. You want to find the intersection of these curves with the curves $y=d f(x/d)$. I believe this way of tackling the problem makes it simpler, numerically, as you decouple the cotan with the rational function $f^2$.

Comment: @anderstood That sounds like a promising approach. How would I find the intersection of the contour plot and y= d f(x/d)? Is there a function in Mathematica that does that efficiently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am expanding on my comment. You want to find $x,y$ such that:

$$ X\cot X + Y\cot Y =0, \ X=d\times x,\ Y=d\times y, \quad \text{and}\quad Y=f(X).$$

$d$ can be seen as a scaling parameter, for simplicity I write the equations here with $d=1$.
The problem becomes:

$$x\cot x + y \cot y=0\quad\text{and}\quad y=f(x)$$

These are two equations, that individually are not too complicated. We are going to take advantage of this uncoupling to simplify the numerical resolution.

*A side node*: the first equation can be visualized with `ContourPlot`:

```
 ContourPlot[{x*Cot[x] + y*Cot[y] == 0}, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, PlotPoints -> 25]
```

[image]

It is a family of curves that must be not too difficult to find by continuation. Of course the obvious symmetries $y=x$, $x=0$ and $y=0$ should be considered to reduce the computational cost by 8. You are looking for the intersection of these curves with $f(x)=y$.
*End of side note*

Now, you can see that $f^2$ is quite a simple function:

```
f[x_] = Sqrt[(c^2 + x^2)((-1 + b) c^2 - e + b x^2)+a(c^2 - b (c^2 + x^2))]/Sqrt[-a + c^2 + x^2];
f[x]^2 // FullSimplify
(* (-1 + b) c^2 + b x^2 + e (-1 - a/(-a + c^2 + x^2)) *)
```

This is an indication that *Mathematica* can find analytical solutions to $f(x)=y$:

```
xsol = x /. Solve[f[x] == y, x] // Last // Simplify
(* Sqrt[(a b + c^2 - 2 b c^2 + e + y^2 + Sqrt[ a^2 b^2 - 2 a b (c^2 - e + y^2) + (c^2 + e + y^2)^2])/b]/Sqrt[2] *)
```

Not that `Solve` returned 4 solutions, I just kept the last one since it corresponded the real and positive value with the set of parameter I played with.

We can plug that back into the $\cot$ equation:

```
toroot[y_] = Simplify[xsol*Cot[xsol*d] + f[xsol]*Cot[f[xsol]*d], 
                    Assumptions -> a > 0 && b > 0 && c > 0 && d > 0 && e > 0 && y > 0]
```

[image]

and you end up with a nice, not too complicated function, to solve.

---

Example 1

```
a = b = c = d = e = 1;
NSolve[{toroot[y], 0 <= y <= 10}, y]
Plot[toroot[y], {y, 0, 20}]
(* {{y -> 1.32709}, {y -> 3.05686}, {y -> 4.65635}, {y -> 6.24267}, {y ->
7.82151}, {y -> 9.39803}} *)
```

[image]

That gives you the $y$ values. Compute the $x$ using: `xsol /. y -> ...`

---

Example 2

Here, due to the large ratio between `a` and `b`, we need to drastically increase `WorkingPrecision`. Also, `toroot` is highly oscillatory so I restrict the domain to $[0.999, 1]$

```
a = 10^14; b = 10^(-18); c = 10^6; d = 10; e = 10^(-18);
NSolve[{toroot[y], 0.999 <= y <= 1.}, y, WorkingPrecision -> 100]
Plot[toroot[y], {y, 0.999, 1.}, WorkingPrecision -> 100]
(* {{y -> 0.9991315326455330769499064220676412494508654045149413025951079\
    640308969038148391768838923514208798058}, 
    {y -> 0.99944591552386175181844643447881974202302427515487185004566648939\
     95674269572854160671851261222602081}} *)
```

We can check that it is an actual solution:

```
 xtmp = xsol /. First[NSolve[{toroot[y], 0.999 <= y <= 1.}, y, WorkingPrecision -> 100]]
 xtmp*Cot[d*xtmp] + f[xtmp]*Cot[d*f@xtmp]
 (* 0.*10^-82 *)
```

[image]

Comment: It seems like NSolve does a good job finding the roots in Example 1, but Example 2 is not very convincing. If you use the results to find the x values and then insert these x values into `xsol*Cot[xsol*d] + f[xsol]*Cot[f[xsol]*d]` you would expect this expression to become zero. That is not quite what is happening, so I assume that NSolve fails for highly oscillatory functions.

Comment: @xabdax Most likely due to the huge values involved.  Have you tried increasing `WorkingPrecision`?

Comment: Yes, that helps! Great answer by the way!