# Solve-ing with initially unassigned parameters and Solve-ing using their numerical values produces different results

Tags: equation-solving, numerics

I am trying to solve an equation using the following piece of code:

```
f[t_] = Aa*t^4 + Bb*t^3 + Cc*t^2 + Dd;

s = Solve[f[t] == 0, t];

t1 = t /. s[[1]];
t2 = t /. s[[2]];
t3 = t /. s[[3]];
t4 = t /. s[[4]];
```

And it gives me four symbolic formulas.

Then, I try to give numbers to the `Aa`, `Bb`, `Cc`, `Dd` parameters:

```
Aa = 1.2347931365926803*10^30 ;
Bb = 4.6356322739291924*10^23 ;
Cc  = 4.350806821541392*10^16 ;
Dd = -1.2562823055999998*10^6 ;
```

and the formulas provide the results:

```
-7.18016*10^-7 - 6.17065*10^-7 I
5.30307*10^-7 + 6.17065*10^-7 I
-7.18016*10^-7 + 6.17065*10^-7 I
5.30307*10^-7 - 6.17065*10^-7 I
```

But, if I solve using the numerical values of `Aa`, `Bb`, `Cc`, `Dd` from the beginning, I get:

```
-1.10255*10^-6
-9.38545*10^-8 - 9.99928*10^-7 I
-9.38545*10^-8 + 9.99928*10^-7 I
 9.14844*10^-7
```

I have also noticed that this behavior is sensitive to the values I give to the parameters.
Using these instead,

```
Aa = 2.8262007068794462*10^25;
Bb = -5.389762192271189*10^21;
Cc = 2.5696632603084144*10^17;
Dd = -1.2213607220736102*10^6;
```

the problem seems to still be there, but not as serious.
Any ideas on what might be causing this and maybe a way to avoid it?

Answer (score 3):

We encounter here numerical incompatibility of reducing the exact solutions written in terms of radicals by some arbitrary numerical parameters and merely numerically solving of corresponding algebraic equations.
In fact it is not  really surprising taking into account values of given parameters. 
We might guess this effect appears  more significant when the parameters get higher absolute values and become more asymmetric.

The documentation of [`ToRadicals`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ToRadicals.html?q=ToRadicals&lang=en)  says (see e.g. Details and Options ):

> ```
> If Root objects in expr contain parameters, ToRadicals[expr] may yield a result that 
> is not equal to expr for all values of the parameters.
> ```

At first we define:

```
f[t_] := a t^4 + b t^3 + c t^2 + d

ncoeff = { a :> 1.2347931365926803*10^30, b :> 4.6356322739291924*10^23, 
           c :> 4.350806821541392*10^16, d :> -1.2562823055999998*10^6  };

fn[t_] := f[t] /. ncoeff
```

If we prevent getting solutions in terms of radicals there'll be no problems anymore. We can use e.g. the `Quartics -> False` option of `Solve`:

```
{t1e, t2e, t3e, t4e} = t /. Solve[ f[t] == 0, t, Quartics -> False]
```

> ```
> {Root[d + c #1^2 + b #1^3 + a #1^4 &, 1], Root[d + c #1^2 + b #1^3 + a #1^4 &, 2], 
>  Root[d + c #1^2 + b #1^3 + a #1^4 &, 3], Root[d + c #1^2 + b #1^3 + a #1^4 &, 4]}
> ```

now we have:

```
{t1e, t2e, t3e, t4e} /. ncoeff
```

> ```
>  {-1.10255*10^-6, 9.14844*10^-7, 
>   -9.38545*10^-8 - 9.99928*10^-7 I, -9.38545*10^-8 + 9.99928*10^-7 I}
> ```

and this result is numerically equal to numerical solutions.

```
t /. Solve[ fn[t] == 0, t]
```

> ```
> { -1.10255*10^-6, -9.38545*10^-8 - 9.99928*10^-7 I, 
>   -9.38545*10^-8 + 9.99928*10^-7 I, 9.14844*10^-7}
> ```

as well as

```
t /. FindRoot[ fn[t], {t, #}] & /@ {-10^-6, 10^-6, 10^-7 (-1 - 10 I), 10^-7 (-1 + 10 I)}
```

> ```
> { -1.10255*10^-6, 9.14844*10^-7, 
>   -9.38545*10^-8 - 9.99928*10^-7 I, -9.38545*10^-8 + 9.99928*10^-7 I}
> ```

Now there is no ambiguity of the results.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Artes! The thing is that I was going for the analytical solution, because I want to use it in a fortran code. The way Solve provided it mislead me...I'm guessing there is no way around these Root objects, right? I've been reading [this post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13767/how-do-i-work-with-root-objects) so...

Comment: Also, I've found this post on [general formula for solving quartic (4th degree polynomial) equations](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/785/is-there-a-general-formula-for-solving-4th-degree-equations). They give a general solution based on what solve gives, but in another answer someone goes the old fashion way. I'll see what I can find maybe some constraints or something.

Comment: @nahn In general the class of equations solvable in terms of radicals is much narrower than those solvable in terms of root objects (the former is a subset of the latter). The idea of putting symbolic solutions found with _Mathematica_ to transform them in _Fortran_ sounds as a total misconception. Nonetheless there are no fundamental barriers.

Comment: I think you are right Artes. The key word being "solutions". Taking, for example a Curl(V), where V a 3D vector, expanding it through mathematica into its components and transforming it to fortran is a safe procedure. Solving an equation (unless you really know how mathematica works) turned out to be not a good idea. I've implemented the actual analytical solution and still could not get the numbers right. Thank you!

Comment: Your comments are not quite relevant to the essence of your question. You haven't clarified whether my post **answers** your question or **not**. If this is the case you should update your question providing clear idea what you would like to get.

Answer (score 2):

The correct result can be obtained by switching to arbitrary precision calculations:

```
f[t_] := a t^4 + b t^3 + c t^2 + d
{t1e, t2e, t3e, t4e} = t /. Solve[f[t] == 0, t];
ncoeff = Rationalize[#, 0] &@{a :> 1.2347931365926803*10^30, 
    b :> 4.6356322739291924*10^23, c :> 4.350806821541392*10^16, 
    d :> -1.2562823055999998*10^6};
N[{t1e, t2e, t3e, t4e} /. ncoeff, 6]
```

> ```
> {-9.38545*10^-8 - 9.99928*10^-7 I, -9.38545*10^-8 + 9.99928*10^-7 I, 
> -1.10255*10^-6, 9.14844*10^-7}
> ```