# Tweaking Solve for systems of polynomial equations

Tags: equation-solving, symbolic, polynomials

I am trying to solve the following system of $6$ quadratic equations in $6$ variables:

```
system = 
  { 1/144 (Sqrt[3] x (Sqrt[5] + 1) + 2Sqrt[3] (t1 + t2 - 1) + 4 Sqrt[3] t1 
   - 2Sqrt[3] t2 + 2 Sqrt[3] (x - 1))^2 + 1/16 (x (Sqrt[5] + 1) - 2t1 - 4t2 - 2x + 4)^2
  + 1/9 (x (Sqrt[3] - 3Sqrt[1/2 Sqrt[5] + 7/6]) + 3(x - 1) Sqrt[1/2 Sqrt[5] + 7/6])^2 == s,
   1/144 (Sqrt[3] x (Sqrt[5] + 1) + 2Sqrt[3] (x - 1) + 2Sqrt[3] (Sqrt[5] + 1))^2 
  + 1/16 (x (Sqrt[5] + 1) - 2x + 2)^2 + 1/9 (x (Sqrt[3] - 3Sqrt[1/2 Sqrt[5] + 7/6]) 
  + 3*(x - 1) Sqrt[1/2 Sqrt[5] + 7/6] - Sqrt[3] + 3 Sqrt[1/2 Sqrt[5] + 7/6])^2 == s, 
   1/36 (Sqrt[3] (t1 + t2 - 1) + 2 Sqrt[3] t1 - Sqrt[3] t2 - Sqrt[3] (Sqrt[5] + 1))^2 
  + 1/4 (t1 + 2t2 - 1)^2 + 1/9 (Sqrt[3] - 3Sqrt[1/2 Sqrt[5] + 7/6])^2 == s, 
    1/144 (Sqrt[3] (u1 + u2 - 1) (Sqrt[5] + 1) - 2Sqrt[3] (t1 + t2 - 1)
  - 4Sqrt[3] t1 + 2 Sqrt[3] t2 + 2Sqrt[3]u1 - 4Sqrt[3] u2)^2 + 
    1/16 ((u1 + u2 - 1) (Sqrt[5] + 1) - 2t1 - 4t2 - 2u1 + 2)^2 + 
    1/9 ((u1 + u2 - 1)(Sqrt[3] - 3Sqrt[1/2 Sqrt[5] + 7/6]) 
  + 3u1 Sqrt[1/2 Sqrt[5] + 7/6] + 3u2 Sqrt[1/2 Sqrt[5] + 7/6])^2 == s, 
    1/144 (Sqrt[3] (u1 + u2 - 1) (Sqrt[5] + 1) + Sqrt[3] x (Sqrt[5] + 1) 
  + 2Sqrt[3] u1 - 4 Sqrt[3] u2 + 2Sqrt[3] (x - 1))^2 + 
    1/16 ((u1 + u2 - 1)(Sqrt[5] + 1) - x (Sqrt[5] + 1) - 2u1 + 2x - 2)^2
  + 1/9 ((u1 + u2 - 1)(Sqrt[3] - 3Sqrt[1/2 Sqrt[5] + 7/6]) 
  + x (Sqrt[3] - 3Sqrt[1/2 Sqrt[5] + 7/6]) + 3u1 Sqrt[1/2 Sqrt[5] + 7/6]
  + 3u2 Sqrt[1/2 Sqrt[5] + 7/6] + 3(x - 1)Sqrt[1/2 Sqrt[5] + 7/6])^2 == s, 
    1/144 (Sqrt[3] (u1 + u2 - 1)(Sqrt[5] + 1) + 2Sqrt[3] u1
  - 4Sqrt[3] u2 - 2Sqrt[3](Sqrt[5] + 1))^2 + 1/16 ((u1 + u2 - 1)(Sqrt[5] + 1) - 2u1)^2 
  + 1/9 ((u1 + u2 - 1)(Sqrt[3] - 3Sqrt[1/2 Sqrt[5] + 7/6]) 
  + 3u1 Sqrt[1/2 Sqrt[5] + 7/6] + 3u2 Sqrt[1/2 Sqrt[5] + 7/6] +
      Sqrt[3] - 3Sqrt[1/2 Sqrt[5] + 7/6])^2 == s};
```

Unfortunately *Mathematica* does not give a solution:

```
Solve[ system, {s, t1, t2, u1, u2, x}]
```

It ran for about an hour and it didn't finish.
 Numerically the system can be solved   with `NSolve`.
I am looking for the solution, where all the variables (`{s, t1, t2, u1, u2, x}`) are positve.
Numerically it should be this one:

```
{s -> 1.8156, t1 -> 0.290762, t2 -> 0.352453, 
 u1 -> 0.332044,  u2 -> 0.0729072, x -> 0.645495}
```

Is there a way to obtain the exact solutions?
Things I tried that didn't work:

- setting the domain to `Reals`. (Then even `Nsolve` doesn't find a solution)
- adding an extra inequality `s > 0`.
- eliminating the variable `s` by hand, which gives a system of $5$ quadratic equations with $5$ variables.

Comment: With "Mathematica does not give a solution" you mean you let it run for a couple of hours and it didn't finish or did it return but unevaluated?

Comment: @Sjoerd C. de Vries: I let it run for about an hour and it didn't finish.

Comment: If the coefficients in your quadratic equations were rationals (so you could write equivalent equations with integer coefficients), it would be easier for Mathematica to provide an exact answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue we encounter here is an instance of **utility of update** of the `Root` object in *Mathematica 9*.

We should provide the assumptions you've mentioned:

```
assumptions = {s > 0, x > 0, t1 > 0, t2 > 0, u1 > 0, u2 > 0};
```

Now we can expect that the new supplemented system `Join[system, assumptions]` might be solved in terms of the root objects involving multivariable polynomials, in fact we can get the solution instantly,
let's solve the system symbolically e.g. with respect to `s`:

```
s /. ToRules @ Reduce[ Join[ system, assumptions], {s, t1, t2, u1, u2, x}]
```

> ```
>  Root[{-5 + #1^2 &, 
>          103432987 + 46256631 #1 - 609434392 #2 - 272547320 #1 #2 + 1523870292 #2^2 
>        + 681494812 #1 #2^2 - 2136466980 #2^3 - 955452228 #1 #2^3 + 1858641502 #2^4 
>        + 831194522 #1 #2^4 - 674274382 #2^5 - 301515206 #1 #2^5 + 54637540 #2^6 
>        + 24400884 #1 #2^6 - 1318386 #2^7 - 569734 #1 #2^7 + 10082 #2^8 &}, {2, 1}]
> ```

We can transform the root object of the form: [`Root[ {f1, f2}, {k1, k2}]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Root.html?q=Root&lang=en) (new capability of *Mathematica 9*) to the form `Root[ f, k]` with `RootReduce`:

```
RootReduce @ %
```

> ```
> Root[  160801 - 1536272 #1 + 21904868 #1^2 - 217962112 #1^3 + 1256858478 #1^4 
>      - 4717349124 #1^5 + 12495147544 #1^6 - 24298372458 #1^7 + 35173457839 #1^8 
>      - 37805732980 #1^9 + 29448527368 #1^10 - 15736320636 #1^11 + 5246771058 #1^12 
>      - 924552262 #1^13 + 60348584 #1^14 - 1318386 #1^15 + 5041 #1^16 &, 5]
> ```

Although the full solution is rather involved its numerical values are quite simple:

```
N @ Reduce[ Join[ system, assumptions], {s, t1, t2, u1, u2, x}]
```

> ```
>  s == 1.8156    && t1 == 0.290762 && t2 == 0.352453 && 
>  u1 == 0.332044 && u2 == 0.0729072 && x == 0.645495
> ```

**Warning:** `Reduce[ Join[ system, assumptions], {s, t1, t2, u1, u2, x}]` in *Mathematica 8* takes rather a long time (it's been running ~ $30$ minutes without solving the system.)

The main improvement in *Mathematica 9* is that symbolic solutions can be
written in terms of multipolynomial root objects:

> `Root[`$\{f_1, f_2,\dots \},\{k_1, k_2,\dots \}$ `]`  represents the last coordinate of the exact vector $\{a_1, a_2,\dots \}$ such that $a_i$ is the $k_i$-th root of the polynomial equation $f_i( a_1,\dots a_{i-1}, x)=0$.

unlike in the former versions of *Mathematica*. We can't get immediately the solution with `Solve` in *Mathematica 9* since its transformation to radicals might be rather complicated if possible at all and most likly we encounter the latter case. Nontheless we can get from root objects almost as much as we like, see e.g. [How do I work with Root objects?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13767/how-do-i-work-with-root-objects/13768#13768). We can guess that in the next versions of the system this issue will be improved.

Comment: I'm going to show a different approach. Regardless, this shows a simple method and is moreover a very nice explanation of the new `Root` capabilities in version 9.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Thanks, I was a bit puzzled with the fact that eliminating variables capabilities od `Solve` or `Eliminate` hadn't seemed to provide a direct approach to this system in _Mathematica 8_. Therefore one has to discover somewhat nonstandard solution.

Comment: nice solution! I used _Mathematica 8_ before, now I use _Mathematica 9_. Having a `Root` object is nice. I wonder whether you can express the solution in terms of the finite algebraic extension that is defined by the coefficients of my system?!

Answer (score 3):

An alternative route is to solve numerically to "adequate" precision (can involve
trial and error), and then convert to algebraic numbers.

```
vars = {x, s, u1, u2, t1, t2};In[289]:= Timing[
sols1 = NSolve[system, vars, WorkingPrecision -> 300];]

(* Out[289]= {1.884000, Null} *)
```

Now select the one of interest.

```
sols2 = vars /. sols1;
sols3 = Cases[sols2, {_?(Element[#, Reals] && # > 0 &) ..}];
sol = sols3[[1]];
```

Here it is, to low approximation.

```
sol // N

(* Out[293]= {0.645495309224, 1.81560223491, 0.332043561796, \
0.0729071548476, 0.290761734788, 0.352452740635} *)
```

Now convert.

```
Timing[exvals = RootApproximant[sol]]

(* {5.768000, {Root[-41 + 2406 #1 - 2804 #1^2 - 11920 #1^3 + 
     35854 #1^4 - 48088 #1^5 + 51560 #1^6 - 92310 #1^7 + 
     136499 #1^8 - 95276 #1^9 + 46202 #1^10 - 61466 #1^11 + 
     64290 #1^12 - 19898 #1^13 - 2730 #1^14 + 972 #1^15 + 71 #1^16 &, 
   5], Root[
   160801 - 1536272 #1 + 21904868 #1^2 - 217962112 #1^3 + 
     1256858478 #1^4 - 4717349124 #1^5 + 12495147544 #1^6 - 
     24298372458 #1^7 + 35173457839 #1^8 - 37805732980 #1^9 + 
     29448527368 #1^10 - 15736320636 #1^11 + 5246771058 #1^12 - 
     924552262 #1^13 + 60348584 #1^14 - 1318386 #1^15 + 5041 #1^16 &, 
   5], Root[-3231 - 20880 #1 + 32430 #1^2 + 205752 #1^3 + 
     361976 #1^4 - 31034 #1^5 - 2388194 #1^6 - 3457962 #1^7 - 
     4152301 #1^8 - 816290 #1^9 + 10299276 #1^10 + 2267938 #1^11 - 
     3187810 #1^12 + 167604 #1^13 + 382842 #1^14 - 92718 #1^15 + 
     5751 #1^16 &, 4], 
  Root[-369 + 9072 #1 + 1053588 #1^2 - 18740400 #1^3 + 
     51387632 #1^4 - 35043358 #1^5 - 80109508 #1^6 + 205675176 #1^7 - 
     123966325 #1^8 - 43454770 #1^9 + 50328778 #1^10 - 
     3388962 #1^11 - 3522208 #1^12 + 1789782 #1^13 - 194904 #1^14 - 
     46224 #1^15 + 5751 #1^16 &, 5], 
  Root[80739 - 501966 #1 - 116490 #1^2 + 5939274 #1^3 - 
     11929078 #1^4 + 92852 #1^5 + 43561778 #1^6 - 101000582 #1^7 + 
     141911857 #1^8 - 139202168 #1^9 + 102269216 #1^10 - 
     60817892 #1^11 + 26786870 #1^12 - 7817358 #1^13 + 
     1642392 #1^14 - 170964 #1^15 + 5751 #1^16 &, 4], 
  Root[64251 + 243738 #1 - 504834 #1^2 - 2032764 #1^3 - 977942 #1^4 + 
     2220422 #1^5 + 2767104 #1^6 - 2704036 #1^7 + 2877417 #1^8 + 
     4747162 #1^9 + 743040 #1^10 - 959712 #1^11 - 901126 #1^12 - 
     342012 #1^13 - 16650 #1^14 + 24732 #1^15 + 5751 #1^16 &, 5]}} *)
```

One can verify, more or less, by plugging these into the equations and checking that they give zero to very high precision (much more than what was used to find the roots, say). This is not a proof, unless you precompute a validating precision (which will be impossibly high). An alternative might be to use `RootReduce` though that could be slow going.