# How do I interpret the Roots syntax when I am finding the eigenvalues of a matrix

Tags: matrix

Here is an example of my problem:

[image: eigenvalues]

I am somewhat confused by the syntax of this. I am guessing that the #1 is specifying the start of another root? Why then does one of the roots = u + with nothing after the plus? I think if I better grasped what the #1 stood for I might understand. Also, is there a reason that the Root ends with an &? Thanks!

Comment: This is likely to be closed as being due to a trivial mistake, but the #1 symbols are function notation. WolframAlpha presumably does not apply ToRadicals by default to cubic roots, so it gives an expression for the cubic roots in terms of generic `Root[]` objects.

Comment: [How do I work with `Root` objects](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13767/5478)