# Transform Root objects into Trigonometric expressions

Tags: simplifying-expressions, symbolic, algebraic-manipulation, trigonometry

Consider the Root objects

```
roots = Table[Root[-1 + 27 #1^2 - 162 #1^4 + 243 #1^6 &, i],{i,1,6}]
```

These can be expressed in terms trigonometric functions as follows

```
trig = 
  {-2/3 Cos[Pi/18], -2/3 Cos[5 Pi/18], -2/3 Cos[7 Pi/18], 
    2/3 Cos[7 Pi/18], 2/3 Cos[5 Pi/18], 2/3 Cos[Pi/18]}
```

This can be checked Numerically, but also exactly using the following expression:

```
And @@ 
  MapThread[
    PossibleZeroQ[ToNumberField[#1 - #2], Method -> "ExactAlgebraics"] &, 
    {roots, trig}]
```

> True

Is there a way to have Mathematica translate between these two things? I have not been able to make FullSimplify do it. Does anyone know of something like a RootToTrig function?

---

Example (by [Vladimir Reshetnikov](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/7288/vladimir-reshetnikov)):

```
Root[1 - 420 # + 32373 #^2 - 33276 #^3 + 11322 #^4 - 1296 #^5 + 9 #^6 &, 2]
```

should be converted to

```
Sin[π/36]^2 Sin[5π/36]^2 / (Sin[7π/36]^2 Sin[2π/9]^2)
```

---

Further Examples (by [Matthew Titsworth](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5700/matthew-titsworth)):

Since more examples have been asked for, here is the function that spurred the original asking of this question:

```
Y[r_, p_] := Table[{(-1)^i Cos[(i^2 r \[Pi])/(2 p + 1)], (-1)^(i-1)^2 Sin[(i^2 r \[Pi])/(2 p + 1)]}, {i, 1, p}]
```

This contains plenty of examples (e.g. r=1,p=7, r=3,p=4) which do not return to their original form under the transformation

```
FullSimplify[ComplexExpand[ToRadicals[ToNumberField[Y[r,p],All]]]]
```

Comment: `FullSimplify[ComplexExpand[ToRadicals[roots]]]`

Comment: This ends up throwing `N:meprec`.

Comment: Wrap `Quiet` around it (it's dealing with zeros that it cannot quite recognize as such).

Comment: Thanks. This works part way in that it gives me trigonometric expressions. However, It still doesn't simplify down to the expressions above. However, that may just be a matter of doing things with `FullSimplify`.

Comment: Vladimir, this is obviously important to you.  Would you please edit the question to include some additional example `Root` objects of the type you have for ease of experimentation?

Comment: Vladimir, do you have more examples we can play with?

Comment: @Vladimir I never really appreciated the possibility that roots of polynomials may be expressed as trig functions of rational multiples of $\pi$.  Would you know where I can read more about this possibility?

Comment: @QuantumDot I don't know where you can read about it. But I find it useful, because it could make an expression containing an algebraic quantity more amenable to transformations and simplifications by elementary methods.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** This is not a full answer, but perhaps it's a start.

From an algebraic stand point this seems like a very hard problem. I attacked it with a more brute force approach. I guess a basis and use `LatticeReduce` to try to find a Diophantine relation.

Note this code only tries to identify roots as the **product of integral powers of trig**. If it returns an answer you can be assured it's correct. If it returns `$Failed`, you may not draw any conclusions.

```
RootToTrig[r_, max_:36] := RootToTrig[r, Range[max]]

RootToTrig[r_, denomGuesses_List] := Module[{redroot, Nr},
    redroot = RootReduce[Sign[r]r];
    Nr = N[Log[Abs[r]], 30];
    Catch[
        If[Im[r] != 0, Throw[$Failed]];
 Do[iRootToTrig[redroot, Nr, Sign[r], n], {n, denomGuesses}];
 $Failed
    ]
]

iRootToTrig[r_, Nr_, sign_, n_] := Block[{tbl, V, pos, root},
    tbl = Join[Prime[Range[8]], Table[Sin[k π/n], {k, n}]];
    tbl = Log[DeleteCases[tbl, 0|1]];
    tbl = Union@Replace[tbl, t_Times :> Select[t, FreeQ[Head[#], Integer|Rational]&], {1}];

    While[Length[tbl] > 1,
        V = LatticeBasis[tbl, Nr];
        (* if First[V] == 0, then we have found a trig identity, we will ignore it *)
        If[First[V] != 0, 
            V = Rest[V]/First[V];
            Break[]
        ];

        pos = Flatten[Position[V, Except[0], {1}]]-1;
        tbl = Delete[tbl, Last[pos]];
    ];

    (* uncomment extra conditions below for integer exponents only *)
    If[Length[tbl] <= 1 (* || !VectorQ[V, IntegerQ] || Max[Abs[V]] > 20 *),
        Return[]
    ];

    root = Exp[V.tbl];
    If[Abs[N[r, 40] - N[root, 40]] < 1.*^-38 && RootReduce[root] == r,
        Throw[sign root]
    ]
]

LatticeBasis[a_List, b_] := Block[{A, prec, basis}, 
    A = Prepend[a, -b];
    prec = Ceiling[Precision[A]]; 
    basis = Transpose[Prepend[IdentityMatrix[Length[A]], Round[10^prec A]]];
    Rest[First[LatticeReduce[basis]]]
]
```

This code works on all provided examples:

```
RootToTrig /@ Table[Root[-1 + 27 #1^2 - 162 #1^4 + 243 #1^6 &, i], {i, 1, 6}]
```

> ```
> {-2/3 Cos[π/18], -Csc[π/9]Sec[π/18]/(4 Sqrt[3]), -2/3 Sin[π/9], 2/3 Sin[π/9], Csc[π/9]Sec[π/18]/(4 Sqrt[3]), 2/3 Cos[π/18]}
> ```

```
RootToTrig[Root[1 - 420 # + 32373 #^2 - 33276 #^3 + 11322 #^4 - 1296 #^5 + 9 #^6 &, 2]]//AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {3.447089, 1/96 (Sqrt[3]-1)^2 Cos[π/18]^4 Sec[π/9]^4 Sec[5π/36]^4}
> ```

Also note if we have a hunch on what the possible denominator should be (or have multiple guesses), you can provide those for a speed up:

```
RootToTrig[Root[1 - 420 # + 32373 #^2 - 33276 #^3 + 11322 #^4 - 1296 #^5 + 9 #^6 &, 2], {36}]//AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.570626, 1/96 (Sqrt[3]-1)^2 Cos[π/18]^4 Sec[π/9]^4 Sec[5π/36]^4}
> ```

---

A more robust approach is to use the AskConstants package [[download link](http://math.hawaii.edu/~dale/AskConstants/AskConstants.html)] [[WTC presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6gm_ocyvRlA)]:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. In cases I'm working with, there are often fractional powers of trig functions, and denominators in arguments sometimes exceed 100.

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov, to get fractional powers in my code, you can remove the condition `!VectorQ[V, IntegerQ]`. Also if your denominators are larger, you can increase the second argument, or provide a list of denominator guesses.

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov, could you give more examples? I'd like to see if I could improve my code to work with them.

Comment: A family of examples have been added. In my work fairly arbitrary products of these can show up, but handling that use case is likely problematic. This seems to be a good answer for the moment that can be updated as necessary, so I'm going to mark it as the accepted answer for the question.

Comment: @MatthewTitsworth Thanks for the accept. I have just made an edit removing the `!VectorQ[V, IntegerQ]` condition and adding one more example at the bottom of the post.