# Help inteprete the solution given by reduce

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to solve for `a2` in the equation below:

```
(-((ρ σ1 σ2)/(a2 a3)) + σ2^2)^2 
 > (σ2^2 (-2 a3 ρ σ1 σ2 + a2 (σ1^2 + a3^2 σ2^2)))/(a2^2 a3^3)
```

I would like to arrange this expression in terms of `a2` or `a3` if possible.

So far I've tried using `Reduce`, together with some assumptions intended to produce a 'nice' solution:

```
Reduce[(-((ρ σ1 σ2)/(a2 a3)) + σ2^2)^2 > 
 (σ2^2 (-2 a3 ρ σ1 σ2 + a2 (σ1^2 + a3^2 σ2^2)))/(a2^2 a3^3) && 
 σ1 > 0 && \[Sigma]2 > 0 && -1 <= ρ <= 1, {a2}]
```

But *Mathematica* returns a large output which I don't fully understand; I don't know which solution to take or leave.

Comment: If no further assumptions are allowed you have to realize that the full output is most likely a correct solution, or if if another assumptions you have in mind you should specify them in the input. With appropriate assumptions on `a3` or `a2` there is still  a some space to find a simpler expression. Perhaps you'll find convenient the `Backsubstitution -> True` option. You should probably read also e.g. [How do I work with Root objects?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13767/how-do-i-work-with-root-objects/13768#13768)

Comment: `Reduce[.., {a2, a3, ρ, σ1, σ2}]` yields a [cylindrical decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylindrical_algebraic_decomposition) of the inequality in which inequalities for `σ1` are given in terms of `σ2`, for `ρ` in terms of `σ1` and `σ2`, for `a3` in terms of `ρ`, `σ1`, `σ2` etc.  The inequalities for each variable are divided into cases with `Or`; the inequalities for one variable is connected to the next by `And`.  The whole can be represented in a nice tree structure, but since `And` is `Flat`, the expression does not usually have this structure.

Comment: ow than you so much for this