# How to enforce mathematica to analytically evaluate roots?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, polynomials

I am interested in simplifying expressions involving HeavisideTheta. A simple example could be:

```
HeavisideTheta[1 + x - x^2 + x^3]
```

The best I can achieve is with

```
FullSimplify[HeavisideTheta[1 + x - x^2 + x^3]//FunctionExpand]
```

but that only outputs this:

```
HeavisideTheta[x - Root[1 + #1 - #1^2 + #1^3 &, 1]]
```

Now, I know mathematica can solve the given polynomial:

```
In[2]:=  Solve[-1 - 2 x - x^2 + 2 x^3 + x^4 == 0]
Out[2]:= {x -> 1/2 (-1 - I Sqrt[-5 + 4 Sqrt[2]])}, {x -> 
1/2 (-1 + I Sqrt[-5 + 4 Sqrt[2]])}, {x -> 
1/2 (-1 - Sqrt[5 + 4 Sqrt[2]])}, {x -> 
1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[5 + 4 Sqrt[2]])}}
```

But how do I make it give me an appropriately simplified expression for the simplified HeavisideTheta?

Comment: Maybe ToRadicals

Comment: Sorry, I did't notice the comment, so deleted the answer.

Comment: Umm... ToRadicals solves the problem conveniently. How should I accept this the answer?

Comment: Two points: 1) `Simplify` and `FullSimplify` don't solve equations, even [extremely easy ones](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/75368/21750); 2) The result with all those `Sqrt`s is longer than the original expression, so even if `FullSimplify` did manage to find that result, it would discard it since it's no simpler than the input!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [Apple](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/10193/apple) alludes to in a comment, [`ToRadicals`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToRadicals.html) converts [`Root`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) objects to radicals, when the roots can be expressed in terms of radicals:

```
ToRadicals[FunctionExpand[
  HeavisideTheta[1 + x - x^2 + x^3]]]
(* HeavisideTheta[ 1/3 (-1 + 2/(-17 + 3 Sqrt[33])^(1/3) - (-17 + 3 Sqrt[33])^(1/3)) + x] *)
```

It well known that not all root can be expressed in terms of radicals, so in some cases the `Root` objects are the best option:

```
ToRadicals@FunctionExpand[HeavisideTheta[x^5 - 4 x^3 + x - 3]]
(*
  HeavisideTheta[x - Root[-3 + #1 - 4 #1^3 + #1^5 &, 1]] - 
   HeavisideTheta[x - Root[-3 + #1 - 4 #1^3 + #1^5 &, 2]] + 
   HeavisideTheta[x - Root[-3 + #1 - 4 #1^3 + #1^5 &, 3]]
*)
```

---

Refs.:

- [How do I work with Root objects?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13767/how-do-i-work-with-root-objects)
- [Meta discussions of answers from comments](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=comment+answer)

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit ? Otherwise it is just a copy-paste from the comment of Chenminqi

Answer (score 0):

Ok, there's got to be a better way, but for the time being you could use the following.

First define a function `f` (for lack of a better name) that transforms the argument:

```
f[expr_] := {1, -1}.List @@ Solve[0 == expr][[1, 1]]

f[1 + x - x^2 + x^3]
```

> `1/3 (-1 + 2/(-17 + 3 Sqrt[33])^(1/3) - (-17 + 3 Sqrt[33])^(1/3)) + x`

Then, you commute the function heads, so that `f` acts on the argument only (`@` is understood as function composition):

```
f /: f@g[x_] := g@f[x]
```

What you end up with is:

```
g = HeavisideTheta;

g[1 + x - x^2 + x^3]//f
```

> `HeavisideTheta[
>    1/3 (-1 + 2/(-17 + 3 Sqrt[33])^(1/3) - (-17 + 3 Sqrt[33])^(1/3)) + x]`

Comment: I am on Mathematica 10.1.0.0. I directly copied and executed your code. I get the same output for `f[1 + x - x^2 + x^3]`, but having added the second definition using TagSetDelayed, `f /: f@g[x_] := g@f[x]` I don't get your result. Rather I get `HeavisideTheta[1 + x - x^2 + x^3]`