# I want to calculate the equation in terms of the lambda

Tags: equation-solving, special-functions

```
(2/5)^(2/5) Sqrt[x] λ^(1/5)
   BesselI[-(2/5), 4/5 x^(5/4) Sqrt[λ]] C[1] Gamma[3/
   5] + ((-2)^(2/5) Sqrt[x] λ^(1/5)
   BesselI[2/5, 4/5 x^(5/4) Sqrt[λ]] C[2] Gamma[7/5])/5^(2/5)==0
```

Comment: Could you format your question, please? Instructions can be found in the top right corner of the edit box. Additionally, you are talking about an equation, but I don't see one here. And what does "calculate an equation in terms of lambda" mean? Do you want it to be solved for lambda?

Comment: Try `Solve`, `Reduce` and `Eliminate`?

Comment: Yes, I want solved for lambda.

Comment: This is not an equation and hence cannot be "solved for lambda," just as you cannot "solve for lambda" in the expression "lambda + 14."

Comment: It looks like this equation cannot be solved algebraically.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We can solve the equation after a fashion with some algebraic manipulation.  There infinitely many complex solutions, but *Mathematica* can find the ones in a finite domain.

Here is the left hand side of the OP's equation:

```
lhs = (2/5)^(2/5) Sqrt[x] λ^(1/5) BesselI[-(2/5), 4/5 x^(5/4) Sqrt[λ]] C[1] Gamma[3/5] + 
     ((-2)^(2/5) Sqrt[x] λ^(1/5) BesselI[2/5, 4/5 x^(5/4) Sqrt[λ]] C[2] Gamma[7/5])/5^(2/5);
```

Look at the factors and solve each equal to zero.  There is one factor that is left unsolved, saved in the variable `eqs`.  Its left hand side is a function of `u = 4/5 x^(5/4) Sqrt[λ]`; the replacement rule `λ2u = 4/5 x^(5/4) Sqrt[λ] -> u` will put it in terms of `u`.

```
List @@ Factor@lhs
(*
  {(2/5)^(2/5),
   Sqrt[x],
   λ^(1/5), 
   BesselI[-(2/5), 4/5 x^(5/4) Sqrt[λ]] C[1] Gamma[3/5] +
     (-1)^(2/5) BesselI[2/5, 4/5 x^(5/4) Sqrt[λ]] C[2] Gamma[7/5]}
*)

λ2u = 4/5 x^(5/4) Sqrt[λ] -> u;
sol0 = Solve[# == 0, λ] & /@ List @@ Factor@lhs;
{sols, eqs} = GatherBy[Join[{{}}, sol0], FreeQ[#, Solve] &];
sols
eqs = First /@ eqs
eqs /. λ2u
```

> Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve. >>

```
(*
  {{}, {}, {{}}, {{λ -> 0}}}
  {BesselI[-(2/5), 4/5 x^(5/4) Sqrt[λ]] C[1] Gamma[3/5] +
    (-1)^(2/5) BesselI[2/5, 4/5 x^(5/4) Sqrt[λ]] C[2] Gamma[7/5] == 0}
  {BesselI[-(2/5), u] C[1] Gamma[3/5] + (-1)^(2/5) BesselI[2/5, u] C[2] Gamma[7/5] == 0}
*)
```

**Update**: As [DumpsterDoofus](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/9697/dumpsterdoofus) pointed out, `λ -> 0` is only a solution when `C[1] == 0`; otherwise, the left hand side is undefined.

Given numeric values for `C[1]` and `C[2]`, *Mathematica* can solve the remaining equation in a limited domain.  The function `u0` solves for `u`, given valus `c1`, `c2` for `C[1]`, `C[2]` resp., and a finite domain in which to search for roots.  I somewhat arbitrarily set up the default domain to be `-10 <= Re[u] <= 10 && -10 <= Im[u] <= 10` (because ±1 yields no roots).  The results of an exact solution are returned in terms of `Root` objects (see, for example, [How do I work with Root objects?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13767/how-do-i-work-with-root-objects)).

```
u0[c1_?NumericQ, c2_?NumericQ, 
   domain : {z1_?NumericQ, z2_?NumericQ} : {-10 - 10 I, 10 + 10 I}] := 
  Quiet[
   Solve[
    (First@eqs /. λ2u /. {C[1] -> c1, C[2] -> c2}) && 
     Re[z1] <= Re[u] <= Re[z2] && Im[z1] <= Im[u] <= Im[z2],
    u],
   Solve::ratnz];
```

Now we can use the solutions for `u` given by `u0` to solve for `λ` by reversing the substitution.

```
First@Solve[#, λ] & /@ Thread[(u /. Reverse[λ2u]) == u /. u0[1, 1]]
```

> Solve::incs: Warning: Solve was unable to prove that the solution set found is complete. >>

```
(*
  {{λ -> (1/(16 x^(5/2)))25 Root[{
     BesselI[-(2/5), #1] Gamma[3/5] + (-1)^(2/5) BesselI[2/5, #1] Gamma[7/5] &,
     -0.3705505531326194245117619840662337995953846760177051847 + 
      7.4965854610603720569205193398193535444066971045089011861 I}]^2},
   {λ -> (1/(16 x^(5/2)))25 (Root[<..>]^2)},
   {λ -> (1/(16 x^(5/2)))25 (Root[<..>]^2)},
   {λ -> (1/(16 x^(5/2)))25 (Root[<..>]^2)},
   {λ -> (1/(16 x^(5/2)))25 (Root[<..>]^2)}}
*)
```

This gave 5 solutions, in the form `λ -> C[3] / x^(5/2)`, one for each root returned by `u0[1, 1]`.

Interestingly, `DSolve` can obtain the same form (plus another unsolved equation):

```
λ2λx = λ -> λ[x];
dsols = DSolve[D[eqs /. λ2λx, x], λ, x]

(*
 {
   {λ -> Function[{x}, C[3]/x^(5/2)]}, 
   Solve[BesselI[-(7/5), 4/5 x^(5/4) Sqrt[λ[x]]] C[1] Gamma[3/5] +
     BesselI[3/5, 4/5 x^(5/4) Sqrt[λ[x]]] C[1] Gamma[3/5] +
     (-1)^(2/5) BesselI[-(3/5), 4/5 x^(5/4) Sqrt[λ[x]]] C[2] Gamma[7/5] +
     (-1)^(2/5) BesselI[7/5, 4/5 x^(5/4) Sqrt[λ[x]]] C[2] Gamma[7/5] == 0,
    λ[x]]}
*)
```

Comment: Nice. One possible issue: in the first couple lines when you factor the equation and then apply `Solve[# == 0, λ]` to the individual parts, you get a spurious solution $\lambda=0$ because $\lambda^{1/5}=0$ has solution $\lambda=0$. However, the negative-order `BesselI` is singular at the origin, and this destroys the zeroing effect of the $\lambda^{1/5}$ term unless `C[1]` is zero. This is just due to the issue that when finding the zeros of an expression, you may get spurious roots when solving for the zeros of the individual factors when other factors have singularities.

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus You're right, I wasn't very careful.  The sort of thing I get onto my students for, too.  [Whatever the chagrined form of the smiley goes here.]

Answer (score 10):

This does not appear to be possible to solve in Mathematica, but here's a couple steps that might help. Simplify it:

```
Simplify[(2/5)^(2/5) Sqrt[x] λ^(1/5)
    BesselI[-(2/5), 4/5 x^(5/4) Sqrt[λ]] C[1] Gamma[3/5] + 
    ((-2)^(2/5) Sqrt[x] λ^(1/5) BesselI[2/5, 4/5 x^(5/4) Sqrt[λ]] C[2] Gamma[7/5])/5^(2/5)]
```

which gives

```
Sqrt[x] λ^(
 1/5) (BesselI[-(2/5), 4/5 x^(5/4) Sqrt[λ]] C[1] Gamma[3/5] + (-1)^(2/5)
     BesselI[2/5, 4/5 x^(5/4) Sqrt[λ]] C[2] Gamma[7/5])
```

The first case to consider is $x=0$ or $\lambda=0$. Evaluating the limits

```
Limit[Sqrt[x] λ^(
  1/5) (BesselI[-(2/5), 4/5 x^(5/4) Sqrt[λ]] Gamma[3/5] C[1] + (-1)^(2/5)
      BesselI[2/5, 4/5 x^(5/4) Sqrt[λ]] C[2] Gamma[7/5]), λ -> 0]
Limit[%, x -> 0]
```

gives

```
((5/2)^(2/5) Sqrt[x] C[1])/(x^(5/4))^(2/5)
(5/2)^(2/5) C[1]
```

and the same result is obtained when approaching the origin from other angles. So if `C[1]` is 0, then $x=0$ or $\lambda=0$ (or both) is a zero. Otherwise, neither is.

Otherwise, if $x\neq0,\lambda\neq0$ then we can remove the factor of $\lambda^{1/5} \sqrt{x}$ and absorb the Gamma constants into `C[1]` and `C[2]` to give
$$c_1 I_{-2/5}\left(u\right)+c_2 I_{2/5}\left(u\right)=0$$
where $u=\frac{4}{5} x^{5/4} \sqrt{\lambda }$, at which point it would probably be best to consult the DLMF, or somebody at MathematicsSE who knows more about special functions than I do.