# Integration of a Rational Function returns RootSum[]

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am trying to solve an integral given below:

```
Integrate[r^2/(-α r^3 + r^2 - 2 m r + Q^2), r]
```

but since coefficients of this cubic polynomial are as parameters, so i could not get any reasonable answer from mathematica, output:

```
(*
-RootSum[Q^2 - 2 m #1 + #1^2 - α #1^3 &,   (Log[r - #1] #1^2)/(2 m - 2 #1 + 3 α #1^2) &]
*)
```

Please help me in finding this integral, what information i have for these coefficients is as: `\alpha` is a positive number, and `m` and `Q` are reals, with `m` positive real.

Comment: `RootSum[...]` is a reasonable answer, see e.g. a related question [How do I work with Root objects?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13767/how-do-i-work-with-root-objects)

Comment: @ Artes thanks for your comment, I am sorry that I cant understand the logic of root sum from the link you mentioned above, could you please briefly describe it here?

Comment: @BushraMajeed You will not understand `RootSum` unless you learn about `Root`. You have to try a bit harder. You can compute that expression for special values of prarameters e.g. `With[{Q = 1, m = 2, α = 0}, -RootSum[ Q^2 - 2 m #1 + #1^2 - α #1^3 &, (Log[r - #1] #1^2)/(2 m - 2 #1 + 3 α #1^2) &]]`.

Comment: how about `Integrate[r^2/(-\[Alpha] r^3 + r^2 - 2 m r + Q^2), r] //Normal//ToRadicals`?

Comment: @chris I believe that makes a good answer, probably better if you explain a bit about RootSum[]. I'll surely upvote it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

or using [Rubi](http://www.apmaths.uwo.ca/~arich/) integration package (Rubi does not use Root or RootSum in its answers)

(to use Rubi, just change `Integrate` with `Int`, everything remains the same:

```
   Int[r^2/(-a r^3 + r^2 - 2 m r + q^2), r]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 10):

Let's look at this in steps:

```
Integrate[r^2/(-α r^3 + r^2 - 2 m r + Q^2), r]
```

returns the formal solution as a sum of the roots of the polynomial of the first argument of [`RootSum`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RootSum.html) applied to the slots of the second argument.

(* -RootSum[#1^3 (-α)+#1^2-2 #1 m+Q^2&,(#1^2 log(r-#1))/(3 #1^2 α-2 #1+2 m)&] *)

Indeed if we ask Mathematica for an explicit expression

```
Normal[Integrate[r^2/(-α r^3 + r^2 - 2 m r + Q^2), r]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Involving the 3 [`Root`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Root.html)

Or even more explicitly

```
ToRadicals@Normal[Integrate[r^2/(-α r^3 + r^2 - 2 m r + Q^2), r]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

> which I think illustrates nicely why Mathematica (and possibly you) prefers the original expression.

Comment: @ Chris, these useful commands are really helpful for a reasonable output, though the expression for this case is very long and complex numbers involved there, due to roots, and i am considering the case when this polynomial has two complex roots and one real, so I cant avoid these complex numbers. Thanks for your suggestions.