# How to get the correct answer of this expression with Minimize?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I want to find minimum value of the expression 
$$P = 13 x^2  + 12 y^2 + 22 z^2$$ such that $x y +  y z + z x = 1$. I tried

```
Minimize[{13 x^2  + 12 y^2 + 22 z^2, x y +  y z + z x == 1}, {x, y,
```

z}]

and got

> {Root[-13728 + 47 #1^2 + #1^3 &, 
>     3], {x -> (1 - 
>         Root[{-13728 + 47 #1^2 + #1^3 &, 
>            663520 + 13728 #1 - 79 #1^2 - 791648 #2^2 - 145288 #1 #2^2 - 
>              3105 #1^2 #2^2 + 2423278 #2^4 + 66924 #1 #2^4 + 
>              597 #1^2 #2^4 + 679536 #2^6 + 1981 #1 #2^6 + 
>              133908 #2^8 &}, {3, 2}] Root[{-13728 + 47 #1^2 + #1^3 &, 
>            663520 + 13728 #1 - 79 #1^2 - 791648 #2^2 - 145288 #1 #2^2 - 
>              3105 #1^2 #2^2 + 2423278 #2^4 + 66924 #1 #2^4 + 
>              597 #1^2 #2^4 + 679536 #2^6 + 1981 #1 #2^6 + 133908 #2^8 &,
>             13 - #1 #2^2 + 12 #2^4 - 26 #2 #3 - 2 #1 #2 #3 + 
>              24 #2^3 #3 - #1 #3^2 + 47 #2^2 #3^2 + 44 #2 #3^3 + 
>              22 #3^4 &}, {3, 2, 2}])/(Root[{-13728 + 47 #1^2 + #1^3 &, 
>           663520 + 13728 #1 - 79 #1^2 - 791648 #2^2 - 145288 #1 #2^2 - 
>             3105 #1^2 #2^2 + 2423278 #2^4 + 66924 #1 #2^4 + 
>             597 #1^2 #2^4 + 679536 #2^6 + 1981 #1 #2^6 + 
>             133908 #2^8 &}, {3, 2}] + 
>         Root[{-13728 + 47 #1^2 + #1^3 &, 
>           663520 + 13728 #1 - 79 #1^2 - 791648 #2^2 - 145288 #1 #2^2 - 
>             3105 #1^2 #2^2 + 2423278 #2^4 + 66924 #1 #2^4 + 
>             597 #1^2 #2^4 + 679536 #2^6 + 1981 #1 #2^6 + 133908 #2^8 &, 
>           13 - #1 #2^2 + 12 #2^4 - 26 #2 #3 - 2 #1 #2 #3 + 
>             24 #2^3 #3 - #1 #3^2 + 47 #2^2 #3^2 + 44 #2 #3^3 + 
>             22 #3^4 &}, {3, 2, 2}]), 
>     y -> Root[{-13728 + 47 #1^2 + #1^3 &, 
>        663520 + 13728 #1 - 79 #1^2 - 791648 #2^2 - 145288 #1 #2^2 - 
>          3105 #1^2 #2^2 + 2423278 #2^4 + 66924 #1 #2^4 + 
>          597 #1^2 #2^4 + 679536 #2^6 + 1981 #1 #2^6 + 
>          133908 #2^8 &}, {3, 2}], 
>     z -> Root[{-13728 + 47 #1^2 + #1^3 &, 
>        663520 + 13728 #1 - 79 #1^2 - 791648 #2^2 - 145288 #1 #2^2 - 
>          3105 #1^2 #2^2 + 2423278 #2^4 + 66924 #1 #2^4 + 
>          597 #1^2 #2^4 + 679536 #2^6 + 1981 #1 #2^6 + 133908 #2^8 &, 
>        13 - #1 #2^2 + 12 #2^4 - 26 #2 #3 - 2 #1 #2 #3 + 
>          24 #2^3 #3 - #1 #3^2 + 47 #2^2 #3^2 + 44 #2 #3^3 + 
>          22 #3^4 &}, {3, 2, 2}]}}

If I tried

```
Clear[x, y, z]
FunctionRange[{13 x^2  + 12 y^2 + 22 z^2, x y +  y z + z x == 1}, {x,y, z}, w]
```

I got

> w >=  Root[-13728 + 47 #1^2 + #1^3 &, 3]

How to get the correct answer of this expression with commad `Minimize`?

Comment: `Minimize[{13 x^2 + 12 y^2 + 22 z^2, x y + y z + z x == 1}, {x, y, 
   z}] // N`

Comment: @belisariushassettled Thank you. I tried. Can I get the correc answer?

Comment: If you just need to get a good approximate answer (assuming there is no exact answer), try `NMinimize`:  `NMinimize[{13 x^2 + 12 y^2 + 22 z^2, x y + y z + z x == 1}, {x, y, z}]`

Comment: @JimBaldwin I knew this command and I did that.

Comment: It is my understanding that usually when a root object appears, there is no "nice" form (such as a rational number or a multiple of $\pi$, etc.).  The following post might help:  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13767/how-do-i-work-with-root-objects

Comment: @JimBaldwin that is OP's own question. I am not sure why the answer did not sink in, but I cannot think of anything better than to recommend a review of the documentation. As such, I vote to close.

Comment: @OleksandrR.  I know.  I just couldn't resist.

Comment: @JimBaldwin The root object contains a cubic function, meaning there is in fact a "nice" form.

Comment: @JHM.  I stand corrected.

Comment: @JHM, it's a closed form, yes. Nice? That's more subjective, but I would have personally preferred the trigonometric representation.

Answer (score 5):

```
min = Minimize[{13 x^2 + 12 y^2 + 22 z^2, x y + y z + z x == 1}, {x, y, z}];
```

The [`Root`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) expressions are the exact solutions. Use [`N`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/N.html) to convert the `Root` expressions to their approximate numeric equivalent. You can specify any arbitrary precision using the second argument to `N`.

```
min // N

(*  {14.893, {x -> -0.635532, y -> -0.668213, z -> -0.441289}}  *)
```

This is consistent with the [`FunctionRange`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionRange.html)

```
FunctionRange[{13 x^2 + 12 y^2 + 22 z^2, x y + y z + z x == 1}, {x, y, z}, 
  w] // N

(*  w >= 14.893  *)
```

Alternatively, using the constraint to remove one variable and again using `N` to convert the `Root` expressions to their approximate numeric equivalent.

```
Minimize[13 x^2 + 12 y^2 + 22 z^2 /. Solve[x y + y z + z x == 1, z], {x, y}] //
  N

(*  {14.893, {x -> -0.635532, y -> -0.668213}}  *)
```

Comment: Well, let me just add that the "numeric equivalent" is not really *equivalent*. The `Root` object represents the solution at infinite precision; the numeric value is just an approximation to it.

Comment: @OleksandrR. - agree. I tried to clarify above.

Answer (score 5):

If you only want the minimum value, `MinValue` would be adequate.

```
MinValue[{13 x^2 + 12 y^2 + 22 z^2, x y + y z + z x == 1}, {x, y, z}]

(*  Root[-13728 + 47 #1^2 + #1^3 &, 3] *)
```

If you want to use `Minimize`:

```
Minimize[{13 x^2 + 12 y^2 + 22 z^2, x y + y z + z x == 1}, {x, y, z}][[1]]

(*  Root[-13728 + 47 #1^2 + #1^3 &, 3] *)
```

If you want the exact value and not the `Root` object:

```
ToRadicals @ Root[-13728 + 47 #1^2 + #1^3 &, 3]

(* 1/3 (-47 + 2209/(81505 + 36 I Sqrt[3191474])^(1/3)
 + (81505 + 36 I Sqrt[3191474])^(1/3)) *)
```

(This works because the equation in the `Root` object is a cubic equation; it may not work for high-order polynomials)

Note that this expression contains imaginary terms but is a real number ([Casus Irreducibilis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casus_irreducibilis)).