# Get rid of imaginary parametric eigenvalues of a Hermitian matrix

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, physics

I have four matrices with below structures (`mat1`, `mat2`, `mat3` and `mat4`). With real coefficients (`c1`, `c2`, `c3`) I have created the matrix `matcomplete=(mat1+c1*mat2)+c3*(mat3+c2*mat4)`. All `mat`'s are Hermitian matrices. I know in this case of real coefficients (as it is the my case), `matcomplete` will be Hermitian. Then the eigenvalues of `matcomplete` have to be real. But when I use of [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11498/mathematica-wont-give-eigenvectors-but-wolfram-alpha-will-what-am-i-doing-wron) method:

```
Eigenvalues[matcomplete, Cubics -> True]
```

the some eigenvalues will be `Imaginary`. I mean in one term I see

```
 (*  ((1 + I Sqrt[3])  *)
```

I wanted to use of `FullSimplify[Eigenvalues[matcomplete, Cubics -> True], Assumptions{c1>0,c2>0,c3>0}]` but it has taken too long!!.

*There are some assumptions (but I think the third is true):*

1-Eigenvalues of a Hermitian matrix such as `matcomplete` maybe are not always real.

2- `matcomplete` is not a Hermitian matrix even with real coefficients.

3-`Eigenvalues[matcomplete, Cubics -> True]` is not a good way for these matrices.

How can I reach to the correct eigenvalues of the `matcomplete`? 
[here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/102025/how-to-get-the-correct-answer-of-this-expression-with-minimize) introduces a method that has been suggested by Feyre. It means that one way is use of numeric values but I have to obtain eigenvalues parametricaly.

```
    mat1={{0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0,0, 
 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}};
     mat2={{0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  1, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
 1}, {0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 
 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 
 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0}, {0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1,
 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 
  0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1,
 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 
 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1,
  0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}};
   mat3={{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 
  1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
  0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 
  1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
  0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}};
    mat4={{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0}, {0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 
   0}, {0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, -1,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1,
   0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
 0, 0}};
```

Comment: I ran the `FullSimplify[]`, and it still contains complex values, note that substituting in real positive values for the constants also still gives complex values.

Comment: This is a cancellation error:

    `ret = Eigenvalues[newmat, Cubics -> True];
    Manipulate[
      Chop[N[ret] /. {c1 -> a1, c2 -> a2, c3 -> a3}], {a1, 0, 10, 
       0.1}, {a2, 0, 10, 0.1}, {a3, 0, 10, 0.1}] // MatrixForm`

Comment: @ Feyre, I think I cannot understand a thing! You added Chop and look numerically to eigenvalues. But no eigenvalues are complex.

Comment: Could you tell the coefficients for which you get complex eigenvalues?

Comment: @ Sumit, So Sorry, I could not understand your sentence. I think a verb is missed.

Comment: @Irreversible The `Chop[]` is to illustrate that the Imaginary components of the eigenvalues are close to zero, and the result of  cancellation errors.

Comment: @ Feyre, Yes. You are right. In another question I try to focus on `Root` of any eigenvalues equations.

Comment: Again we have the *casus irreducibilis* situation for radical solutions of the cubic. I'd suggest use `Root` form, it's better anyway.

Comment: @Irreversible, let me refresh my grammar. You construct `matcomplete` from 4 Hermitian matrix, and if I understand correctly, you find some complex eigenvalues which lead you to your three assumptions. Can you give an example when `matcomplete` returns complex eigenvalues. If it  is happening for some values of `c1,c2,c3` , what are those values?

Comment: @ Sumit, when we use of numerical coefficients (please set each of them equal to 5)  or in a way suggested by Feyre, imaginary parts will be so little which can be eliminated by `Chop`. But if you attack to the problem parametricaly (not numerics) you can see that appeared (1-Sqrt[3] I) term and so on. and I need to parametric configuration of eigenvalues unfortunately!

Comment: As @DanielLichtblau mentioned, you can't always get what you want, see [Casus irreducibilis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casus_irreducibilis). So I think the question will not be answerable in the way you expect. But all the eigenvalues will be real, you can be certain of that even if imaginary units appear.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the correct answer of this expression with Minimize?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/102025/how-to-get-the-correct-answer-of-this-expression-with-minimize)

Comment: @ Jens, thank you to suggest the address. but I explained and modified the body of question that the address is not useful for me. If possible please don't sign the question as duplicate.

Comment: @ Jens, right now I saw your comment. Ok I am convinced that I cannot obtain all I want but I just want the real part. I want to eliminate not necessary imaginary part. for example it will be so good if the answers be as `(a+b I)`. I just choose `a` and I know ` b` is not important. but answers are not written as `a+b I`?!!!! I have written another question which strongly related to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply ignore the fact that you are seeing a `(1 + I Sqrt[3])`. Let's have a look at the last eigenvalue where this thing appears.

```
eval = Eigenvalues[matcomplete, Cubics -> True][[-1]]
```

> (-2*(-c3 + c2*c3))/3 - ((1 - I*Sqrt[3])*(-48 - 48*c1^2 - 16*c3^2 - 16*c2*c3^2 - 16*c2^2*c3^2))/
>     (3*2^(2/3)*(-1152*c3 + 576*c1^2*c3 - 576*c2*c3 + 1152*c1^2*c2*c3 + 128*c3^3 + 192*c2*c3^3 - 192*c2^2*c3^3 - 128*c2^3*c3^3 + 
>        Sqrt[4*(-48 - 48*c1^2 - 16*c3^2 - 16*c2*c3^2 - 16*c2^2*c3^2)^3 + (-1152*c3 + 576*c1^2*c3 - 576*c2*c3 + 1152*c1^2*c2*c3 + 128*c3^3 + 192*c2*c3^3 - 192*c2^2*c3^3 - 128*c2^3*c3^3)^2])^(1/3)) + 
>    ((1 + I*Sqrt[3])*(-1152*c3 + 576*c1^2*c3 - 576*c2*c3 + 1152*c1^2*c2*c3 + 128*c3^3 + 192*c2*c3^3 - 192*c2^2*c3^3 - 128*c2^3*c3^3 + 
>        Sqrt[4*(-48 - 48*c1^2 - 16*c3^2 - 16*c2*c3^2 - 16*c2^2*c3^2)^3 + (-1152*c3 + 576*c1^2*c3 - 576*c2*c3 + 1152*c1^2*c2*c3 + 128*c3^3 + 192*c2*c3^3 - 192*c2^2*c3^3 - 128*c2^3*c3^3)^2])^(1/3))/
>     (6*2^(1/3))

[image]

and you can see $1-i\sqrt3$ and also $1+i\sqrt3$. Now Mathematica can not simplify it because it does not know the values of `c1,c2,c3` so it can not evaluate the square roots and cube roots. Specifying `c1,c2,c3` to be `Reals` or $>0$ is not sufficient because it does not specify the value of the terms inside the roots. But when you specify the exact values, it can evaluate those terms and the imaginary parts cancels each other explicitly and you get real eigenvalues.  May be with some luck and trials you can find a condition which can get read of the imaginary part in this parametric form - I am too lazy for that.