# What is the meaning of #, Root and &

Tags: expression-construction

I am new, but can any one tell me what is the meaning of formulas of x and y in the picture?
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: Though it's not particularly important for this question, people here generally like users to post code as Mathematica code instead of images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful.

Comment: Check out all the references in [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25616/9490), and all the other stuff on that page is good to read as well.

Comment: Have you [searched the site](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=root+objects) or [the documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) for Root?

Comment: For this, when you see an expression with `#` followed by a `&`, it means a [pure function](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PureFunctions.html)

Comment: @olivia, mark a simbol that concerns you, and press `F1` key (Help). Usually it helps a lot.

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13767/how-do-i-work-with-root-objects