# How do I find the analytical roots of this polynomial?

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials

I want to find the analytical roots of this polynomial

```
- x - a^3*x*(a^2*x*(a*x*(x - 1) + 1)*(x - 1) + 1)*(a*x*(x - 1) + 1)*(x - 1)
```

`Solve` gives the first 2 roots as `x=0` and `x=1-1/a` while the other 6 roots - as symbolic expressions using `Root` object. Is there a way to find analytical solutions for other 6 roots expressed without `Root` object?

Comment: The other six roots apparently do not exist in closed form.

Comment: `Solve[-x - a^3*x*(a^2*x*(a*x*(x - 1) + 1)*(x - 1) + 1)*(a*x*(x - 1) + 1)*(x - 1) == 0, x]` works for me: http://i.stack.imgur.com/SULgx.png

Comment: I am very curious how did you find the numerical roots? Your `a` is not defined.

Comment: Could use `Roots[-x - a^3*x*(a^2*x*(a*x*(x - 1) + 1)*(x - 1) + 1)*(a*x*(x - 1) + 1)*(x - 1) == 0, x]` which of course is a documented function.

Comment: Are you interested only in real solutions or also in imaginary ones? I think your problem will be much simpler if you are only looking for real solutions.

Comment: @PavloFesenko Note that it is an error to say `Solve` returns numerical solutions.  It returns symbolic ones for the other 6 roots in terms of `Root` (see for instance http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13768). If it is returning numerical solutions for you, it is a bug.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks for pointing it out. I have corrected my edit.

Answer (score 6):

You have the irreducible polynomial of the 7th degree:

```
-x + a^3 x - a^3 x^2 - a^4 x^2 - a^5 x^2 + 2 a^4 x^3 + 2 a^5 x^3 + 
 2 a^6 x^3 - a^4 x^4 - a^5 x^4 - 6 a^6 x^4 - a^7 x^4 + 6 a^6 x^5 + 
 4 a^7 x^5 - 2 a^6 x^6 - 6 a^7 x^6 + 4 a^7 x^7 - a^7 x^8
```

The general algebraic solution doesn't exist for polynomials of the 5th degree and higher with arbitrary coefficients. This is called [Abel-Ruffini theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem).

Comment: Some higher order polynomials can be solved analytically eg `x^8-1==0`. Abel-Ruffini says there's no general algorithm in terms of radicals.