# Using functions in Solve

Tags: equation-solving, functions

i wanted to calculate the real roots of a function. To my knowledge the function i defined has no real roots, so i expected an emptyset, but instead i got some Root[...#..] answers by Mathematica.

**My first input:**
`i[x_] := (86 - 4*x^2)/4;
uaa[x_, y_] := 60 - 9*y^2 - 2*x;`
`Solve[uaa[x, i[x]] == 0, x, Reals]`

Then i plugged in the function directly into the Solve and i get the expected anser of emptyset.

**Control input:**
`{Solve[60 - 9 (86 - 4*x^2)/4^2 - 2*x == 0, x, Reals]}`

How can i change my input in the first input so that i get the emptyset?

Thank you very much

Comment: Sorry for forgetting one line :-(

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: I get four real solutions from both W|A and *Mathematica*.  Maybe there's a typo?  For `Root` to seem less weird, perhaps see the [docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) or [this Q&A](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13767/how-do-i-work-with-root-objects).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [(13767)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13767/121) ?

Comment: Your control input is wrong - you have squared only the denominator of `i[x]` instead of the whole thing. Replace `(86 - 4*x^2)/4^2` with `((86 - 4*x^2)/4)^2`

Comment: Hi, thank you @Simon Wood This was my error just realized it myself :-( Shame on me