# Expressing the n-th power of a matrix

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

My matrix is

$\qquad A= \begin{pmatrix}
 {1} & {2} & {3}\\
 {4} & {1} & {0}\\
 {0} & {5} & {4}
 \end{pmatrix} $

I need

$\qquad A^n$

I tried

```
MatrixPower[A, n]
```

I do not understand the result. Should it not go according to `n`

#### Edit

[by m_goldberg]

The result the OP is complaining about is full of root objects and looks like this:

```
Shallow[MatrixPower[{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 1, 0}, {0, 5, 4}}, n], 6]
```

[image: result]

Comment: The result should be an expression valid for arbitrary $n$. What precisely were you expecting?

Comment: I do not understand this result, I can explain how it is interpreted, it took no time with Mathematica                                                     Root[-32 + #1 - 6 #1^2 + #1^3 &, 1]^
  n Root[-540 + 4543 #1 - 12952 #1^2 + 12952 #1^3 &, 1] + (
 Root[-32 + #1 - 6 #1^2 + #1^3 &, 2]^n)

Comment: Have a look at the docs for `Root[]` and [this thread](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13767) to help you understand your result. You might want to apply `ToRadicals[]` to your result if you want to see explicit (and complicated!) radical expressions.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to understand that *Mathematica* prefers to write some numbers in their closed form because with numerical values, you would loose information and probably precision. It is kind of why it is better to keep `Sin[4]` and not use `-0.756802`, because `Sin[4]` can probably later in your calculation be combined or simplified with other expressions.

That being said, an easy way to understand matrix-power is to assume you can decompose your matrix A into $A=PDP^{-1}$, where D is a diagonal matrix. This is not always possible with every matrix `A`, but in your case it is. Please see `DiagonalizableMatrixQ` for more information.

If A is indeed diagonalizable, you can use

$$A^n = P D^n P^{-1}$$

and look how easy it is to calculate the power of a diagonal matrix:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So what you can do is to calculate D and P by

```
A = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 1, 0}, {0, 5, 4}};
{p, d} = JordanDecomposition[A];
```

Looking at `d`, you see the same `Root` objects

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The components in on the diagonal, really just mean the 1st, 2nd and 3rd root of a special polynomial: the [characteristic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_polynomial) of the matrix A. You can compute it with

```
CharacteristicPolynomial[A, x]
(* 32 - x + 6 x^2 - x^3 *)
```

and you can find the roots by a simple

```
Solve[-32 + x - 6 x^2 + x^3 == 0, x]
```

Now, it is important to see that you get the same numerical values by using `ToRadicals[d]`. Compare them!

Finally, you can easily write down your matrix power with `p` and `d` and of course, you can compare it to what `MatrixPower` gives as answer (might take a while)

```
FullSimplify[p.d^n.Inverse[p] == MatrixPower[A, n], n > 0]
(* True *)
```

Comment: I'm sure you know this, but $\mathbf D$ won't be diagonal in general, especially if the given matrix is *defective*. The point of using `JordanDecomposition[]` is that it can handle the case where the input matrix doesn't have a complete eigenvector set. The OP was fortunate here that his matrix was diagonalizable, tho.

Comment: Yes, I was very close to mention `DiagonalizableMatrixQ`, but I thought that might be to much information in this specific case. But I may be wrong and I should include this hint. I have added it now.

Comment: On another note, you might also want to mention `CharacteristicPolynomial[]` so that OP can see where the stuff within `Root[]` might have come from.

Comment: Hehe.. I knew from the beginning that this answer would be too large and should not be given here :)

Comment: Well, yeah, apart from the question of what `Root[]` is, this really is a math question. ;)

Comment: hali, @J.M. Jordan was an interesting walking encyclopaedia http://www-history.mcs.st-andrews.ac.uk/Biographies/Jordan.html

Answer (score 4):

*Mathematica* has given you what you asked for. You can see that this is true by looking at the values it takes for values of `n = 0, 1, 2, 3`.

```
a = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 1, 0}, {0, 5, 4}};
b[n_Integer] := Chop[N[MatrixPower[a, n]]]
Column[Table[MatrixForm[b[i]], {i, 0, 3}]]
```

[image: matrix]

Comment: It would probably be more convincing to use `RootReduce[]` instead of `Chop[]` + `N[]`, methinks. For further fun, OP can check that `b[-1]` will give the same result as `Inverse[a]`.

Comment: @J.M. I don't disagree with your comment, but I still think my answer is reasonably convincing

Comment: I did upvote your post before commenting, tho; it just feels unseemly to me to use `N[]` to show that the result of an appropriate linear combination of various radicals results in an integer.

Comment: `FullSimplify` yields the exact integer results as well