# How is MatrixPower computed?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, implementation-details

How does Mathematica compute `MatrixPower[m,n]`?

The documentation states it is equivalent to `Dot @@ ConstantArray[m, {n}]`, but this construction is limited to $n\leq 4096$ and simple `Timing` exercises show it is slower.

[This answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/107551/4393) to a similar question mentions `JordanDecomposition`, but I don't know if that is what Mathematica actually uses.

In Linear Algebra classes, it is often taught that diagonalization allows for fast exponentiation.  But is that actually how Mathematica does it?

Comment: The official answer:  [Why You Do Not Usually Need to Know about Internals](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TheInternalsOfTheWolframSystem.html#1881)

Comment: (I'm still curious to know the answer, though)

Comment: The Internals document's second paragraph states "... knowing about the internals of the Wolfram System may be of intellectual interest ...", to which I reply "Yes. Yes it is." I'm a pure mathematician at heart, and am less interested in implementation than others. But I don't like telling students "This is a great way to accomplish XYZ" when, in reality, no one actually does. So I wonder if MMA uses diagonalization; it looks like it does use the generalized form via `JordanDecomposition`, but I'm not positive.

Comment: For comparison, `matrix_power` in [numpy.linang](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.22.0/numpy/linalg/linalg.py#L553-L666) appears to simply perform repeated matrix multiplication.  It gains some efficiency by (effectively) repeatedly squaring $M$ to get matrices of the form $M^{2n}$ and then using the binary decomposition of the desired exponent to express it as a product of matrices of that form.

Comment: ... So if Mathematica uses a similar algorithm then it wouldn't be a good example.  However, [this Wolfram page](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation.html) notes that "`MatrixExp` uses Putzer's method or Jordan decomposition" for exact numerical results, so maybe you can mention that to your students.

Comment: To modify @Michael's statement a little: Jordan or Putzer is used in the exact case, and the Schur decomposition is used in the inexact case for noninteger powers.

Comment: `MatrixPower` and `MatrixExp` do not work the same way in general.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau:  Makes sense.  My comment was mainly directed towards the OP's desire to be able to tell his students about a "real-world" implementation of Jordan decomposition.