# Rearrange generic expression into a quartic polynomial

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials

I'm rather new to mathematica. I'm attempting to express: $$\sqrt{x}  = \frac{\gamma \sqrt{y}}{-i(\Delta - g \sqrt{1 - (\frac{\tau}{4lhx})^2})+\frac{\gamma}{2}}$$
as $$0 = Ax^4 + Bx^3 + Cx^2 + Dx + E,$$
in order to find A,B,C,D,E. I have tried using Collect, however this does not produce the result I want. I was wondering if there was another function I could use that could do this, or if not how to define one myself.

Comment: It would be most useful to have your original expression in *Mathematica* form, for people to copy/paste and play with.

Comment: Also remember to clarify if $i$ represents imaginary number.

Comment: Can you make any assumptions on the values of your parameters? Reals, positive, complex, etc?

Comment: Note also that if you are simply trying to solve the equation for `x`, then you can implement a change of variable to remove the $\sqrt{x}$, and `Solve` will then return a solution (in terms of radicals no less!): `eq /. {Sqrt[x] -> radx, x -> radx^2, x^2 -> radx^4}; Solve[%, radx]`. If you can [work with `Root` objects](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13767/27951), then I would suggest adding `Quartics -> False` to the `Solve` expression above.

Comment: @MarcoB Actually in v9.0.1 without the change of variable `Solve` still manage to find the solution in a few seconds, no matter $i$ represents imaginary number or not.

Comment: @xzczd Ah! That's quite disappointing, since it seems unable to do the same in v. 10.4 anymore... :-(

Comment: $i$ does represent the imaginary number, and x can take on complex values. Everything else is real-valued.