# Hash in Eigenvalue calculation

Tags: equation-solving, linear-algebra

When I tried to find the eigenvalue of a 5x5 matrix, I get the following

```
In[1]:= Eigenvalues[{{6. a, -2. b, 0, 0, 0}, {-2. b, 3. a, -Sqrt[6] b, 0, 0}, {0, -Sqrt[6] b, 2. a, -Sqrt[6] b, 0}, {0, 0, -Sqrt[6] b, 3. a, -2. b}, {0, 0, 0, -2. b, 6. a}}]

Out[1]:= {Root[-1. a^5 + 2.44444 a^3 b^2 - 
0.493827 a b^4 + (1.5 a^4 - 1.77778 a^2 b^2 + 
   0.0987654 b^4) #1 + (-0.861111 a^3 + 
   0.41358 a b^2) #1^2 + (0.236111 a^2 - 0.0308642 b^2) #1^3 - 
0.0308642 a #1^4 + 0.00154321 #1^5 &, 1], 
Root[-1. a^5 + 2.44444 a^3 b^2 - 
0.493827 a b^4 + (1.5 a^4 - 1.77778 a^2 b^2 + 
   0.0987654 b^4) #1 + (-0.861111 a^3 + 
   0.41358 a b^2) #1^2 + (0.236111 a^2 - 0.0308642 b^2) #1^3 - 
0.0308642 a #1^4 + 0.00154321 #1^5 &, 2], 
Root[-1. a^5 + 2.44444 a^3 b^2 - 
0.493827 a b^4 + (1.5 a^4 - 1.77778 a^2 b^2 + 
   0.0987654 b^4) #1 + (-0.861111 a^3 + 
   0.41358 a b^2) #1^2 + (0.236111 a^2 - 0.0308642 b^2) #1^3 - 
0.0308642 a #1^4 + 0.00154321 #1^5 &, 3], 
Root[-1. a^5 + 2.44444 a^3 b^2 - 
0.493827 a b^4 + (1.5 a^4 - 1.77778 a^2 b^2 + 
   0.0987654 b^4) #1 + (-0.861111 a^3 + 
   0.41358 a b^2) #1^2 + (0.236111 a^2 - 0.0308642 b^2) #1^3 - 
0.0308642 a #1^4 + 0.00154321 #1^5 &, 4], 
Root[-1. a^5 + 2.44444 a^3 b^2 - 
0.493827 a b^4 + (1.5 a^4 - 1.77778 a^2 b^2 + 
   0.0987654 b^4) #1 + (-0.861111 a^3 + 
   0.41358 a b^2) #1^2 + (0.236111 a^2 - 0.0308642 b^2) #1^3 - 
0.0308642 a #1^4 + 0.00154321 #1^5 &, 5]}
```

What exactly are the eigenvalues ?

Comment: just add a `.` ie use real values `Eigenvalues[{{6., -2, 0, 0, 0}, {-2, 3, -Sqrt[6], 0, 0}, {0, -Sqrt[6],
    2, -Sqrt[6], 0}, {0, 0, -Sqrt[6], 3, -2}, {0, 0, 0, -2, 6}}]`

Comment: @tsuresuregusa what should I do if there are unknown constants in the matrix ?

Comment: then you have to solve those cubic equations for the eigenvalues... if I remember correctly there is no way to have an analytical solution that is also numerically stable for arbitrary coefficients :( You need to give values to a and b, I had them defined in my kernel andthe solution was simple.

Comment: @tsuresuregusa when there are no unknown coefficients its fine with a dot. So with these constants $a, b$, is it not at all possible to find an expression for eigenvalues ?

Comment: no analytically. I think because you cannot know which root of the 3 is the one you are looking for. I may be wrong though.

Comment: If you have anything larger than a $4\times4$ matrix, there is no general expression for the eigenvalues of the matrix in terms of radicals, because Galois Theory. And anyway, even for the $4\times4$ and $3\times3$ cases, the expressions are usually ugly anyway, so why use them? Also, see [How do I work with Root objects?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13767/how-do-i-work-with-root-objects).

Comment: I got momentarily confused by @tsuresuregusa's comments that I had to count the rows and columns of the given matrix. Anyway, as noted, `Root[]` objects are used to represent the eigenvalues; the polynomial within with `Slot[]` (`#`) arguments is in fact the matrix's characteristic polynomial. A tip: anytime you are mystified by something in the software, **highlight it** and **press F1** for info.