# How to derive closed-form expression for a variable in an equation?

Tags: equation-solving, expression-form

I have an equation
$q = \frac{f + 2 f^2 + 3 f^3}{1 + 2 f + 3 f^2 + 4 f^3}$ and want Mathematica to derive a closed-form expression for real solution to $f$. I've tried running the following code:

```
Solve[q == (f + 2 f^2 + 3 f^3) / (1 + 2 f + 3 f^2 + 4 f^3), f, Reals]
```

but the answer I get is confusing

```
{{f -> Root[q + (-1 + 2*q)*#1 + (-2 + 3*q)*#1^2 + (-3 + 4*q)*#1^3 &, 1]}}
```

I read elsewhere that `#1` means the argument to function `f`, but why is there an additional argument other than `q`?

**Edit:** I've just started deriving this expression manually and ended up with an equation $(4q-3)f^3+(3q-2)f^2+(2q-1)f+q=0$, which looks very similar to what Mathematica returned to me. I am starting to suspect that Mathematica is not able to find a solution since number of solutions could depend on the value of `q`. I have another constraint that `q` is in range $[0,1]$, which implies that the number of real solutions is always 1 (#\Delta<0# for all values in range $[0,1]$, but I am not sure how to communicate this additional constraint to Mathematica, so that it can derive the expression for me.

Comment: `Root` objects are a symbolic representation of roots of polynomials.  Roots of 5th and higher order polynomials are not in general representable with radicals.  However, we can still do useful symbolic computations with them, thus the need for a representation.  You will notice that your solution is in fact the root of a 3rd order polynomial.  If you prefer the radical form, apply `ToRadicals` to it.

Comment: `First@Reduce[q == (f + 2 f^2 + 3 f^3)/(1 + 2 f + 3 f^2 + 4 f^3) && 0 < q < 1, f, Reals] // ToRadicals // Simplify`

Comment: @Szabolcs Someone should probably mention `ToRadicals` in [(13767)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13767/121) to make it more complete.