# Roots of an equation output

Tags: equation-solving, syntax

I'm trying get the critical points of the function $f(x)=(( 1 - 3*(x + 1)^3)/(x^4 + 1))*(x - 2)$ so I took the derivative which is $(16 + 18 x - 9 x^2 - 28 x^3 - 48 x^4 - 18 x^5 + 3 x^6)/(1 + x^4)^2$ and typed:

```
Roots[16 + 18 x - 9 x^2 - 28 x^3 - 48 x^4 - 18 x^5 + 3 x^6 == 0, x]
```

And it gives me this six times, only changing the number after &,:

```
 x == Root[16 + 18 #1 - 9 #1^2 - 28 #1^3 - 48 #1^4 - 18 #1^5 + 3 #1^6 &, 1]
```

I'm new to this program so I was expecting an actual number. What does that mean and how can I get the critical point or get a number for the root ?

Comment: Check out the Root documentation: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html

Comment: See [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/126156).

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Sixth order polynomials don't have a general closed-form solution except for some special cases - `Roots` represents these roots for potential further processing. If you want numerical approximations, you can either 1) wrap the `Roots` command in `N`, or 2) use `NSolve` to get "actual numbers".

Answer (score 1):

```
f[x_] := ((1 - 3*(x + 1)^3)/(x^4 + 1))*(x - 2)

Plot[{f[x], f'[x]}, {x, -7, 7}, Frame -> True, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

```
roots1 = x /. Solve[f[x] == 0, x]
```

> $\left\{2,\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{3}}-1,-1-\frac{1-i \sqrt{3}}{2
> > \sqrt[3]{3}},-1-\frac{1+i \sqrt{3}}{2 \sqrt[3]{3}}\right\}$

```
ListPlot[(Tooltip[{Re[#1], Im[#1]}] &) /@ roots1, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotStyle -> Red]
```

[image]

```
Plot[f[x], {x, -5, 5}, Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], Point[{{roots1[[1]], 
0}, {roots1[[2]], 0}}]}]
```

[image]

```
roots2 = x /. Solve[f'[x] == 0, x]
```

> {Root[16+18 #1-9 #1^2-28 #1^3-48 #1^4-18 #1^5+3 #1^6&,1],Root[16+18 #1-9 #1^2-28 >#1^3-48 #1^4-18 #1^5+3 #1^6&,2],Root[16+18 #1-9 #1^2-28 #1^3-48 #1^4-18 #1^5+3 >#1^6&,3],Root[16+18 #1-9 #1^2-28 #1^3-48 #1^4-18 #1^5+3 #1^6&,4],Root[16+18 #1-9 >#1^2-28 #1^3-48 #1^4-18 #1^5+3 #1^6&,5],Root[16+18 #1-9 #1^2-28 #1^3-48 #1^4-18 >#1^5+3 #1^6&,6]}

```
ListPlot[(Tooltip[{Re[#1], Im[#1]}] &) /@ roots2, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotStyle -> Red]
```

[image]

```
N[roots2]
```

> {-1.57785,-0.714464,0.703213,8.11693,-0.263913-0.871319 I,-0.263913+0.871319 I}

```
NSolve[{f[x] == 0}, x]
```

> {{x->2.},{x->-1.34668+0.600468 I},{x->-1.34668-0.600468 I},{x->-0.306639}}

```
NSolve[{f[x] == f'[x]}, x, Reals]
```

> {{x -> 2.60019}, {x -> -1.35042}, {x -> -0.840415}, {x -> 0.51624}}

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear[f]

f[x_] = (1 - 3*(x + 1)^3)/(x^4 + 1)*(x - 2);

roots = x /. Solve[f[x] == 0, x]

(*  {2, -1 + 1/3^(1/3), -1 - (1 - I Sqrt[3])/(2 3^(1/3)), -1 - (1 + I Sqrt[3])/(
  2 3^(1/3))}  *)
```

The radicals can be expressed as [**`Root`**](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) objects

```
roots // RootReduce

(*  {2, Root[2 + 9 #1 + 9 #1^2 + 3 #1^3 &, 1], 
 Root[2 + 9 #1 + 9 #1^2 + 3 #1^3 &, 3], Root[2 + 9 #1 + 9 #1^2 + 3 #1^3 &, 2]}  *)
```

And low-order `Root` objects can be expressed by radicals using [**`ToRadicals`**](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToRadicals.html)

```
% // ToRadicals

(*  {2, -1 + 1/3^(1/3), -1 - (1 - I Sqrt[3])/(2 3^(1/3)), -1 - (1 + I Sqrt[3])/(
  2 3^(1/3))}  *)

% === roots

(*  True  *)
```

Either radicals or `Root` objects can be converted to approximate numeric values by `N`

```
roots // N

(*  {2., -0.306639, -1.34668 + 0.600468 I, -1.34668 - 0.600468 I}  *)

critPts = x /. Solve[f'[x] == 0, x]

(*  {Root[16 + 18 #1 - 9 #1^2 - 28 #1^3 - 48 #1^4 - 18 #1^5 + 3 #1^6 &, 1], 
 Root[16 + 18 #1 - 9 #1^2 - 28 #1^3 - 48 #1^4 - 18 #1^5 + 3 #1^6 &, 2], 
 Root[16 + 18 #1 - 9 #1^2 - 28 #1^3 - 48 #1^4 - 18 #1^5 + 3 #1^6 &, 3], 
 Root[16 + 18 #1 - 9 #1^2 - 28 #1^3 - 48 #1^4 - 18 #1^5 + 3 #1^6 &, 4], 
 Root[16 + 18 #1 - 9 #1^2 - 28 #1^3 - 48 #1^4 - 18 #1^5 + 3 #1^6 &, 5], 
 Root[16 + 18 #1 - 9 #1^2 - 28 #1^3 - 48 #1^4 - 18 #1^5 + 3 #1^6 &, 6]}  *)
```

The order of these polynomials are too high to express as radicals but can be expressed as approximate numeric values with `N`

```
critPts // N

(*  {-1.57785, -0.714464, 0.703213, 8.11693, -0.263913 - 0.871319 I, -0.263913 + 
  0.871319 I}  *)

Plot[f[x], {x, -3, 10}, PlotRange -> All,
 Epilog -> {AbsolutePointSize[6], Red,
   Point[{#, f[#]} & /@
     Cases[critPts, _?(Im[#] == 0 &)]],
   Blue, Point[{#, f[#]} & /@
     Cases[roots, _?(Im[#] == 0 &)]]},
 PlotLegends -> PointLegend[{Red, Blue},
   {"Critical Point", "Root"}]]
```

[image]