# What Does Slot Mean In Root Output and How To Translate It To Code?

Tags: equation-solving, code-generation, slot

I have the notebook below which produces the correct numerical output but the `CForm` function doesn't appear as though it is working correctly (or I don't know how to interpret the `Slot` function within `Out[4]/CForm`.)  I'm trying to get something I can stick into c++.  How should this be parsed and/or is there a way to get Mathematica to output a more straightforward `CForm` (complex numbers are fine if needed.)

[image]

Edit: Different from that suggested.

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13767/how-do-i-work-with-root-objects -- Since the solution is basically an implicit equation solve by an internal Mathematica function, I'm not sure what's best to do in C.

Comment: You might want to look into `ToRadicals[]` to get a "more traditional" expression, which may or may not be numerically sound when you finally embed it in C++. Those coefficients look huge, so you might also want to do a preliminary rescaling. Anyway, as it stands, you don't have anything C++-ready even with that *Mathematica* result, and [you have more work to do](http://www.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a206859.pdf).

Comment: @J.M. `ToRadicals[]` doesn't seem to get there - even just running that through with the variables `d` and `v` defined comes in pretty significantly off of the correct value.

Comment: Hence "which may or may not be numerically sound". To repeat: your coefficients are huge, and rescaling seems to be warranted.

Comment: @J.M. How do I go about doing that properly?

Comment: @J.M. I'm not exactly sure how it worked (I'm sure it's what you meant by "rescaling") but dropping the `x10^7` off all the coefficients worked.  Are you able to explain why that worked?  I'm not typically into math beyond getting through it for engineering issues but this has me a bit curious of the logic behind it.  Is it just a rounding issue?

Comment: Maybe an analogy would be appreciated: you could express the height of a building in *inches*, and you could express the width of a virus in *miles*, but that doesn't mean they're the appropriate units to use for those quantities. If stuff's going to be large in any computation you're doing, they should be large because it naturally came up, and not because you messed up your initial choice of units.

Comment: Try `Solve[(Pi/3) (y^2) (((3/2) d) - y) == v && d > 0 && y > 0 && v > 0 && v > y && v > d && y <= d, {y}, Reals] // ToRadicals` -- Exact `3/2` vs. approximate `1.5` -- People here generally like users to post code as Mathematica code instead of images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful -- which is why I was slow to try it, what with a regular job and all.... :)

Comment: @MichaelE2 That results in the same issue however I was able to get it via `Roots[1/3 Pi (1.5 d - y) y^2 == v, y]` and then taking the equation for the third root.