# Using Solve on a polynomial equation (5th degree) to get the inverse function

Tags: equation-solving

I used `Solve` to get the inverse function of a polynomial. The result I get contains slots. I do not understand what that means or how to work with it. Here is what I have.

```
poly = 
  208.5932` + 0.3751773` px + 0.00003837606` px^2 - 
  1.304226`*^-8 px^3 + 5.021461`*^-12 px^4 - 9.522892`*^-16 px^5
res = Solve[lambda == poly && px > 500 && px < 1700, px, Reals]
```

with

> ```
> {{px -> 
>    ConditionalExpression[
>      Root[-1.10053*10^60 + 5.27598*10^57 lambda - 1.97943*10^57 #1 - 
>            2.02471*10^53 #1^2 + 6.88107*10^49 #1^3 - 2.64931*10^46 #1^4 + 
>            5.02426*10^42 #1^5 &, 2], 
>      404.43 < lambda < 921.643]}}
> ```

I have seen a lot of options in the `Solve`reference (use of `Exist`...). However, I could not make it usable for my case. Can someone improve the solution or explain what the slots are about?

Comment: See [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/126156).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is a [`Root`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) object with constraints on its domain. You can use it like any other function as long as you honor the constraint on the independent variable.

```
Clear[pxF]
pxF[lambda_] = 
  Solve[lambda == poly && px > 500 && px < 1700, px, Reals][[1, 1, 2]]
```

Then

```
pxF[500]
```

> `732.211`

```
poly /. px -> 732.2113549706908`
```

> `500.`

```
Plot[pxF[x], {x, 300, 1000}]
```

[image: plot]

Note that `pxF` will not plot outside of its domain `404.43 < lambda < 921.643`.

Comment: Thank you for answering clearly. I was worried about the solution above as there were slots ans the variable mixed. If the slot is equal to lambda I would have expected only one of it.