# How to solve a coupled system of transcendental equations?

Tags: equation-solving

If I try to [`Solve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) the following system of three coupled equations, it does not yield solutions, and but gives an error

```
eqns = {
   x - Exp[-(1 - x - y - z)] == 0,
   y - Exp[-(1 - 0.5 x - y - z)] == 0,
   z - Exp[-(1 - x - 0.8 y - z)] == 0
   };


Solve[ eqns, {x, y, z}]
```

> *Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve.*

**How can I solve the following system of equations?**

Comment: I care about roots only, whether these are real or complex, doesn't matter!!

Comment: Are numerical approximations of the roots fine for you?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It doesn't look like there are any *real* solutions.

```
eqns = {x - Exp[-(1 - x - y - z)] == 0, 
   y - Exp[-(1 - 0.5*x - y - z)] == 0, 
   z - Exp[-(1 - x - 0.8*y - z)] == 0};

ContourPlot3D[Evaluate@eqns, {x, -1.5, 1.5}, {y, -1.5, 1.5}, {z, -1.5, 1.5}, 
  ViewVector -> {5, 5, 5}]
```

[image]

Edit: Of course there may well be complex ones.

Answer (score 16):

There are infinitely many solutions. Here we demonstrate only a small part of the `x` - solution space in the complex plane.

[image: enter code here]

Let's start from the begining. 
There are no real solutions:

```
Reduce[{ x - Exp[-(1 - x - y - z)] == 0, 
         y - Exp[-(1 - x/2 - y - z)] == 0, 
         z - Exp[-(1 - x - 4/5 y - z)] == 0}, {x, y, z}, Reals]
```

> ```
> False
> ```

Without domain specification (it means we are looking for complex solutions) `Reduce` has to be supplemented by an appropriate domain specification, otherwise it won't find any solutions.

To demonstrate what is going on here let's take a pedestrian approach, after all it might be automized a bit.

From the first equation we see that $x=a$ where we introduced $\quad a = \exp(-1+x+y+z)$.  Now we get from the second equation $y=a \exp(-x/2)$ and in turn from the first one we have $y=x \exp(-x/2) $. From the third equation we get $z=a\exp(-y/5)$. Next we can obtain an equation for $x$ by eliminating $y$ and $z$ i.e. it yields
 $$x=e^{-1+x+x e^{-\frac{x}{2}} + x e^{-\frac{x}{5} e^{-\frac{x}{2}}}}$$
  We need to restrict appropriately the complex domain since knowing properties of exponential functions we expect there are infinitely many solutions. Now we obtain two exact solutions for `x` nearest zero in the complex plane:

```
Reduce[ x == Exp[-1 + x (1 + Exp[-x/2] + Exp[-(x/5) Exp[-(x/2)]])] && 
        Abs[x] < 2, x]
sx = {ToRules @ % } // N;
```

> ```
>  x == Root[{-E^(
>    E^(-(#1/2) - 
>      1/5 E^(-(#1/2)) #1) (-E^(#1/2 + 1/5 E^(-(#1/2)) #1) + 
>       E^(#1/2) #1 + E^(1/5 E^(-(#1/2)) #1) #1 + 
>       E^(#1/2 + 1/5 E^(-(#1/2)) #1) #1)) + #1 &, 
> 0.055803204968110806464128827202522530324263607292 - 
>  0.510206373369089749181274412607230169611834407013 I}] || 
> x == Root[{-E^(
>    E^(-(#1/2) - 
>      1/5 E^(-(#1/2)) #1) (-E^(#1/2 + 1/5 E^(-(#1/2)) #1) + 
>       E^(#1/2) #1 + E^(1/5 E^(-(#1/2)) #1) #1 + 
>       E^(#1/2 + 1/5 E^(-(#1/2)) #1) #1)) + #1 &, 
> 0.055803204968110806464128827202522530324263607292 + 
>  0.510206373369089749181274412607230169611834407013 I}]
> ```

`Root` is a symbolic representation of **exact solutions**, see e.g. [How do I work with Root objects?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13767/how-do-i-work-with-root-objects/13768#13768).
For example taking restriction `Abs[x] < 370/100` after a few minutes I got **102 complex solutions for `x`**. One can show that if `x + I y` is a  solution then `x - I y` is a solution too (for `x` and `y` reals)

To demonstrate the structure of the `x`-solution space in a small part of the complex plane we  define:

```
f[x_, y_] := -E^(-1 + (1 + E^(1/2 (-x - I y)) + 
   E^(-(1/5) E^(1/2 (-x - I y)) (x + I y))) (x + I y)) + x + I y
```

and we can catch a glimpse of multitude of solutions

```
sol = {ToRules@
Reduce[x == 
   Exp[-1 + x (1 + Exp[-x/2] + Exp[-(x/5) Exp[-(x/2)]])] && 
  Abs[x] < 370/100, x]};
Length[sol]
```

> ```
> 102
> ```

```
ContourPlot[{Re[f[x, y]] == 0, Im[f[x, y]] == 0},
            {x, -3.7, -2.85}, {y, 0.65, 1.5}, 
  PlotPoints -> 50, ImageSize -> Large, 
  ContourStyle -> {Orange, Darker@Cyan}, 
  Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.015], Point[ReIm[x /. sol]]}]
```

Solutions are denoted by red points where curves intersect. For a technical reason not all the intersection point are drawn.

The results for `y` and `z` might be expressed also in the symbolic form, nontheless for brevity we demonstrate them only related to given two solutions for `x` in the numerical form

```
sy = y -> x Exp[-x/2] /. sx
```

> ```
> {y -> 0.177717 - 0.466416 I, y -> 0.177717 + 0.466416 I}
> ```

```
z -> x  Exp[-y/5] /. Transpose[{sx // Flatten, sy}]
```

> ```
> {z -> 0.0994856 - 0.485233 I, z -> 0.0994856 + 0.485233 I}
> ```

`Reduce` couldn't find solutions without approprate restriction of domains for `x`, `y`, `z` separately. This is crucial point to get any solutions.

Answer (score 6):

**Edit:** As pointed out by @anderstood, `FindRoot` can't be used to decisively say if there are no solutions for a set a equations as it depends on the starting values of variables.

You can use [`FindRoot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot.html) to solve these transcendental equations. Real and complex solutions are checked, if any, as follows.

**Checking for Real solutions:**

```
exps = {x - Exp[-(1 - x - y - z)], y - Exp[-(1 - 0.5 x - y - z)], 
   z - Exp[-(1 - x - 0.8 y - z)]};
sols = FindRoot[Thread[exps == 0], {x, 0}, {y, 0}, {z, 0}] (*FindRoot throws a warning message*)
```

> {x -> -0.00592577, y -> -0.0047965, z -> -0.00555911}

Substituting the above solution in `exps` gives,

```
exps /. sols
```

> {-0.367864, -0.367809, -0.367845}

**Checking for Complex solutions:**
To look for complex solutions, add 1.I to the initial values of variables.

```
exps = {x - Exp[-(1 - x - y - z)], y - Exp[-(1 - 0.5 x - y - z)], 
   z - Exp[-(1 - x - 0.8 y - z)]};
sols = FindRoot[
  Thread[exps == 0], {x, 0 + 1. I}, {y, 0 + 1. I}, {z, 0 + 1. I}]
```

> {x -> 0.0558032 + 0.510206 I, y -> 0.177717 + 0.466416 I, 
>    z -> 0.0994856 + 0.485233 I}

Substituting the above solution into `exps` gives,

```
exps /. sols
```

> {8.32667*10^-17 + 1.11022*10^-16 I, 2.77556*10^-17 + 1.11022*10^-16 I,
>     4.16334*10^-17 + 5.55112*10^-17 I}

Looking at these solutions, it can be seen that the equations only have a complex solution.

Comment: @Artes That's right. That is clearly seen from the error it produced when I substituted the real solution into `exps`. I concluded at the end that only a complex solution exists because the error is closer to zero.

Comment: Well, it is hard to conclude anything from `FindRoot`. It may not converge for the zero initial conditions your provided, but could find some solutions for more exotic ones. From what you have shown, I don't think you can conclude that there are no real solutions. Also `FindRoot` certainly outputs an error message, which you have not mentioned.

Comment: @anderstood I agree with you. It depends on the starting values. An exhaustive search might be the only way when using `FindRoot` to conclude if there are solutions.