# Getting different eigenvalues for same matrix?

Tags: matrix, numerics, linear-algebra

Im trying to find eigenvalues for the matrix

\begin{bmatrix}
  2 & -1 & -1 \\
  -1 & 1 & 1 \\
  -1 & 1 & 4
 \end{bmatrix}

Finding the eigenvalues using the Eigenvalues function I get:

```
N@Eigenvalues[ {
{2, -1, -1},
{-1, 1, 1},
{-1, 1, 4}
             } ]
```

And it returns

```
{4.8662, 1.78924, 0.344558}
```

However, when I try to solve it by hand, and using the Characteristic Polynomial function

```
 CharacteristicPolynomial[ {
{2, -1, -1},
{-1, 1, 1},
{-1, 1, 4}
                         } , \[Lambda]]
```

I get $$3 - 11 \lambda + 7 \lambda^2 - \lambda ^3$$

Solving it for zero I get non real answers.

```
N@Solve[3 - 11 \[Lambda] + 7 \[Lambda]^2 - \[Lambda]^3 == 
0, \[Lambda]]

{{\[Lambda] -> 4.8662 + 7.40149*10^-17 I}, 
{\[Lambda] -> 
0.344558 + 4.44089*10^-16 I},
{\[Lambda] -> 
1.78924 - 4.44089*10^-16 I}}
```

Comment: [tag:bugs] is a tag to be used only when other people have confirmed your observations to be a bug. In this case, it isn't: the tiny imaginary parts are on the order of roundoff error.

Comment: If you use `NSolve[charpoly == 0, \[Lambda]]` instead of `N@Solve[charpoly == 0, \[Lambda]]` you get all real solutions.

Comment: The following is a guess, as you had not provided the code you used to get the roots of the eigenpolynomial: if you had used `Solve[]` and applied `N[]` to the results, you might want to recall that the results are an instance of *casus irreducibilis*; you are then making *Mathematica* compute a real result from complex numbers, and thus the tiny imaginary part is but an artifact.

Comment: Use `ComplexExpand`:  `Solve[3 - 11 \[Lambda] + 7 \[Lambda]^2 - \[Lambda]^3 == 
    0, \[Lambda]] // ComplexExpand // N`

Comment: Really this seems to be a question about the math and not Mathematica.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drop the `N` and look at the symbolic results.

`Eigenvalues` gives an answer like

```
Root[-3 + 11 #1 - 7 #1^2 + #1^3 &, 1]
```

([What is `Root`?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13767/12))

`Solve` gives

```
7/3 - (8 (1 + I Sqrt[3]))/(3 (37 + 3 I Sqrt[303])^(1/3)) - 
 1/6 (1 - I Sqrt[3]) (37 + 3 I Sqrt[303])^(1/3)
```

This is no surprise because there is no reason to assume that two distinct functions use the same methods.  The two results are equivalent, just expressed in different forms.

Since they are written in different forms, again it is not a surprise that computing then numerically gives slightly different results due to roundoff errors.

The second form contains the imaginary unit, [but this does not mean that it has a non-zero imaginary part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casus_irreducibilis).  However, it is entirely expected that when computing a numerical *approximation*, the imaginary part will only be *almost* zero.

Mathematica uses different numerical methods to compute the value of `Root`, and thus arrives to a slightly different numerical approximation.  The difference between the results is on the order of $10^{-16}$ though, which is the precision limit of machine numbers.

To deal with these situations, look up [`Chop`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Chop.html), or try computing these expressions to more digits using the second argument of [`N`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/N.html). This will also trigger [`Precision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Precision.html) tracking and will give you more reliable results.  Notice that the imaginary part  never disappears, but the more digits you compute, the smaller it gets.  Also notice that the imaginary part is smaller than the [`Accuracy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Accuracy.html) of the result.