# Don't understand `Root` objects as solutions of an equation

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to solve an equation for a variable `t` under some assumptions.

However, the output produced is completely unclear to me. In particular, Mathematica's output says "Assuming a list of rules" and contains stuff like "#1^6 &" which I can't interpret (even though I understand the operators in general). Can anyone help? The expression I am trying to evaluate is as follows:

```
Assuming[
  omega == 2 && sigma > 0 && sigma <= 1 && t > 0 && t <= 0.5 && 
    sigma ∈ Reals && omega ∈ Reals && t ∈ Reals,
  Solve[
    (omega*sigma*(1/(omega*(t - 1)) + 1) - (sigma*t)/(t - 1)^2)/
        (omega*sigma*t*(1/(omega*(t - 1)) + 1) + 1) - t/(t - 1)^2 -
      1/(t - 1) - omega + log (omega*sigma*t*(1/(omega*(t - 1)) + 1) + 1)*
        (omega*sigma*(1/(omega*(t - 1)) + 1) - (sigma*t)/(t - 1)^2) +
      omega*(1/(omega*(t - 1)) + 1) -
      2*omega^2*sigma*t*(1/(omega*(t - 1)) + 1)^2 +
      (2*omega*sigma*t^2*(1/(omega*(t - 1)) + 1))/(t - 1)^2 == 0,
    t]]
```

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: See [here](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12505) and [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html)

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/126156)? Let me also offer a tip: anything you see in your output that you don't understand, highlight it and press F1.

Comment: Your output involves *Root* objects. Think of them as a generalization of radicals, capable of representing any algebraic number.

Comment: Thanks for the links. I looked at many of them, however they're dealing with simply outputting a number. What i am looking for is a closed form expression solved for t. Is there any way to do this? I realize there might be no global closed form solution, but is there any way to at least get multiple local ones? Thanks!

Comment: What you get **is** the list of closed form solutions.

Comment: Sorry, I'm really unexperienced with Mathematica and I just don't get it. I get expressions like t->Root(...). Isn't it just an implicit solution saying that t would be equal to the root of a certain polynomial? what i am looking for instead is a certain function f(sigma,omega) = t* , where t* is the root of the implicit expression above

Comment: *Root[polynomial,n]* is essentially the same kind of thing as *Sqrt[x]*, but generalizes to cases where radicals can't go.

Comment: Also, did you mean to use *log* as a variable? The logarithm is *Log[]*, using brackets, not parentheses.

Comment: Another tip for you. Since you're now (somewhat) familiar with `Root[]`, look at the degree of the polynomial in its first argument. If it's 5 or greater, don't count on getting anything more explicit than that, per Abel and Galois.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments, John and J.M.! I tried it as you described and replaced log() by Log[]. What I am getting now is "Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve." Is there any possible workaround here? The command I am running is as above, just with Log replaced

Comment: If `Solve` doesn't work, your next stop is usually `Reduce`.

Comment: What if both doesnt work? :)

Comment: That's the situation quaintly referred to in some circles as "SOL".

Comment: When `sigma` is given a specific value (and keeping in mind `omega` is set to 2) then `Solve` can give a solution. It involves `Root` objects for transcendental solutions but they evaluate numerically just fine...

Comment: ...Try e.g. `f[sigma_] := 
 Solve[{(2*sigma*(1/(2*(t - 1)) + 1) - (sigma*t)/(t - 1)^2)/(2*sigma*
         t*(1/(2*(t - 1)) + 1) + 1) - t/(t - 1)^2 - 1/(t - 1) - 2 + 
     Log [2*sigma*t*(1/(2*(t - 1)) + 1) + 
        1]*(2*sigma*(1/(2*(t - 1)) + 1) - (sigma*t)/(t - 1)^2) + 
     2*(1/(2*(t - 1)) + 1) - 
     2*2^2*sigma*
      t*(1/(2*(t - 1)) + 1)^2 + (2*2*sigma*
        t^2*(1/(2*(t - 1)) + 1))/(t - 1)^2 == 0, t > 0, t <= 1/2}, t];
f[1/3]`

Answer (score 2):

1. Mathematica has transformed your problem into finding the roots of a polynomial of degree 6 in `t`, which has 6 solutions. As always, it returns the solutions as a list of rules. In this case, each of the solutions is expressed as a `Root` object, because equations of degree 6 can usually not be solved in terms of radicals.

   See [`Root`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) in the documentation.
2. One of your terms is

   ```
   log (omega*sigma*t*(1/(omega*(t - 1)) + 1) + 1)*
     (omega*sigma*(1/(omega*(t - 1)) + 1) - (sigma*t)/(t - 1)^2)
   ```

   The symbol `log` is being interpreted  as a complex number. Is that intentional? Or were you trying to write an expression of form `Log[...]`? If the latter, then you problem is a simple syntax error.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! No, it wasn't intentional. However, when I replace log by "Log[...]", the problem persists...