# Eigenvalues function not working properly

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, eigenvalues

I am trying to simply find the Eigenvalues of any matrix. 
I have set up M to be a 3 by 3 matrix filled with random values:

```
M = Table[RandomInteger[{-10, 10}], {i, 1, 3, 1}, {j, 1, 3, 1}]
```

This produces something like:

```
 {{7, 10, -3}, {1, -4, -8}, {7, -8, 5}}.
```

Then I ask Mathematica to find the Eigenvalues of the matrix:

```
Eigenvalues[M]
```

It returns this:

```
{Root[1258 - 66 #1 - 8 #1^2 + #1^3 &, 3], 
 Root[1258 - 66 #1 - 8 #1^2 + #1^3 &, 2], 
 Root[1258 - 66 #1 - 8 #1^2 + #1^3 &, 1]}
```

I know that is know the correct answer, but I am not sure what I am doing wrong. 
The only matrix I have tried for which Eigenvalues works properly is the Identity matrix

Comment: I read that post you linked before posting this and it was of no help whatsoever :(

Comment: Use `ToRadicals[]` on the result to get explicit radical expressions, as noted in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/126156). More directly, try `Eigenvalues[{{7, 10, -3}, {1, -4, -8}, {7, -8, 5}}, Cubics -> True]`.

Comment: Ah, I kept expecting numbers, but now that I got it this far, I can take it from here. Thanks!