# Understanding Solve output

Tags: syntax

In Solve output for such as:

```
Solve[r^2 - 6 r - 3 s^2 + 8 s Sqrt[r] == 0 && 0 < s < 1, r, Reals]
```

Where in the documentation do I learn how to read the output?

Answer (score 0):

without testing the code generally Solve gives you an answer in the form of list with i entries like {r-> x1, r-> x2}  depending in your case how many i Real answers there are...based on your condition...If you write ?Solve you’ll get a snippet of the documentation for that command...and the >>will take you directly to the documentation itself.

Comment: In particular, how do I read the result:

Comment: Root[9 s^4 - 28 s^2 #1 + (36 - 6 s^2) #1^2 - 12 #1^3 + #1^4 &, 2], 
 0 < s < 1]

Comment: @LeonDavidRoper See e.g. [How do I work with Root objects?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13767/how-do-i-work-with-root-objects/13768#13768)

Answer (score 0):

```
Region[ImplicitRegion[
  r^2 - 6 r - 3 s^2 + 8 s Sqrt[r] == 0 && 0 < s < 1, {r, s}], 
 FrameLabel -> {"r", "s"}, Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

Note I am using `<=`

```
RegionPlot[
 r^2 - 6 r - 3 s^2 + 8 s Sqrt[r] <= 0 && 0 < s < 1, {s, 0.001, 
  0.999}, {r, 0, 7}, FrameLabel -> Automatic]
```

[image]

```
 val=Table[Join @@ {{s}, 
        Flatten@Values@
          NSolve[r^2 - 6 r - 3 s^2 + 8 s Sqrt[r] == 0 && 0 < s < 1, r, 
           Reals]}, {s, 1/100, 1, 1/100}] // Most
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To get an insight of the solution variety you can use

```
ContourPlot[r^2 - 6 r - 3 s^2 + 8 s Sqrt[r] == 0, {s, 0, 1}, {r, -1, 6}, 
MaxRecursion -> 4, FrameLabel -> {s, r}]
```

[image]

The plot includes the solution s=r=0