# Reciprocal function of a polynomial : Why mathematica doesn't find a solution on my given interval?

Tags: equation-solving, approximation

I am trying to find a reciprocal function to the binary shannon entropy $H_2(p)$ (chosing the branch were $p>1/2$).

I used a method based on solving the differential equation that the reciprocal follows but it was a little too long for what i need to do.

Thus, I want to do a polynomial approximation of the shannon entropy and then find the reciprocal of this polynomial function.

But mathematica answers me things I don't understand.

Here is my code :

```
H2[x_] := 
  If[x != 0, If[x != 1, (-x)*Log[x] - (1 - x)*Log[1 - x], 0], 0]; 

tableauValeursH2 = Table[{x, H2[x]}, {x, 1/2, 1, 0.001}]; 

ff[y_] = Fit[tableauValeursH2, Table[y^k, {k, 0, 10}], y]


Solve[y == ff[x], x]
```

And mathematica answers me :

```
{{x -> Root[
    502925249036334454715336778553984003440864263790494070 + 
      79507334695638259109060376450677753198917644793560 y - 
      7228015973937440731974941433834202407604387494117592200 #1 + 
      46469470965681832229663230673595151067237874818752782840 #1^2 - 
      176009396354156927628824727628578542386502238219708082250 #1^3 \
+ 434953160110610020035094377442281900757943807833308766200 #1^4 - 
      732785165581324716157030456066865775762616415498186198190 #1^5 \
+ 852422521044952102836379759843676923790865671573802051255 #1^6 - 
      676099528944398287173100625127955582322701524364225111800 #1^7 \
+ 349947592110433543619114105190630648009305990596089919920 #1^8 - 
      106747371466686462957887174434503958626612109573992670672 #1^9 \
+ 14573808550521644768419974300540238469473534471735953168 #1^10 &, 
    1]}, {x -> 
   Root[502925249036334454715336778553984003440864263790494070 + 
      79507334695638259109060376450677753198917644793560 y - 
      7228015973937440731974941433834202407604387494117592200 #1 + 
      46469470965681832229663230673595151067237874818752782840 #1^2 - 
      176009396354156927628824727628578542386502238219708082250 #1^3 \
+ 434953160110610020035094377442281900757943807833308766200 #1^4 - 
      732785165581324716157030456066865775762616415498186198190 #1^5 \
+ 852422521044952102836379759843676923790865671573802051255 #1^6 - 
      676099528944398287173100625127955582322701524364225111800 #1^7 \
+ 349947592110433543619114105190630648009305990596089919920 #1^8 - 
      106747371466686462957887174434503958626612109573992670672 #1^9 \
+ 14573808550521644768419974300540238469473534471735953168 #1^10 &, 
    2]}, {x -> 
   Root[502925249036334454715336778553984003440864263790494070 + 
      79507334695638259109060376450677753198917644793560 y - 
      7228015973937440731974941433834202407604387494117592200 #1 + 
      46469470965681832229663230673595151067237874818752782840 #1^2 - 
      176009396354156927628824727628578542386502238219708082250 #1^3 \
+ 434953160110610020035094377442281900757943807833308766200 #1^4 - 
      732785165581324716157030456066865775762616415498186198190 #1^5 \
+ 852422521044952102836379759843676923790865671573802051255 #1^6 - 
      676099528944398287173100625127955582322701524364225111800 #1^7 \
+ 349947592110433543619114105190630648009305990596089919920 #1^8 - 
      106747371466686462957887174434503958626612109573992670672 #1^9 \
+ 14573808550521644768419974300540238469473534471735953168 #1^10 &, 
    3]}, {x -> 
   Root[502925249036334454715336778553984003440864263790494070 + 
      79507334695638259109060376450677753198917644793560 y - 
      7228015973937440731974941433834202407604387494117592200 #1 + 
      46469470965681832229663230673595151067237874818752782840 #1^2 - 
      176009396354156927628824727628578542386502238219708082250 #1^3 \
+ 434953160110610020035094377442281900757943807833308766200 #1^4 - 
      732785165581324716157030456066865775762616415498186198190 #1^5 \
+ 852422521044952102836379759843676923790865671573802051255 #1^6 - 
      676099528944398287173100625127955582322701524364225111800 #1^7 \
+ 349947592110433543619114105190630648009305990596089919920 #1^8 - 
      106747371466686462957887174434503958626612109573992670672 #1^9 \
+ 14573808550521644768419974300540238469473534471735953168 #1^10 &, 
    4]}, {x -> 
   Root[502925249036334454715336778553984003440864263790494070 + 
      79507334695638259109060376450677753198917644793560 y - 
      7228015973937440731974941433834202407604387494117592200 #1 + 
      46469470965681832229663230673595151067237874818752782840 #1^2 - 
      176009396354156927628824727628578542386502238219708082250 #1^3 \
+ 434953160110610020035094377442281900757943807833308766200 #1^4 - 
      732785165581324716157030456066865775762616415498186198190 #1^5 \
+ 852422521044952102836379759843676923790865671573802051255 #1^6 - 
      676099528944398287173100625127955582322701524364225111800 #1^7 \
+ 349947592110433543619114105190630648009305990596089919920 #1^8 - 
      106747371466686462957887174434503958626612109573992670672 #1^9 \
+ 14573808550521644768419974300540238469473534471735953168 #1^10 &, 
    5]}, {x -> 
   Root[502925249036334454715336778553984003440864263790494070 + 
      79507334695638259109060376450677753198917644793560 y - 
      7228015973937440731974941433834202407604387494117592200 #1 + 
      46469470965681832229663230673595151067237874818752782840 #1^2 - 
      176009396354156927628824727628578542386502238219708082250 #1^3 \
+ 434953160110610020035094377442281900757943807833308766200 #1^4 - 
      732785165581324716157030456066865775762616415498186198190 #1^5 \
+ 852422521044952102836379759843676923790865671573802051255 #1^6 - 
      676099528944398287173100625127955582322701524364225111800 #1^7 \
+ 349947592110433543619114105190630648009305990596089919920 #1^8 - 
      106747371466686462957887174434503958626612109573992670672 #1^9 \
+ 14573808550521644768419974300540238469473534471735953168 #1^10 &, 
    6]}, {x -> 
   Root[502925249036334454715336778553984003440864263790494070 + 
      79507334695638259109060376450677753198917644793560 y - 
      7228015973937440731974941433834202407604387494117592200 #1 + 
      46469470965681832229663230673595151067237874818752782840 #1^2 - 
      176009396354156927628824727628578542386502238219708082250 #1^3 \
+ 434953160110610020035094377442281900757943807833308766200 #1^4 - 
      732785165581324716157030456066865775762616415498186198190 #1^5 \
+ 852422521044952102836379759843676923790865671573802051255 #1^6 - 
      676099528944398287173100625127955582322701524364225111800 #1^7 \
+ 349947592110433543619114105190630648009305990596089919920 #1^8 - 
      106747371466686462957887174434503958626612109573992670672 #1^9 \
+ 14573808550521644768419974300540238469473534471735953168 #1^10 &, 
    7]}, {x -> 
   Root[502925249036334454715336778553984003440864263790494070 + 
      79507334695638259109060376450677753198917644793560 y - 
      7228015973937440731974941433834202407604387494117592200 #1 + 
      46469470965681832229663230673595151067237874818752782840 #1^2 - 
      176009396354156927628824727628578542386502238219708082250 #1^3 \
+ 434953160110610020035094377442281900757943807833308766200 #1^4 - 
      732785165581324716157030456066865775762616415498186198190 #1^5 \
+ 852422521044952102836379759843676923790865671573802051255 #1^6 - 
      676099528944398287173100625127955582322701524364225111800 #1^7 \
+ 349947592110433543619114105190630648009305990596089919920 #1^8 - 
      106747371466686462957887174434503958626612109573992670672 #1^9 \
+ 14573808550521644768419974300540238469473534471735953168 #1^10 &, 
    8]}, {x -> 
   Root[502925249036334454715336778553984003440864263790494070 + 
      79507334695638259109060376450677753198917644793560 y - 
      7228015973937440731974941433834202407604387494117592200 #1 + 
      46469470965681832229663230673595151067237874818752782840 #1^2 - 
      176009396354156927628824727628578542386502238219708082250 #1^3 \
+ 434953160110610020035094377442281900757943807833308766200 #1^4 - 
      732785165581324716157030456066865775762616415498186198190 #1^5 \
+ 852422521044952102836379759843676923790865671573802051255 #1^6 - 
      676099528944398287173100625127955582322701524364225111800 #1^7 \
+ 349947592110433543619114105190630648009305990596089919920 #1^8 - 
      106747371466686462957887174434503958626612109573992670672 #1^9 \
+ 14573808550521644768419974300540238469473534471735953168 #1^10 &, 
    9]}, {x -> 
   Root[502925249036334454715336778553984003440864263790494070 + 
      79507334695638259109060376450677753198917644793560 y - 
      7228015973937440731974941433834202407604387494117592200 #1 + 
      46469470965681832229663230673595151067237874818752782840 #1^2 - 
      176009396354156927628824727628578542386502238219708082250 #1^3 \
+ 434953160110610020035094377442281900757943807833308766200 #1^4 - 
      732785165581324716157030456066865775762616415498186198190 #1^5 \
+ 852422521044952102836379759843676923790865671573802051255 #1^6 - 
      676099528944398287173100625127955582322701524364225111800 #1^7 \
+ 349947592110433543619114105190630648009305990596089919920 #1^8 - 
      106747371466686462957887174434503958626612109573992670672 #1^9 \
+ 14573808550521644768419974300540238469473534471735953168 #1^10 &, 
    10]}}
```

As my polynomial is of degree 10 I have possibly 10 solutions to this equation. But actually I am looking what happens for $1/2 \leq x \leq 1$. Then, I changed my solve line by :

```
Solve[y == ff[x] && 1/2 <= x <= 1, x]
```

But then I have 0 solutions :

```
Solve::ratnz: Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact system and numericizing the result.
```

But of course there is a solution we can see it graphically.

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I work with Root objects?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13767/how-do-i-work-with-root-objects)

Comment: What is returned are the ten solutions to the equation you gave to `Solve`, so exactly what you want

Comment: @Mathe172 ok I edited, indeed i didn't told me i was looking for things on $[1/2;1]$ but then I still have a problem

Comment: Try `Reduce` instead of `Solve`, optionally with `Simplify[…,y∈Reals]`

Comment: It seems to me that the NDSolve approach is much simpler, e.g., `if = NDSolveValue[{H2'[x[y]] x'[y] == 1, x[H2[3/4]] == 3/4}, x, {y, 0, Log[2]}, WorkingPrecision->16]`

Answer (score 4):

## Finding a good polynomial fit

Just as an alternative way to solve the first part of original problem, finding a good fit to the shannon entropy, here's another way.

First let's write down the expression we want to approximate

```
shannonentropy = (-x)*Log[x] - (1 - x)*Log[1 - x]
```

and a (polynomial) linear model with free parameters

```
model = \[Alpha] x (1 - x) + \[Beta] x^2 (1 - x)^2 + \[Gamma] x^3 (1 - x)^3
```

, that we want to optimize. Here we used our knowledge about the symmetry of the `shannonentropy` function to omit some other possible polynomial terms and also only used terms that fulfill the boundary condition, that the function goes to zero at `x==0` and `x==1`.

Now because, in terms of integration, the expression we want to find a fit for, is not that complicated, we can directly integrate the squared error between our desired function and our model, fully symbollically without needing to discretize!

```
(shannonentropy - model)^2
Expand[%]
errsq = Integrate[Evaluate[%], {x, 0, 1}]
```

> 5/6 - [Pi]^2/18 - (37 [Beta])/900 - (533 [Gamma])/58800 + (
>    143 (7 [Alpha] (-35 + 6 [Alpha]) + 18 [Alpha] [Beta] + 
>        2 [Beta]^2) + 26 (22 [Alpha] + 5 [Beta]) [Gamma] + 
>     15 [Gamma]^2)/180180

Now we just need to find the parameter set that minimizes the squared error and insert this into our model to get the best fit!

```
solparams = Minimize[errsq, {\[Alpha], \[Beta], \[Gamma]}]
```

> {10833173/19756800 - [Pi]^2/
>     18, {[Alpha] -> 1297/280, [Beta] -> -(451/35), [Gamma] -> 6149/
>      280}}

```
bestfit = model /. solparams[[2]]
```

> 1297/280 (1 - x) x - 451/35 (1 - x)^2 x^2 + 6149/280 (1 - x)^3 x^3

```
Plot[{shannonentropy, bestfit}, {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Shannon entropy and best fit]

## Getting the inverse of the polynomial

With this simpler model it's also easy to get the correct branch of the function inverse:

```
Solve[y == bestfit && 1/2 < x < 1, x, Reals]
```

> {{x -> ConditionalExpression[
>       Root[280 y - 1297 #1 + 4905 #1^2 - 13365 #1^3 + 22055 #1^4 - 
>          18447 #1^5 + 6149 #1^6 &, 2], 0 < y < 12469/17920]}}

, where `Solve` gives back the right branch as a `Root` expression, if the function value is in the correct value range (`0 < y < 12469/17920`). Here giving the `Reals` domain to `Solve` is important to get an explicit solution.