# How can I force results to be expressed in exact fractions rather than approximate decimals?

Tags: equation-solving, output-formatting

I have a table that where the elements are the results of `Solve`:

```
table = 
  Table[
    Solve[
      Sum[(2 j π Sin[(2 j π  x)/(r + 1)])/(r + 1)^2, {j, 0, r}] == 0 && 
      0 < x <= 1],
    {r, 25}]
```

My issue is that, from `r = 4` onwards, the results are not expressed in fractional form, but as approximations in decimal form. I assume it's because the fractions would become long or complicated, but I want the expanded fractional form regardless of complexity.

How do I force Mathematica to express the results as fractions?

#### EDIT

My main aim is to derive a systematic formula for the zeroes of the equation within that range of `x`. Unfortunately, I'm a total amateur, and when I see things like `6 ArcTan[Sqrt[Root[55 - 396 #1 + 594 #1^2 - 220 #1^3 + 15 #1^4 &, 1]]]` I kind of freeze. What does something like `#1` even mean? I thought I saw a pattern developing in the first few outputs. But then I lost it because I can't interpret what Mathematica is trying to tell me.

Comment: When I run your code I get answers in terms of `Root` objects, which are precise objects but involve roots of polynomials.

Comment: To add to the comment of @KraZug: What version of Mathematica are you on? I get `Root` objects as well, not decimal approximations.

Comment: OK, I probably wasn't clear enough. Wasn't trying to be cryptic, just brief and to the point. Would be v grateful if you could look at my edit of the OP, and help me further.

Comment: And thanks for the formatting help :-)

Comment: Richard, have a look into the documentation of `Function` in order to learn about more about these somewhat cryptic things like `#`, `#1`,`##`, and `&`.

Comment: MMA11 home use, BTW.

Comment: `Root` objects are a way of expressing roots of polynomial equations. You can use `ToRadicals` to get the cubic and quartic ones to explicit expressions, but only up to n=4. Incidentally, Mathematica seems to give a closed form for the sum with arbitrary r.

Comment: Hi Henrik. (Again! You are such a helpful person! Vielen dank.) So, in my case, `#1` means 'parameter 1'... Which is...`x`...? Sorry to be a bit slow. I have an English degree, but the last time I did any serious mathematics, I was 18 - a long time ago...

Comment: Hi KraZug, how did you get to the closed form? It looks to me like it's convergent, but I don't know how to get to the actual final expression...

Comment: Also: KraZug - I very much appreciate your input too. I only singled out Heinrik because he's answered a few other questions I posed :-)

Comment: D'oh! `#1` must be `r`... I think...?

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13767/how-do-i-work-with-root-objects

Comment: You might want to have a look into a nice online book of L. Shifrin. You may find it here: http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/node50.html The chapter 4.11 is what you need.